# Accessing class members on a NULL pointer

Tags: c++, null, virtual, null-pointer

I was experimenting with C++ and found the below code as very strange.

```
class Foo{
public:
    virtual void say_virtual_hi(){
        std::cout << "Virtual Hi";
    }

    void say_hi()
    {
        std::cout << "Hi";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo* foo = 0;
    foo->say_hi(); // works well
    foo->say_virtual_hi(); // will crash the app
    return 0;
}
```

I know that the virtual method call crashes because it requires a vtable lookup and can only work with valid objects.

I have the following questions

1. How does the non virtual method `say_hi` work on a NULL pointer?
2. Where does the object `foo` get allocated?

Any thoughts?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-behav) for what the language says about it. Both are undefined behavior.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The object `foo` is a local variable with type `Foo*`. That variable likely gets allocated on the stack for the `main` function, just like any other local variable. But the *value* stored in `foo` is a null pointer. It doesn't point anywhere. There is no instance of type `Foo` represented anywhere.

To call a virtual function, the caller needs to know which object the function is being called on. That's because the object itself is what tells which function should really be called. (That's frequently implemented by giving the object a pointer to a vtable, a list of function-pointers, and the caller just knows it's supposed to call the first function on the list, without knowing in advance where that pointer points.)

But to call a non-virtual function, the caller doesn't need to know all that. The compiler knows exactly which function will get called, so it can generate a `CALL` machine-code instruction to go directly to the desired function. It simply passes a pointer to the object the function was called on as a hidden parameter to the function. In other words, the compiler translates your function call into this:

```
void Foo_say_hi(Foo* this);

Foo_say_hi(foo);
```

Now, since the implementation of that function never makes reference to any members of the object pointed to by its `this` argument, you effectively dodge the bullet of dereferencing a null pointer because you never dereference one.

Formally, calling *any* function — even a non-virtual one — on a null pointer is undefined behavior. One of the allowed results of undefined behavior is that your code appears to run exactly as you intended. *You* shouldn't rely on that, although you will sometimes find libraries from your compiler vendor that *do* rely on that. But the compiler vendor has the advantage of being able to add further definition to what would otherwise be undefined behavior. Don't do it yourself.

Comment: There also seems to be confusion as to the fact that the function code and the object data are two different things. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966920/more-info-on-memory-layout-of-an-executable-program-process. The object data is not available after the initialization in this case because of the null pointer, but the code has alsways been available in memory elsewhere.

Comment: FYI this is derived from `[C++11: 9.3.1/2]`: "If a non-static member function of a class `X` is called for an object that is not of type `X`, or of a type derived from `X`, the behavior is undefined." Clearly `*foo` is not of type `Foo` (as it doesn't exist).

Comment: Actually, in hindsight, it's more directly derived from `[C++11: 5.2.5/2]`: "The expression `E1->E2` is converted to the
equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2`" and then the obvious UB of dereferencing `E1` when it's not a valid pointer (inc. `[C++11: 3.8/2]`).

Comment: Can you tell me where you saw this question referenced, @Lightness? I've gotten over 20 votes on it in the last day, and I'd like to see why it's suddenly attracted so much attention.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Someone linked to it on freenode##c++ yesterday, and likely elsewhere too. My comments also may have brought it to the front pages briefly.

Answer (score 18):

The `say_hi()` member function is usually implemented by the compiler as

```
void say_hi(Foo *this);
```

Since you don't access any members, your call succeeds (even though you are entering undefined behaviour according to the standard).

`Foo` doesn't get allocated at all.

Comment: Thanks. If *Foo* doesn't get allocated, how the call happens? I am bit confused..

Comment: Processor or assembly respectively, has no clue about HLL details of the code. C++ non virtual functions are merely normal functions with a contract that the 'this' pointer is at given place (register or stack, depends on compilers). As long as you don't access the 'this' pointer everything's fine.

Comment: I had a situation that null point de reference did not crash even if it accessed a data field. I think the crash should be standardized.

Comment: Implementations vary, but requiring null checks everywhere would make pointer references too expensive for the core C++ design objectives on most platforms.

Answer (score 7):

Dereferencing a NULL pointer causes "undefined behaviour", This means that anything could happen - your code may even appear to work correctly. You must not depend on this however - if you run the same code on a different platform (or even possibly on the same platform) it will probably crash.

In your code there is no Foo object, only a pointer which is initalised with the value NULL.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about the second question? Where *Foo* gets allocated?

Comment: foo isn't an object, it is a pointer. That pointer is allocated on the stack (like any variable which is not marked 'static' or allocated with 'new'. And it never points to a valid object.

Answer (score 6):

It is undefined behaviour, but most compilers generate instructions which will handle this situation correctly if you access neither member variables nor the virtual table.

Let's see the disassembly generated by Visual Studio to understand what happens:

```
   Foo* foo = 0;
004114BE  mov         dword ptr [foo],0 
    foo->say_hi(); // works well
004114C5  mov         ecx,dword ptr [foo] 
004114C8  call        Foo::say_hi (411091h) 
    foo->say_virtual_hi(); // will crash the app
004114CD  mov         eax,dword ptr [foo] 
004114D0  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax] 
004114D2  mov         esi,esp 
004114D4  mov         ecx,dword ptr [foo] 
004114D7  mov         eax,dword ptr [edx] 
004114D9  call        eax
```

As you can see `Foo:say_hi` is called as a normal function, but with `this` in the `ecx` register. To simplify you can assume that `this` is passed as implicit parameter, which is never used in your example.
But in the second case the address of the function must be calculated, due to the virtual table - this requires that the address of `foo` is valid and causes a crash.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how can I get this disassembly in Visual Studio? I am using VS2008

Comment: Debug->Windows->Disassembly under debuger

Answer (score 3):

a) It works because it does not dereference anything through the implicit "this" pointer. As soon as you do that, boom. I'm not 100% sure, but I think null pointer dereferences are done by RW protecting first 1K of memory space, so there is a small chance of nullreferencing not getting caught if you only dereference it past 1K line (ie. some instance variable that would get allocated very far, like:

```
 class A {
     char foo[2048];
     int i;
 }
```

then a->i would possibly be uncaught when A is null.

b) Nowhere, you only declared a pointer, which is allocated on main():s stack.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to realize that *both* calls produce undefined behavior, and that behavior may manifest in unexpected ways. Even if the call *appears* to work, it may be laying down a minefield.

Consider this small change to your example:

```
Foo* foo = 0;
foo->say_hi(); // appears to work
if (foo != 0)
    foo->say_virtual_hi(); // why does it still crash?
```

Since the first call to `foo` enables undefined behavior if `foo` is null, the compiler is now free to assume that `foo` is *not* null. That makes the `if (foo != 0)` redundant, and the compiler can optimize it out! You might think this is a very senseless optimization, but the compiler writers have been getting very aggressive, and something like this has happened in actual code.

Answer (score 2):

The call to say_hi is statically bound. So the computer actually simply does a standard call to a function. The function doesn't use any fields, so there is no problem.

The call to virtual_say_hi is dynamically bound, so the processor goes to the virtual table, and since there is no virtual table there, it jumps somewhere random and crashes the program.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the original days of C++, the C++ code was converted to C. Object methods are converted to non-object methods like this (in your case):

```
foo_say_hi(Foo* thisPtr, /* other args */) 
{
}
```

Of course, the name foo_say_hi is simplified. For more details, look up C++ name mangling.

As you can see, if the thisPtr is never dereferenced, then the code is fine and succeeds. In your case, no instance variables or anything that depends on the thisPtr was used.

However, virtual functions are different. There's a lot of object lookups to make sure the right object pointer is passed as the paramter to the function. This will dereference the thisPtr and cause the exception.