# Fully understanding how .exe file is executed

Tags: windows, assembly, executable, disassembly

### Goal

I want to understand how executables work. I hope that understanding one very specific example in full detail will enable me to do so. My final (perhaps too ambitious) goal is to take a hello-world .exe file (compiled with a C compiler and linked) and understand in full detail how it is loaded into memory and executed by a x86 processor. If I succeed in doing so, I want to write an article and/or make a video about it, since I have not found something like this on the internet.

Specific questions I want to ask are marked in bold. Of course any further suggestions and sources doing something similar are very welcome. Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

### What I need

This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7959885/9988487) gives an overview of the process that C code goes through until it gets into physical memory as a programm. I'm not sure yet how much I want to look into how the C code is compiled. **Is there a way to view the Assembly code a C compiler generates before assembling it?** I may decide it's worth the effort to understand the processes of loading and linking. In the meantime the most important parts I need to understand are

- the PA executable file format
- the relation between assembler code and x86 byte-code
- the process of loading (i.e. how the process RAM is prepared for execution using information from the executable file).

I have a very basic understanding of the PA format (this understanding will be outlined in the section "What I have learned so far") and I think the sources given there should be sufficient, I just need to look into it some more until I know enough to understand a basic Hello-World programm. **Further sources on this topic are of course very welcome**.

The translation of byte-code into assembler code (disassembly) seems to be quite difficult for x86. Nonetheless, I would love to learn more about it. How would you go about disassembling a short byte code segment?

I'm still looking for a way to view the contents of a process' memory (the virtual memory assigned to it). I've already looked into windows-kernel32.dll functions such as `ReadProcessMemory` but couldn't get it to work yet. Also it's strange to me that there don't seem to be (free) tools available for this. Together with an understanding of loading, I may then be able to understand how a process is run from RAM. Also I'm looking for debugging tools for assembly programmers that allow to view the entire process virtual memory conents. My current starting point of this search is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2134411/9988487). Do you have further advice on **how I can see and understand loading and process execution from RAM?**

### What I have learned so far

The rest of this StackOverflow question describes what I have learned so far in some detail and giving various sources. It is meant to be reproducible and help anyone trying to understand this. However, I still do have some questions about the example I looked at so far.

#### PA format

In Windows, an executable file follows the **PA format**. The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) and [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/february/inside-windows-win32-portable-executable-file-format-in-detail) give a good overview of the format. The format describes what the individual bytes in an .exe file mean. The beginning is a DOS programm (included for legacy reasons) that I will not worry about. Then comes a bunch of headers, which give information about the executable. The actual file contents are split into sections that have names, such as '.rdata'. After the file headers, there are also section headers, which tell you which parts of the file are which section and what each section does (e.g. if it contains executable code).

The headers and sections can be parsed using tools such as dumpbin (microsoft tool to look at binary files). For comparison with dumpbin output, the hex code of a file can be viewed directly with a Hex editor or even using the Powershell (command `Format-Hex -Path <Path to file>`).

#### Specific example

I performed these steps for a very simple programm, which does nothing. This is the code:

```
; NASM assembler programm. Does nothing. Stores string in code section. 
; Adapted from stackoverflow.com/a/1029093/9988487
    global _main
    section .text
_main:
    hlt
    db      'Hello, World'
```

I assembled it with NASM (command `nasm -fwin32 filename.asm`) and linked it with the linker that comes with VS2019 (`link /subsystem:console /nodefaultlib /entry:main test.obj`). This is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029093/9988487), which demonstrates how to make a hello-world programm for Windows using WinAPI call. The programm runs on Windows 10 and terminates with no output. It takes **about 2 sec to run**, which seems very long and makes me think **there may be some error somehwere**?

I then looked at the dumpbin output:

```
D:\ASM>dumpbin test.exe /ALL
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.22.27905.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file test.exe

PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               2 number of sections
        5E96C000 time date stamp Wed Apr 15 10:04:16 2020
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
             102 characteristics
                   Executable
                   32 bit word machine

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic # (PE32)
           14.22 linker version
             200 size of code
             200 size of initialized data
               0 size of uninitialized data
            1000 entry point (00401000)
            1000 base of code
            2000 base of data
          400000 image base (00400000 to 00402FFF)
            1000 section alignment
             200 file alignment
            <further header values omitted ...>

SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
       E virtual size
    1000 virtual address (00401000 to 0040100D)
     200 size of raw data
     200 file pointer to raw data (00000200 to 000003FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read

RAW DATA #1
  00401000: F4 48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 0A        ôHello, World.

SECTION HEADER #2
  .rdata name
      58 virtual size
    2000 virtual address (00402000 to 00402057)
     200 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 000005FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only

RAW DATA #2
  00402000: 00 00 00 00 00 C0 96 5E 00 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00  .....À.^........
  00402010: 3C 00 00 00 1C 20 00 00 1C 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  <.... ..........
  00402020: 00 10 00 00 0E 00 00 00 2E 74 65 78 74 00 00 00  .........text...
  00402030: 00 20 00 00 1C 00 00 00 2E 72 64 61 74 61 00 00  . .......rdata..
  00402040: 1C 20 00 00 3C 00 00 00 2E 72 64 61 74 61 24 7A  . ..<....rdata$z
  00402050: 7A 7A 64 62 67 00 00 00                          zzdbg...

  Debug Directories

        Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
    -------- ------- -------- -------- --------
    5E96C000 coffgrp       3C 0000201C      41C

  Summary
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .text
```

The file header field "characteristics" is a combination of flags. In particular `102h = 1 0000 0010b` and the two set flags (according to the PE format doc) are `IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE` and `IMAGE_FILE_BYTES_REVERSED_HI`. The latter has description

> IMAGE_FILE_BYTES_REVERSED_HI:
>    Big endian: the MSB precedes the LSB in memory. This flag is deprecated and should be zero.

I ask myself: **Why does a modern assembler and a modern linker produce a deprecated flag?**

There are 2 sections in the file. The section `.text` was defined in the assembler code (and is the only one containing executable code, as specified in its header). **I don't know what the second section '.rdata' (name seems to refer to "readable data") is or does here.** Why was it created? How could I find out?

#### Disassembly

I used dumpbin to diassemble the .exe file (command `dumpbin test.exe /DISASM`). It gets the `hlt` correct, the 'Hello, World.' string is (perhaps unfortunately) interpreted as executable commands. I guess the disassembler can hardly be blamed for this. However, if I understand correctly (I have no practical experience in assembly programming), putting data into a code section is not unheard of (it was done in several examples that I found while looking into assembly programming). **Is there a better way to disassemle this, that would be able to reproduce my assembly code better**? Also, **do compilers sometimes put data into code sections in this way?**

Comment: Get a copy of [Windows Internals](https://www.amazon.com/Windows-Internals-Part-architecture-management-ebook/dp/B0711FDMRR/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=windows+internals&qid=1586943652&sr=8-1) - doesn't have to be the latest edition. It covers many of these issues in much greater detail than can be provided in a post here.

Comment: I don't mean to be mean but you got almost everything wrong. From the name of the exec format (PE, not PA) to the interpretation of the constants (which are given in hex). Your question is **very** broad, it's impossible to answer. When asked to exec a file, Windows kernel will: Create a new EPROCESS struct (with its address space), map the PEB, TEB and ntdll in that address space. Make an ETHREAD pointing (userspace) into ndll, which will read the image file. The PE header tells the loader how to map the section (where, protection). The DLL deps are processed. Hooks called and then jump to EP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some respects this is a massively broad question that may not survive for that reason. The information is all out there on the internet, keep looking, it is not complicated, and not worthy of a paper or video.

So you have a rough idea that a compiler takes a program written in one language and converts it to another language be that assembly language or machine code or whatever.

Then there are file formats and there are many different ones that we all use the term "binary" for but again, different formats.  Ideally they contain, using some form of encoding, the machine code and data or information about the data.

Going to use ARM for now, fixed length instructions easy to disassemble and read, etc.

```
#define ONE 1
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y = 5;
const unsigned int z = 7;
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a )
{
    return(a+ONE);
}
```

and gnu gcc/binutils because it is very well know, widely used, you can use it to make programs on your wintel machine.  I run Linux so you will see elf not exe, but that is just a file format for what you are asking.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c so.c -save-temps -o so.o
```

This toolchain (chain of tools that are linked for example compiler -> assembler -> linker) is Unix style and modular.  You are going to have an assembler for a target so not sure why you would want to re-invent that, and it is so much easier to debug a compiler by looking at the assembly output than trying to go straight to machine code.  But there are folks that like to climb the mountain just because it is there rather than go around and some tools go straight for machine code just because its there.

This specific compiler has this save temps feature, gcc itself is a front end program that preps for the real compiler then if asked for (if you don't say not to) will call the assembler and linker.

```
cat so.i
# 1 "so.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "so.c"


unsigned int x;
unsigned int y = 5;
const unsigned int z = 7;
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int a )
{
    return(a+1);
}
```

So at this point defines and includes are taken care of and its one big file to be sent to the compiler.

The compiler does its thing and turns it onto assembly language

```
cat so.s
    .cpu arm7tdmi
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 2
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "so.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global fun
    .arch armv4t
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   fun, %function
fun:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    add r0, r0, #1
    bx  lr
    .size   fun, .-fun
    .global z
    .global y
    .comm   x,4,4
    .section    .rodata
    .align  2
    .type   z, %object
    .size   z, 4
z:
    .word   7
    .data
    .align  2
    .type   y, %object
    .size   y, 4
y:
    .word   5
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.3.0"
```

which then gets put into an object file, in this case, binutils, linux default, etc

```
file so.o
so.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

It is using an elf file format which is easy to find info on, easy to write programs to parse, etc.

I can disassemble this, note that because I am using the disassembler it tries to disassemble everything even if it isn't machine code, sticking to 32 bit arm stuff It can grind through that and when there are real instructions they are shown (aligned and not variable length as used here, so you can disassemble linearly which you cannot with a variable length instruction set and have a hope of success (like x86) you need to disassemble in execution order and then you often miss some due to the nature of the program)

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <y>:
   0:   00000005    andeq   r0, r0, r5

Disassembly of section .rodata:

00000000 <z>:
   0:   00000007    andeq   r0, r0, r7

Disassembly of section .comment:

00000000 <.comment>:
   0:   43434700    movtmi  r4, #14080  ; 0x3700
   4:   4728203a            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x4728203a
   8:   2029554e    eorcs   r5, r9, lr, asr #10
   c:   2e332e39    mrccs   14, 1, r2, cr3, cr9, {1}
  10:   Address 0x0000000000000010 is out of bounds.


Disassembly of section .ARM.attributes:

00000000 <.ARM.attributes>:
   0:   00002941    andeq   r2, r0, r1, asr #18
   4:   61656100    cmnvs   r5, r0, lsl #2
   8:   01006962    tsteq   r0, r2, ror #18
   c:   0000001f    andeq   r0, r0, pc, lsl r0
  10:   00543405    subseq  r3, r4, r5, lsl #8
  14:   01080206    tsteq   r8, r6, lsl #4
  18:   04120109    ldreq   r0, [r2], #-265 ; 0xfffffef7
  1c:   01150114    tsteq   r5, r4, lsl r1
  20:   01180317    tsteq   r8, r7, lsl r3
  24:   011a0119    tsteq   r10, r9, lsl r1
  28:   Address 0x0000000000000028 is out of bounds.
```

and yes the tool put extra stuff in there, but note primarily that I created. some code, some initialized read/write data, some initialized read/write data and some initialized read only data.  The toolchain authors can use whatever names they want, they don't even have to use the term section.  But from decades of history and communication and terminology  .text is generally used for code (as in read only machine code AND related data), .bss for zeroed read/write data although I have seen other names, .data for initialized read/write data and this generation of this tool .rodata for read only initialized data (technically that could land in .text)

And note that they all have an address of zero.  they are not linked yet.

Now this is ugly but to avoid adding any more code and if the tool lets me do it, let's link it to make a completely unusable binary (no bootstrap, etc, etc):

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x1000 -Tdata=0x2000 so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000001000

arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <fun>:
    1000:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
    1004:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .data:

00002000 <y>:
    2000:   00000005    andeq   r0, r0, r5

Disassembly of section .rodata:

00001008 <z>:
    1008:   00000007    andeq   r0, r0, r7

Disassembly of section .bss:

00002004 <x>:
    2004:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

And now it is linked.  The read only items .text and .rodata landed in the .text address space in the order found in the file.  The read/write items landed in the .data address space in the order found in the file.

Yes, where was .bss in the object?  It is in there, it has no actual data as in bytes that are part of the object, instead it has a name and size and that it is .bss.  And for whatever reason the tool does show it from the linked binary.

So back on the term binary.  The so.elf binary has the bytes that go in memory that make up the program, but also file format infrastructure plus a symbol table to make the disassembly and debugging easier plus other stuff.  Elf is a flexible file format gnu can use it and you get one result some other tool or version of a tool can use it and have a different file.  And obviously two compilers can generate different machine code from the same source program not just due to optimizations, the job is to make a functional program in the target language and functional is the opinion of the compiler/tool author.

What about a memory image type file:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy so.elf so.bin -O binary
hexdump -C so.bin
00000000  01 00 80 e2 1e ff 2f e1  07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....../.........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00001000  05 00 00 00                                       |....|
00001004
```

Now how the objcopy tool works is that it starts with the first defined loadable or whatever term you want to use byte and ends with the last one and uses (zero) padding to make the file size match so that the memory image matches from an address perspective.  The asterisk means essentially 0 padding.  Because we started at 0x1000 with .text and 0x2000 for .data but the first byte of this file (offset 0) is the beginning of .text and 0x1000 byte later which is offset 0x1000 in the file but we know it goes to 0x2000 in memory is the read/write stuff.  Also note that the bss zeros are not in the output. The bootstrap is expected to zero those.

There is no information like where in memory this data from this file goes, etc.  And if you think a bit about it what if I have one byte at a section I define goes to 0x00000000 and one byte at a section I define goes to 0x80000000 and output this file, yes that is a 0x80000001 byte file even though there are only two useful bytes of relevant information.  A 2GB file to hold two bytes.   This is why you don't want to output this file format until you have sorted out your linker script and tools.

Same data and two other equally old school formats with a little history of intel vs motorola

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy so.elf so.hex -O ihex
cat so.hex
:08100000010080E21EFF2FE158
:0410080007000000DD
:0420000005000000D7
:0400000300001000E9
:00000001FF

arm-none-eabi-objcopy so.elf so.srec -O srec
cat so.srec
S00A0000736F2E7372656338
S10B1000010080E21EFF2FE154
S107100807000000D9
S107200005000000D3
S9031000EC
```

now these contain the relevant bytes, plus addresses, but not much other information, takes more than two bytes for every byte of data, but compared to a huge file with padding, a worthy trade-off.  Both of these formats can be found in use today, not as much as the old days but still there.

And countless other binary file formats and a tool like objdump has a decent list of formats it can generate as well as other linkers and/or tools out there.

What is relevant about all of this is that there is a binary file format of some form that contains the bytes we need to run the program.

What format and what addresses you might ask...That is part of the operating system or the system design.  In the case of Windows there are specific file formats and variations perhaps of those formats that are supported by the windows operating system, the specific version you are using.  Windows has determined what the address space looks like.  Operating systems like this take advantage of the MMU both for virtualizing addresses and protection.  Having a virtual address space means every program can live in the same space.  All programs can have an address that is zero based for example....

test.c

```
int main ( void )
{
    return 1;
}
```

hello.c

```
int main ( void )
{
    return 2;
}


gcc test.c -o test
objdump -D test

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000004003e0 <_start>:
  4003e0:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  4003e2:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  4003e5:   5e                      pop    %rsi
...

gcc hello.c -o hello
objdump -D hello

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000004003e0 <_start>:
  4003e0:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  4003e2:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
```

same address, how is that possible won't they sit on top of each other?  no virtual machine.  And note this is built for a specific Linux on a specific day, etc.  The toolchain has a default linker script (notice I didn't specify how to link) for this platform when the compiler was built for this target/platform.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 test.c -c -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-ld test.o -o test.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000008000
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D test.elf

test.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <main>:
    8000:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
    8004:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

same source code, same compiler, built for a different target and system different address.

So for Windows there are definitely going to be rules for the supported binary formats and rules for address spaces that can be used, how to define those spaces in the file.

Then it is a simple matter of the operating systems launcher to read the binary file and put the loadable items into memory at those addresses (in the virtual space that the os has created for this specific program)  It is very possible that a feature of the loader is to zero bss for you since the information is there.  The low level programmer needs to know that to possibly deal with zeroing .bss or not.

If not you will see and may need to create a solution, unfortunately this is where you get deeper into tool specific items.  While C may be somewhat standardized there are tool specific things that are not or at least are standardized by the tool/authors but no reason to assume those cross over to other tools.

```
.globl _start
_start:
    ldr sp,sp_init
    bl fun
    b .

.word __bss_start__
.word __bss_end__

sp_init:
.word 0x8000
```

Everything about assembly language is tool specific, the mnemonics for sanity reasons no doubt will resemble the ip/processor vendors documentation which uses syntax that the tool they paid to have developed uses.  But beyond that assembly language is wholly defined by the tool not the target, x86 because of its age and other things is really bad about that and this is not the Intel vs AT&T thing, just in general.  Gnu assembler is well known for I would assume perhaps intentionally not making compatible languages with other assembly languages.  The above is gnu assembler for arm.

Using the fun() function above, C says it should be main() but the tool doesn't care I am already typing enough here.

add a simple ram based linker script

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ram
    .bss : {
        __bss_start__ = .;
        *(.bss*)
     } > ram
        __bss_end__ = .;
}
```

build it all

```
arm-none-eabi-as start.s -o start.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -T sram.ld start.o so.o -o so.elf
```

examine

```
arm-none-eabi-nm so.elf
0000102c B __bss_end__
00001028 B __bss_start__
00001018 T fun
00001014 t sp_init
00001000 T _start
00001028 B x
00001024 D y
00001020 R z


arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <_start>:
    1000:   e59fd00c    ldr sp, [pc, #12]   ; 1014 <sp_init>
    1004:   eb000003    bl  1018 <fun>
    1008:   eafffffe    b   1008 <_start+0x8>
    100c:   00001028    andeq   r1, r0, r8, lsr #32
    1010:   0000102c    andeq   r1, r0, r12, lsr #32

00001014 <sp_init>:
    1014:   00008000    andeq   r8, r0, r0

00001018 <fun>:
    1018:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
    101c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .rodata:

00001020 <z>:
    1020:   00000007    andeq   r0, r0, r7

Disassembly of section .data:

00001024 <y>:
    1024:   00000005    andeq   r0, r0, r5

Disassembly of section .bss:

00001028 <x>:
    1028:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

So now it is possible to add to the bootstrap a memory zeroing loop (do not use C/memset you don't create chicken and egg problems you write the bootstrap in asm) based on the start and end addresses.

Fortunately or unfortunately because the linker script is tool specific and assembly language is tool specific and they need to work together if you are letting the tools do the work for you (the sane way to do it, have fun figuring out where .bss is otherwise).

This can be done on an operating system but when you get into say microcontrollers where it all has to be on non-volatile storage (flash) well it is possible to have one that is downloaded from elsewhere (like your mouse firmware sometimes, sometimes keyboard, etc) into ram, assume flash, so how do you deal with .data??

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x0000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .data : {
        *(.data*)
     } > ram AT > rom
    .bss : {
        __bss_start__ = .;
        *(.bss*)
     } > ram
        __bss_end__ = .;
}
```

With gnu ld this basically says that .data's home is in ram, but the output binary formats will put it in flash/rom

```
so.elf so.srec -O srec
cat so.srec
S00A0000736F2E7372656338
S11300000CD09FE5030000EBFEFFFFEA04100000A4
S11300100810000000800000010080E21EFF2FE1B4
S107002007000000D1  <-  z variable at address 0020
S107002405000000CF  <-  y variable at 0024
S9030000FC
```

and you have to play with the linker script more to get the tool to tell you both the ram and flash starting addresses and ending addresses or length. then add code in the bootstrap (asm not C) to copy .data from flash to ram.

Also note here per another one of your many questions.

```
.word __bss_start__
.word __bss_end__

sp_init:
.word 0x8000
```

These items are technically data.  but they live in .text first and foremost because they were defined in the code that was assumed to be .text (I didn't need to state that in the asm, but could have).  you will see this in x86 as well, but for fixed length like arm, mips, risc-v, etc where you cant put any old immediate/constant/linked value you want in the instruction itself you put it nearby in a "pool" and do a pc relative read to get it.  You will see this for linking externals too:

```
extern unsigned int x;
int main ( void )
{
    return x;
}


arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c test.c -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text.startup:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   e59f3004    ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; c <main+0xc>
   4:   e5930000    ldr r0, [r3]
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
   c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0   <--- the code gets the address of the
```

variable from here and then reads it from memory

once linked

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <main>:
    8000:   e59f3004    ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; 800c <main+0xc>
    8004:   e5930000    ldr r0, [r3]
    8008:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    800c:   00018010    andeq   r8, r1, r0, lsl r0

Disassembly of section .data:

00018010 <x>:
   18010:   00000005    andeq   r0, r0, r5
```

for x86

```
gcc -c -O2 test.c -o test.o
dwelch-desktop so # objdump -D test.o

test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text.startup:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 6 <main+0x6>
   6:   c3                      retq   


00000000004003e0 <main>:
  4003e0:   8b 05 4a 0c 20 00       mov    0x200c4a(%rip),%eax        # 601030 <x>
  4003e6:   c3                      retq
```

If you squint is it really different?  there is data nearby that the processor reads to load into a register and or use.  either way, due to the nature of the instruction sets the linker modifies the instruction or nearby pool data or both.

last one:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -S test.c 
cat test.s 
    .cpu arm7tdmi
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 6
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global main
    .arch armv4t
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   main, %function
main:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    str fp, [sp, #-4]!
    add fp, sp, #0
    ldr r3, .L3
    ldr r3, [r3]
    mov r0, r3
    add sp, fp, #0
    @ sp needed
    ldr fp, [sp], #4
    bx  lr
.L4:
    .align  2
.L3:
    .word   x
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.3.0"
```

So can you see the assembly language, yes some tools will let you save the intermediate files and/or let you generate the assembly output of the file when compiling.

Can you have data in the code, yes there are times and reasons to have data values in the .text area not just target specific you will see this for various reasons and some toolchains put read only data there.

There are many file formats the ones used by modern operating systems have features not just for defining the bytes that make up the machine code and data values but also will include symbols and other debug information.

The file format and memory space for a program is operating system specific not language nor even target specific (Linux, Windows, MacOS on the same laptop are not expected to have the same rules despite the exact same target computer).  A native toolchain for that platform has a default linker script and whatever other information required to build usable/working programs for that target.  Including the supported file format.

The machine code and data items can be represented in different file formats in different ways, whether or not the operating system or loader of the target system can use that format depends on that target system.

Programs have bugs and nuances.  File formats have versions and inconsistencies, you might find some elf file format reader only to find it doesn't work or prints out strange stuff when fed a perfectly good elf file that works on some system.  Why are some flags being set?  Perhaps those bytes got re-used or the flag to repurposed or the data structure changed or a tool is using it differently or in a non-standard way (think mov 20h,ax) and another tool that is not compatible can't understand or gets lucky and gets close enough.

Asking "why" questions at Stack Overflow is not very useful, the odds of finding the individual that wrote the thing are very low, better odds of asking the place you got the tool from and following that hoping the person is still alive and willing to be bothered.  And 99.999(lots of 9s)% there is no global set of godly rules that the thing was written under/for. General it was some dude just felt like it that is why they did what they did, no real reason, laziness, a bug, intentionally trying to break someone else's tool.  All the way up to a large committee of people with an opinion voted on it on a particular day in a particular room and that's why (and we know what we get when we design by committee or try to write specs that nobody conforms to).

I know you are on Windows and I don't have a Windows machine handy and am on Linux.  But the gnu/binutils and clang/llvm tools are readily available and have a rich set of tools like readelf, nm, objdump, etc.  That assist in examining things, a good tool is going to have that at least internally for the developers so they can debug the output of the tool to a certain quality level.  gnu folks made tools and made them available for everyone, and while it takes time to sort through them and their features they are very powerful for the things you are trying to understand.

You are NOT going to find a good x86 disassembler, they are all crap simply because of the nature of the beast.  It is a variable length instruction set, so by definition unless you are executing you cant sort it out correctly.  You must disassemble in execution order from a known good entry point to have half a chance, and then for various reasons there are code paths you cannot see that way (think jump tables for example, or dlls or so files).  The BEST solution is to have a very accurate/perfect emulator/simulator and run the code and perform all the actions/gyrations you need to do to get it to cover all the code paths, and have that tool record instructions from data and where each is located or each linear section without a branch.

The good side of this is that a lot of code is compiled today using tools that are not trying to hide anything.  In the old days for various reasons you would see hand written asm that intentionally tried to prevent disassembly or due to other factors (hand editing a binary rom image for a video game the day before the trade show, go disassemble some of the classic roms).

```
mov r0,#0
cmp r0,#0
jz somewhere
.word 0x12345678
```

A disassembler isn't going to figure this out, some might add a case for that then

```
mov r0,#0
nop
nop
xor r0,#1
nop
nop
xor r0,#3
xor r0,#2
cmp r0,#0
jz somewhere
.word 0x12345678
```

and it thinks that data is an instruction, for variable length that is super hard for a disassembler to resolve a decent one will at least detect collisions where the non opcode part of the instruction is branched to and/or an opcode part of an instruction shows up later as additional bytes in some other instruction.  The tool cant resolve it a human has to.

Even with arm and mips and having 32 and 16 bit instructions, risc-v with variable sized instructions, etc...

Very often gnu's disassembler will get tripped up with x86.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'll be able to answer to everything. I am a beginner too so I may say some things not exact. But, I'll try my best and I think I can bring you some things.

No, compilers do not put data in code sections (correct me if I am wrong). There is the section .data (for initialized data) and section .bss (for uninitialized data).

I think, I'll better show you an example of a program which prints hello world (for linux because it's much simpler and I don't know how to do with windows. in x64 but it's like x86. Just the names of the syscalls and the registers that are different. x64 is for 64 bits and x86 for 32 bits).

```
BITS 64 ;not obligatory but I prefer

section .data
msg db "hello world" ;the message
len equ $-msg ;the length of msg

section .text
global _start

_start: ;the entry point
mov rax, 1 ;syscall 1 to print something
mov rdi, 1 ;1 for stdout
mov rsi, msg ;the message 
mov rdx, len ;length in rdx
syscall

mov rax, 60 ;exit syscall
mov rdi, 0 ;exit with 0
syscall
```

(https://tio.run/#assembly-nasm if you don't want to use a VM. I advise you to look for WSL + vscode if you are using windows. you will have linux in your windows and vscode has an extension to have an access to the files in windows) but

If you wanna disassemble the code or see what is the memory, you can use gdb or radare2 in linux. For windows, there are other tools such as ghidra, IDA, olly dbg..

I don't know any way to make the compiler create a better assembly code. but it doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

I have never made anything for windows. However, to link my object file, I use ld (I don't know if it will be helpful).

```
ld object.o -o compiledprogram
```

I don't have time right now to continue writing so I can't advise you any courses right now.. I'll see later.

Hope it has helped you.

Comment: The OP is asking about Windows, not Linux, executables. Also, I don't see how this answer *any* of the OP questions. To be fair, the question is very broad and it would require a lot of time to write a proper answer. It is just that this answer is not useful.

Comment: No it answers at sole questions if you search it. Linux and windows are very similar when we have to program in assembly (I mean there are the same sections etc). So no. It does answer at the question. It's not the perfect answer but there are still answers.

Comment: Windows and Linux are **definitively not** similar, at all, in any of the aspects expression in this question. They are more similar in C than in assembly by the way. The fact that the architecture (IA32e) is the same means nothing.

Comment: no there are similar in some ways. I have never found any data in the code section (ok it may be the only I have answered..). Do you want me to delete my post ?

Comment: That's up to you :) I'm just pointing out that what works for Linux (e.g. dbg, radare2) doesn't work for Windows (where x96dbg, IDA, immunity dbg work better). If you want to convert this answer to Windows, I'd be happy to upvote it

Comment: @kamazoultane: you're correct that x86 compilers don't put read/write data in the `.text` or code section.  Read-only string data is often linked next to it or even in the same ELF segment (including `.text` and `.rodata` sections, or Windows `.rdata`).  Some binary obfuscators might do that ([Why do Compilers put data inside .text(code) section of the PE and ELF files and how does the CPU distinguish between data and code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55607052)) but mainstream compilers themselves definitely do not.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to questions in your text:
1. You can see process execution step by step and process memory with debugger. I used OllyDbg for learning assembly, it's free and powerful debugger.
2. Process is loaded by Windows kernel after calling NtCreateUserProcess so I think that you would need kernel debugging to see how it is done.
3. Code that is debugged in OllyDbg is automatically disassembled.
4. You can put read-only data in ".text" section. You can change section flags to make it writable, then code and data can be mixed. Some compilers may merge ".text" and ".rdata" sections.

I would recommend that you read about PE imports, exports, relocations and resources in that order. If you want to see easiest possible i386 PE helloworld you can check my hello_world_pe_i386_dynamic.exe program here: https://github.com/pajacol/hello-world. I wrote it entirely in binary file editor. It contains only required data structures. This executable is position independent and can be loaded at any address without relocations.