# Puzzle - Determine which of the addresses belong to global/local/heap variables

Tags: c, hex, memory-address

I have the following Puzzle to solve and I am not really sure how I could do that. It says:

There's an Ubuntu Linux C program which outputs the addresses of variables.

```
v1: 0xa156128
v2: 0xff97410c
v3: 0xf750e34b
v4: 0x804a0c0
```

I know that the program uses no shared memory and at least one of those variables is a heap variable. Which one of those variables are `global` / `local` / `heap`.

That's all the information available and I am really interested in any ideas towards solving this puzzle.

Edit after reading comments:

If I look at the Runtime - Storage  Organization link (http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node33.html) there it seems likely that `v2` and `v3` are the local variables for having the biggest address, `v1` being the heap variable since it's between stack and static data and `v4` being the global variable which doesn't get declared on the stack at runtime like the locals, but rather in the .data section of the binary.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I have a strong feeling that this question makes no sense.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1966920/1679849

Comment: Thanks for the link @squeamishossifrage . I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try analyzing contents of /proc/PID/maps (see proc(5)). I believe this is the most correct way to determine the memory region an address belongs to.