# Calling class method through NULL class pointer

Tags: c++

I have following code snippet:

```
class ABC{
public:
        int a;
        void print(){cout<<"hello"<<endl;}
};

int main(){
        ABC *ptr = NULL:
        ptr->print();
        return 0;
}
```

It runs successfully. Can someone explain it?

Comment: Can anyone gives more details about runtime of this code? It runs because the class pointer is not using any member variable in print function but it means at runtime it is able to execute the member function (by executing code section?). Sorry i am not a experienced C++ programmer.

Comment: That question is about dereferencing an indeterminate pointer; so although the reason that it appears to work is the same; the (lack of) validity of the code is covered by different C++ rules.

Comment: note that is `print` is virtual, it'll crash(segmentation fault)!! read about `vtables`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Under the hood most compilers will transform your class to something like this:

```cpp
struct _ABC_data{  
    int a ;  
};  
// table of member functions 
void _ABC_print( _ABC_data* this );
```

where `_ABC_data` is a [C-style struct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data)
and your call `ptr->print();` will be transformed to:

```cpp
_ABC_print(nullptr)
```

which is alright while execution since you do not use `this` arg.

---

**UPDATE:** (Thanks to Windows programmer for [right comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505328/calling-class-member-through-uninitialized-class-pointer/2505532#2505532))
Such code is alright only for CPU which executes it.
There is absolutely positively no sane reason to exploit this *implementation* feature. Because:

1. Standard states it yields undefined behavior
2. If you actually need ability to call member function without instance, using `static` keyword gives you that with all the portability and compile-time checks

Comment: The problem with relying on this behaviour is that it is compiler specific. A different compiler might well store a vtable with each instance (though that would perform pretty badly) or a pointer to a common vtable (slighty better) and call all functions like this by actually dereferencing the pointer. AFAIK that would be a legal compiler implementation, causing this code to crash.

Comment: @wds: why call non-virtual function via vtable ?

Comment: "Because standard states it yields undefined behavior (could anyone give a link or at least reference(chapter N, par M...)?)" See this other answer, which makes it clear that it's UB, which IMO is all that needs to - and should be - said to such questions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2505559/2757035

Comment: What about template class methods that only use `this` depending on the instantiation? Some might be defined in terms of static variables, some calls could dispatch/resolve differently, etc. You could know a method is going to be defined (as if) statically, just not how, and you still need the value. It's the same reason you use `std::declval` under `decltype` - you could guarantee that any instance would produce the same result, but not necessarily that you could make one. Oh well, maybe someday there'll be a way.

Answer (score 37):

Calling member functions using a pointer that does not point to a valid object results in *undefined behavior*.  Anything could happen.  It could run; it could crash.

In this case, it *appears* to work because the `this` pointer, which does not point to a valid object, is not used in `print`.

Comment: its "undefined behavior" but how it is working?  I mean to say as it is running then what's happening at run-time which makes it working.

Comment: @Adil - the function does not use any data from the object nor call any virtual member functions, so the compiler did not generate any references to the bad pointer. You got lucky, and another compiler (or the next version of your current one) could crash on the very same code.

Comment: @MarkRansom - which will never happen :D Still, it's best to use static where _cdecl is the correct over _thiscall

Comment: @ПетърПетров you'd be surprised the kinds of trouble that recent advances in optimization are causing in regards to undefined behavior. Best to avoid it altogether, even when you can rationalize why it might work.

Comment: I am surprised all the times, however it's unlikely somebody will change __thiscall on non-virtual this pointer soon. I use this!=nullptr checks only in debug code however

Answer (score 17):

Most answers said that undefined behaviour can include "appearing" to work, and they are right.

Alexander Malakhov's answer gave implementation details which are kind of common and explain why your situation appeared to work, but he made a slight misstatement.  He wrote "which is alright while execution since you do not use this arg" but meant "which appeared to be alright while execution since you do not use this arg".

But be warned, your code still is undefined behaviour.  It printed what you wanted AND it transfered the balance of your bank account to mine.  I thank you.

(SO style says this should be a comment but it's too long.  I made it CW though.)

Comment: Why should this be a comment? I think it's a good answer.

Comment: Because it was primarily a joke.  Jokes belong in comments not in answers.  If other answerers hadn't already given the real answer then I'd have explained the real answer followed by a joke.

Answer (score 7):

It leads to undefined behavior. I put a [bit of work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-behav) into explaining why. :) But that's a more technical answer.

Basically, undefined behavior means you are no longer guaranteed anything about the execution of the program; C++ simply has nothing to say. It could work exactly how you want, or it could crash miserably, or it could do both randomly.

So *appearing to work* is a perfectly fine result of undefined behavior, which is what you're seeing. The practical reason why is, on your implementation (and in honestly, every implementation), the `this` pointer (the address of the instance being invoked) isn't being used at all in your function. That said, if you tried to use the `this` pointer (for example by accessing a member variable), you'd likely crash.

Remember, the above paragraph is something specific to your implementation and it's current behavior. It's just a guess and something you can't rely on.

Comment: its "undefined behavior" but how it is working?  I mean to say as it is running then what's happening at run-time which makes it working.

Comment: @Adil: It's undefined. Alexander explains it well, but that's *not* guaranteed to work. It's simply something you can't count on.

Answer (score 7):

Expression `ptr->print();` will be implicitly converted to `(*ptr).print();` according to C++ Standard (5.2.5/3). And dereferencing the null pointer leads to undefined behaviour. It is fortuitous that the code in question works without errors in your case. You should not rely on it.

> 5.2.5/3:
>
> If E1 has the type “pointer to class
> X,” then the expression E1->E2 is
> converted to the equivalent form
> (*(E1)).E2; the remainder of 5.2.5
> will address only the first option
> (dot)59). Abbreviating
> objectexpression. id-expression as
> E1.E2, then the type and lvalue
> properties of this expression are
> determined as follows. In the
> remainder of 5.2.5, cq represents
> either const or the absence of const;
> vq represents either volatile or the
> absence of volatile. cv represents an
> arbitrary set of cv-qualifiers, as
> defined in 3.9.3.

Comment: The implicit conversion isn't a problem.  Also if the programmer had written (*ptr).print() then there still wouldn't be a syntactic problem.  The problem is that ptr doesn't point to an actual object and ptr is being dereferenced.

Comment: ...which is what Kirill said.

Answer (score 5):

Though I am not sure if this is the exact answer, this is my understanding. (Also, my terminology for CPP is bad - ignore that if possible)

For C++, when any class is declared (i.e. no instant created yet), the functions are placed in the .text section of the binary being created. When an instant is created, Functions or Methods are *not* duplicated. That is, when the compiler is parsing the CPP file, it would replace the function calls for `ptr->print()` with appropriate address defined in the .text section.

Thus, all the compiler would have done is replace appropriate address based on the *type* of `ptr` for function `print`. (Which also means some checking related public/private/inheritance etc)

I did the following for your code (named `test12.cpp`):

*EDIT: Adding some comments to ASM below ( I really am _not_ good at ASM, I can barely read it - just enough to understand some basic stuff) - best would be to read [this Wikibook link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax), which I too have done :D
In case someone finds errors in the ASW, please do leave a comment - I would glad to fix them and learn more too.*

```
$ g++ test.cpp -S
$ cat test.s
...
         // Following snippet is part of main function call
         movl    $0, -8(%ebp)   //this is for creating the NULL pointer ABC* ptr=NULL
                                //It sets first 8 bytes on stack to '0'
         movl    -8(%ebp), %eax //Load the ptr pointer into eax register
         movl    %eax, (%esp)   //Push the ptr on stack for using in function being called below
                                //This is being done assuming that these elements would be used
                                //in the print() function being called
         call    _ZN3ABC5printE //Call to print function after pushing arguments (which are none) and 
                                //accesss pointer (ptr) on stack.
...
```

vWhere `ZN3ABC5printEv` represents the global definition of the function defined in `class ABC`:

```
  ...
  .LC0:                    //This declares a label named .LC0
          .string "hello"  // String "hello" which was passed in print()
          .section        .text._ZN3ABC5printEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZN3ABC5printEv,comdat
          .align 2
          .weak   _ZN3ABC5printEv             //Not sure, but something to do with name mangling
          .type   _ZN3ABC5printEv, @function
  _ZN3ABC5printEv:                   //Label for function print() with mangled name
  //following is the function definition for print() function
  .LFB1401:                          //One more lavbel
          pushl   %ebp               //Save the 'last' known working frame pointer
  .LCFI9:
          movl    %esp, %ebp         //Set frame (base pointer ebp) to current stack top (esp)
  .LCFI10:
          subl    $8, %esp           //Allocating 8 bytes space on stack
  .LCFI11:
          movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)     //Pushing the string represented by label .LC0 in 
                                     //in first 4 bytes of stack
          movl    $_ZSt4cout, (%esp) //Something to do with "cout<<" statement
          call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
          movl    $_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_, 4(%esp)
          movl    %eax, (%esp)
          call    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E   //Probably call to some run time library for 'cout'
          leave                      //end of print() function
          ret                        //returning control back to main() 
  ...
```

Thus, even `((ABC *)0)->print();` works perfectly well.

Comment: For people like me it's pretty hard to figure out what this code does at a glance. Could you make it a little more comprehensible. Say, add comments like *.LCFI11: // moving args for **operator <<** to register ESP*, *movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp) // put "hello" on ESP*.  
And replace generated names with more readable ones, like *$_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_* ==> *$_endl*. Those are pure technical details and really do not help to understand what is going on

Comment: @Alexander, thanks for suggestion and you are right - Sorry being a little ignorant. I have added comments about whatever I know, which certainly is not much.

Answer (score 4):

probably it runs because your class pointer is not using any member variable in print function...If in print function you try to access a it will not run... as uninitialized class pointer can't have initialized member variable...

Answer (score 3):

As others said, it is undefined behavior. Regarding the reason why it appears to work is that you are not trying to access the member variable `a` inside the `print()`. All the instances of the class share same memory for the code of `print()` hence `this` pointer is not required to access the method. However, if you try to access `a` inside the method you are most likely to get an access violation exception.

Comment: Can you please give a link or draft where it is mentioned that it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

This works on every compiler I have ever tried it on (And I've tried it on many).  Yes it is "undefined" but you are not dereferencing the pointer when you call a non-virtual member.  You can even write code using this "feature" although purists will yell at you and call you nasty names and such.

Edit: There seems to be some confusion here about calling member functions.  You are NOT dereferencing the 'this' pointer when you call a non-virtual member. You are simply using fancy syntax to pass it in as a parameter.  This is with all implementations I have seen, but it's not guaranteed.  If it wasn't implemented this way, your code would run slower. A member function is simply a function with and extra semi-hidden parameter. That's it! end of story. That being said there may be some compiler written by Cletus' slack jaw software Co. that has a problem with this, but I haven't run into it yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893251/why-does-the-enhanced-gcc-6-optimizer-break-practical-c-code

Answer (score 1):

This one will explain you more than if I use plain words. Try compiling it with any compiler you want :) But note, it's UB according to standards!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Armor
{
public:
    void set(int data)
    {
        cout << "set("<<data<<")\n";
        if(!this)
        {
            cout << "I am called on NULL object! I prefer to not crash!\n";
            return;
        }
        this->data = data;  //dereference it here
    }
    void get()
    {
        if(this) cout << "data = " << data << "\n";
        else cout << "Trying to dereference null pointer detected!\n";
    }
    int data;
};

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   Armor a;
   a.set(100);
   a.get();


   Armor* ptr1 = &a;
   Armor* ptr2 = 0;

   ptr1->set(111);
   ptr2->set(222);

   ptr1->get();
   ptr2->get();

   return 0;
}
```

Then read about __thiscall - and all comments above.

```
Hello World
set(100)
data = 100
set(111)
set(222)
I am called on NULL object! I prefer to not crash!
data = 111
Trying to dereference null pointer detected!
```

Comment: Can you explain what compiler internally does while calling get function

Comment: On MSVC I got __thiscall issued with "this" field being set as zero, this way the **this** pointer is properly set to zero, and the if() fails. On GCC the result was the same even if I don't know what compiler did exactly.

Comment: Does compiler treat every function as STATIC FUNCTION if that function doesnt contains any class variables in it? If so, this could be the reason why get function gets called?

Comment: Every. Every os-level function is staying somewhere in your RAM and has its address. Even virtual functions. In C++, on most compilers, non virtual class members are implemented as normal functions using so called thiscall calling convention. Read about this and what a stack actually is. And how compilers work. Then you will be able to abuse undefined behavior as you like :)

Comment: Accessing class members is implemented via simple pointer additions.  If you have strict with data members int32_t a, b,  then 'this' pointer will point exactly to a,  and this+4 to b. If you call a non virtual function that dereferences this.a with this being a null pointer, this.b will have absolute address of 4, while this.a will be 0. As soon as code tries to read or write from these invalid addresses, the OS itself will throw access violation exception. You of course can handle that and continue execution as you like.

Comment: And also note that calling virtual function on null pointer to class will try to dereference the object's so called VTABLE which will throw access violation exception immediately  and will not jump into the code. You can however somehow get a pointer to virtual function and try to call it directly by abusing function pointers and void*

Comment: Also about invocation: the linker and the shared library loader are responsible for loading and memory mapping all functions in your program and its libraries.  C++ classes get flattered down to arbitrary functions. For example the Armor::set(int data) may get represented as armor_set(intptr this, int data) by the linker and since it's class member,  first argument is the 'this' pointer. Compiler itself cares about pointers and when you type ptr->set(10) it hardcodes as machine code armor_set(ptr, 10). So it behaves like static friction.

Comment: Thank you  Петър Петров for your valuable reply.

Comment: And also note that true inline functions are not OS functions. They have no calling convention and no address