# What will happen when I call a member function on a NULL object pointer?

Tags: c++

I was given the following as an interview question:

```
class A
{
public:
    void fun()
    {
        std::cout << "fun" << std::endl;
    }
};

A* a = NULL;
a->fun();
```

What will happen when this code is executed, and why?

---

#### See also:

- [When does invoking a member function on a null instance result in undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-behav)

Comment: Looks like a null pointer exception waiting to happen to me.  Why don't you compile, run, and see for yourself instead of asking here?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Or if the code is to be taken literally as a complete unit, a compilation error.

Comment: Tricky question, or trick question?  It won't compile because `Class` (capital C) isn't a C++ keyword.

Comment: Please show the real question. Until then, i think we can't really answer seriously.

Comment: class keyword error and fun() private corrected. @ Johannes: This is the real question, it was asked as it is presented here.

Comment: @ duffymo, I have checked it and it prints "fun" and I couldn't figure out why, so I asked here.

Comment: Assuming that it compiles (i.e. that this is not meant to be the complete compilation unit), and that `NULL` has its usual definition, the answer "nasal demons" would probably get you bonus points for the interview :) http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html

Comment: @Rajendra It doesn'nt matter what it does when you compile it with your specific compiler, the C++ Standard says that dereferencing a null pointer is undefined. So the next iteration of your compiler, or another compiler might do something different, but equally undefined.

Comment: How is this "tricky"? It's basic and, if you ask me, rather pointless. Creating a pointer, initializing it to NULL and using it in the very next line - how "typical"!

Comment: Why was this closed and even worse, why is this being voted to delete? It is a valid question; it happens because of UB. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Amarghosh: because it was a lousy question. Fortunately, it is slowly improving...

Comment: @DanielDaranas that is not basic at all, this case of "using it" -as you put it-, is a pure vue d'esprit, a mere syntax construct to tell the compiler to resolve the type of a. The pointer is not followed so there is no "dereferencing null" here. (Since there is no dereferencing at all) Therefore, it is not UB.

Comment: Adding a 2nd comment here. The only way this could be seen as UB, is if we think of it like Java or C#. Where the instance actually matters to the abstract machine, since methods are fields (a la python). However this is not python, and C++ _can_ define the behavior of this case with a bit of discrimination: notably the case where there is no virtuality.

Comment: @v.oddou Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2505559/96780) in a linked question.

Comment: @v.oddou See also [this more thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474021/96780) to the question [When does invoking a member function on a null instance result in undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2474018/96780).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's undefined behavior, so anything might happen.

A possible result would be that it just prints `"fun"` since the method doesn't access any member variables of the object it is called on (the memory where the object supposedly lives doesn't need to be accessed, so access violations don't necessarily occur).

Comment: Where is the address of the member function stored for a C++ class and how can it be accessed using the NULL pointer to the object of that class?

Comment: @Kamal If the function is not virtual, then it gets statically linked. No need for a table. No need for the object pointer.

Comment: @Kamal The compiler could use static information (it knows the pointer is of type A) to find the function. The fact that the compiler can do this does mean that it must, and does not prevent this from being undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Kamal: Who said it must be stored? The compiler can transform the function call into `A::fun(a)`.

Comment: @Kamal: The compiler knows the type of the object and the address of the method that should be called at compile time and can insert that address "hard coded". There is no need to look anything up at runtime. (This doesn't mean the compiler *has* to do it that way, but it could.)

Comment: The object qualifies as POD, so I don't believe the compiler is allowed to have any hidden fields in the object to be used for finding member functions.  That being the case, it would be very surprising if the compiler couldn't find the correct member function.  It's not even allowed to have a lookup table mapping object pointers to member functions, due to the lifetime rules for POD types.  There's very little flexibility in member function resolution here.  Really, the fact that this is undefined behavior allows the compiler to inject an explicit null check to aid in debugging.

Comment: I want a proof with explicit standard quoting, that this is undefined behavior. In my book on the contrary, it's very provable (both statically and in the abstract machine) that the object and the method are callable from null since the function address is hard-replaced at compile time, and `this` is not dereferenced. Actually even `a` itself isn't dereferenced, it just looks like it, but it could be written as `decltype(a)::fun(a);` (after an imaginary step of build where implicit _this_ pointers are resolved to first parameters)

Comment: @v.oddou: See here for a discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-behav

Comment: While it is true that it's undefined behaviour, and anything could happen, the fact is that functions don't exist within the class. In this situation, the functions are "bound" / associated to the outside class datatype. It's like an extension of the C structure, and this binding is done at the compilation phase, to the type; rather than at run time, in the instantiation phase. This is why I think you see so many compilers behaving in this way. Functions are not physically stored "inside" the class.

Answer (score 28):

By the standard, this is undefined behavior and therefore a very bad thing. In reality of most programming platforms (across both X86 and several other architectures) this will run fine.

Why? Consider how class functions are implemented in C++. This isn't a virtual function, therefor this can be a static call to a known address.
In x86 assembly, we can see this as

```
mov A, 0
mov ecx, A
call a__fun
```

since a__fun requires no instance data, even though it receives a null this pointer, nothing will happen.

Still shitty code and any compiler will scream, but it can run.

Comment: Yes, this is undefined behavior.  Yes, this *may* run as expected on a given architecture.  However it is wise to always keep the following wisdom in mind: "The worst possible outcome of undefined behavior is for it to do what you were expecting."

Comment: This answer ignores all "optimisations". If the compiler can see that the pointer is null it can just elide the call entirely. You're focused too much on the low level details of what happens to the call _if_ it happens. But there's a reason we call it undefined. That's not the same as "basically works".

Answer (score 20):

The most likely behavior, on most modern computers, is that it will run, and print "fun", because:

- C++ doesn't check whether the pointer is NULL before calling the function
- `fun()` is not virtual, so there's no need to refer to a vtable to call `fun()`
- `fun()` never access any member variables in `A` so it doesn't need to dereference
  the null `this` pointer.

Comment: 3. `A* a = NULL; a->fun();` is illegal outside of a function body.

Comment: But I think we still can bend our minds and sort of understand what he meant

Answer (score 11):

We can't know what *will*. Everything *can* happen, because the program exposes undefined behavior. See [Does invoking a member function on a null instance cause undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-behav).

Answer (score 6):

I have tried multiple times,all the time output is coming "fun" this is because function `fun` is independent of instance `a`. while calling `a->fun();` `a` points to 0 so this is undefined behavior but in most of the compilers there should be no crash.

Comment: `A* a = NULL;` emphatically does not result in a constructor call

Comment: You tried multiple times on which hardware with which compiler? Just because it didn't crash for you, doesn't mean it's guaranteed to not crash.

Answer (score 5):

Three points might help:

1) All Functions are stored in code or text section.

2) Non Virtual functions are resolved at complie time.

3) While calling to member functions of class, we pass current object as `this` pointer to that function.

Coming to your question , here `fun()` function is already in memory(code section / text section).
As function `fun()` is non virtual , it will be resolved at complie time (i.e, for this line it will jump to instruction X at code section with `this` pointer as `NULL`).
As no member variable and no virtual function are used/called in `fun()` function, it is working fine.

Comment: Can't anyone compile this and see what it really does?