# Segfault when returning private member

Tags: c++, qt

i have a problem debugging my code. In some Qt Slot i do this:

```
UIElementInterface* interface = qobject_cast <UIElementInterface*>(sender());
```

and the following line gives me a segmentation fault:

```
QStringList data = interface->getSetDefData();
```

this doesn't

```
QString hello = interface->getHello();
```

The implementation of `getSetDefData()` inside of `UIElementInterface`:

```
class UIElementInterface
{
public:
    ...
    UIElementInterface(const QStringList& data) : m_setDefData(data)
    {
        std::cout << qPrintable(m_setDefData[0]) << std::endl; //everything as expected here..
    }

    QStringList getSetDefData(){return m_setDefData;} //gives seg fault
    QString getHello(){return QString("Hello");} //works fine

private:
    QStringList m_setDefData;
};
```

I would appreciate any help on this one :)

**EDIT**
Based on the comments i used `qobject_cast` to cast to a `CheckBox`, which definitely is the sender (in the case of the crash) and It is a subclassed `QCheckBox`. So it definitely ihnerits `QObject` (i also double checked the implementation). When I check the return value as suggested it turns out to be `0`.

```
CheckBox* b = qobject_cast<CheckBox*>(sender());
if (b == 0)
{
    std::cout << "Here we are" << std::endl;
}
```

so that is the problem. I still need to figure out why this is, but this probably causes the crash.

**ANOTHER EDIT** Printing out the class name `sender()->metaObject()->className()` exposed the root of evil:

`QSignalMapper`

Case closed :)

Comment: Classical case of crash when `this == NULL`, a NULL (or invalid) pointer object: `getSetDefData()` dereferences `this`, the `getHello()` doesn't.

Comment: The [documentation for `qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#qobject_cast) clearly says it can return `0` which is the same as a null pointer, something you obviously don't check for.

Comment: So if the implementation for `getSetDefData()` would be in a class that inherits `QObject` this would not happen?

Comment: @Dummy00001 could you give some more Information about that please? Calling the constructor does not prevent that object from being NULL?

Comment: @tobilocker, no, you have to check that the pointer returned by `qobject_cast<>()` is not NULL.

Comment: I used a static_cast and have the same issue.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669742/accessing-class-members-on-a-null-pointer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431420/why-doesnt-the-program-crash-when-i-call-a-member-function-through-a-null-point

Comment: basically the sender probably isnt one of these `UIElementInterface`

Comment: If you were using a signal mapper, why didn't you use the `QSignalMapper::mapped(QObject *object)` or `QSignalMapper::mapped(QWidget *widget)` signal?

Answer (score 0):

It's clear from the `UIElementInterface` class declaration that the class is not a `QObject`. Qt documentation on `qobject_cast` function states that:

> The class T must inherit (directly or indirectly) QObject and be
>   declared with the Q_OBJECT macro.

Thus you cannot use `qobject_cast` with `UIElementInterface` class.