# Why does this code snippet work? How can a nullptr be dereferenced?

Tags: c++, pointers, static, static-methods, nullptr

```
#include <iostream>

class Singleton {
private:
    static Singleton* s_instance;

public:
    static Singleton& Get() {
        return *s_instance;
    }

    void Hello() {
        std::cout << "Hey Bro" << std::endl;
    }
};

Singleton* Singleton::s_instance = nullptr;

int main() {
    Singleton::Get().Hello();
    return 0;
}
```

And it prints the output from the member function Hello(). How can a nullptr be dereferenced in the static member function Get()

P.S: This code snippet was taken from the Cherno C++ series on YouTube.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533476/what-will-happen-when-i-call-a-member-function-on-a-null-object-pointer . As for the Youtube tutorial, it may be better to ditch it in favor of a good book https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: What do you mean by "work"?  On my machine, this code crashes.

Comment: Dereferencing `nullptr` causes undefined behaviour.   The meaning of "undefined" in C++ is essentially "the C++ standard does not place any constraints on what happens".    Practically, that doesn't require a runtime error, or anything else - it is within the bounds of undefined behaviour that it can seem to "work" - for any definition a programmer may place on "work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour, as StoryTeller says.

Most probably it "works" because you don't actually *use* the pointer at the assembly level.

Member functiors are static functions which take the `this` pointer. In your member function `Hello()`, `this` is not used because you are not accessing any member variables. So the function is actually a  `void Hello(Singleton* this) {}` which is passed a null, but noone uses it, so no crash. There is some similarity when using `delete this;` in some member function; the members are destructed, but not the function body itself.

But as said, it's UD, anything can happen. Never rely on such behaviour.