# How to correctly downcast a base class using dynamic cast in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Let parent class `A` and a child class `B` be

```
// A.h
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"

struct B : public A {
    void print() override {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Then in a program the following is possible:

```
int main() {

    A a1;
    a1.print();  // <-- "A"

    B b1;
    b1.print();  // <-- "B"
    
    A* a2 = new B();
    a2->print(); // <-- "B"
}
```

However, the following crashes:

```
B* b2 = dynamic_cast<B*>(new A());
b2->print(); // <-- Crashes
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: An `A` is not a valid `B` - that's why the cast returns a nullpointer

Comment: As a general rule if you're using a dynamic_cast question your design. But you already have your answer as to why it crashes :)

Comment: Read about what `dynamic_cast` does. The code in the question has a fundamental mistake.

Answer (score 2):

`A` does not derive from `B` (the reverse is true).  You are creating an instance of `A`, not of `B`.  Using `dynamic_cast` to cast an `A` object into a `B*` pointer will result in a null pointer, which you are not checking for before calling `B::print()`.  Calling a non-static class method via a null pointer is *undefined behavior*, see: [What will happen when I call a member function on a NULL object pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533476/)

Comment: I found I can use `static_cast` :  `B* b2 = static_cast<B*>(new A()); b2->print(); // 'A'`.

Comment: @TMOTTM still *undefined behavior*, since you are not creating a `B` instance to begin with. Give `B` some data members that `print()` accesses, and you will see that code fail at runtime. Just because it compiles doesn't make it right.