# getting a segfault when I try to deep copy `unique_ptr`s

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, move-semantics

Why can't I return a `unique_ptr` from a `clone` function? I thought [I could do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions).

I have a base class for different mathematical functions called `transform`. I have a container of pointers to this type because I am using polymorphism. For example, all these derived classes have a different implementation of `log_jacobian` that is useful for statistical algorithms.

I am using `unique_ptr`s to this `transform` class, and so I have made a (pure virtual) `clone` function that makes new `unique_ptr` pointing to a deep copy of the same mathematical `transform` object. This new object is of the same type that derives from `transform<float_t>`, but it's a separate because you can't have two `unique_ptr`s pointing to the same thing.

```
template<typename float_t>
class transform{
...
virtual std::unique_ptr<transform<float_t>> clone() const = 0;
...
};
```

My `transform_container` class holds a few of these at a time. After all, most statistical models have more than one parameter.

```
template<typename float_t, size_t numelem>
class transform_container{
private:

    using array_ptrs = std::array<std::unique_ptr<transform<float_t>>, numelem>;
    array_ptrs m_ts;
    unsigned m_add_idx;
...
    auto get_transforms() const -> array_ptrs;
};
```

I'm not sure why the deep copy function `get_transforms` isn't working, though. It is used to make copies, and to access individual transformations from the container. I get a segfault when I run some tests. If I run it in `gdb`, it explicitly tells me the line with a comment after it is bad.

```
template<typename float_t, size_t numelem>
auto transform_container<float_t,numelem>::get_transforms() const -> array_ptrs
{
    array_ptrs deep_cpy;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numelem; ++i){
        deep_cpy[i] = m_ts[i]->clone(); // this line
    }
    return deep_cpy;
}
```

I've also tried `std::move`ing it into `deep_cpy[i]` and using `unique_ptr::reset`, but to no avail.

#### Edit:

here are some other relevant methods: a method that adds transforms to `transform_container`, and the factory method for the individual `transform`:

```
template<typename float_t>
std::unique_ptr<transform<float_t> > transform<float_t>::create(trans_type tt)
{
    if(tt == trans_type::TT_null){
        
        return std::unique_ptr<transform<float_t> >(new null_trans<float_t> );
    
    }else if(tt == trans_type::TT_twice_fisher){
        
        return std::unique_ptr<transform<float_t> >(new twice_fisher_trans<float_t> );
    
    }else if(tt == trans_type::TT_logit){
        
        return std::unique_ptr<transform<float_t> >(new logit_trans<float_t> );
    
    }else if(tt == trans_type::TT_log){

        return std::unique_ptr<transform<float_t> >(new log_trans<float_t> );
    
    }else{

        throw std::invalid_argument("that transform type was not accounted for");
    
    }
}

template<typename float_t, size_t numelem>
void transform_container<float_t, numelem>::add_transform(trans_type tt)
{
    m_ts[m_add_idx] = transform<float_t>::create(tt);
    m_add_idx++;
}
```

Comment: Are all `numelem` elements of the `m_ts` array valid? I.e. are all pointers initialized and pointing to an actual `transform<float_t>` object?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.  I wrote up a quick toy program, and it works without a problem.

Comment: Then all unique pointer objects in the array will be default constructed which means they will be null pointers. Do you initialize *all* `numelem` pointers somewhere else? Actually make them point somewhere?

Comment: Add `if (!m_ts[i]) throw "oopsies";` just before the line that has the problem.  Out of paranoia.

Comment: @Taylor: Yes, you can't tell a thing that doesn't exist to make a clone of itself

Comment: Also, learn how to use a debugger; you'll be able to halt at the moment of crash and examine variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `get_transforms()`, you are looping over the *entire* `m_ts[]` array, calling `clone()` on *all* elements - even ones that have not been assigned by `add_transform()` yet!  Unassigned `unique_ptr`s will be holding a `nullptr` pointer, and it is [*undefined behavior* to call a non-static class method through a `nullptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533476/).

The easiest fix is to change the loop in `get_transforms()` to use `m_add_idx` instead of `numelem`:

```cpp
template<typename float_t, size_t numelem>
auto transform_container<float_t,numelem>::get_transforms() const -> array_ptrs
{
    array_ptrs deep_cpy;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m_add_idx; ++i){ // <-- here
        deep_cpy[i] = m_ts[i]->clone();
    }
    return deep_cpy;
}
```

Otherwise, you would have to manually ignore any `nullptr` elements, eg:

```cpp
template<typename float_t, size_t numelem>
auto transform_container<float_t,numelem>::get_transforms() const -> array_ptrs
{
    array_ptrs deep_cpy;
    for(size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < numelem; ++i){
        if (m_ts[i]) {
            deep_cpy[j++] = m_ts[i]->clone();
        }
    }
    return deep_cpy;
}
```

Either way, you should update `add_transform()` to validate that `m_add_idx` will not exceed `numelem`:

```cpp
template<typename float_t, size_t numelem>
void transform_container<float_t, numelem>::add_transform(trans_type tt)
{
    if (m_add_idx >= numelem) throw std::length_error("cant add any more transforms"); // <-- here
    m_ts[m_add_idx] = transform<float_t>::create(tt);
    ++m_add_idx;
}
```

That being said, since `transform_container` can have a variable number of transforms assigned to it, I would suggest changing `transform_container` to use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::array`, eg:

```cpp
template<typename float_t>
class transform_container{
private:

    using vector_ptrs = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<transform<float_t>>>;
    vector_ptrs m_ts;
...
    auto get_transforms() const -> vector_ptrs;
};

template<typename float_t>
auto transform_container<float_t>::get_transforms() const -> vector_ptrs
{
    vector_ptrs deep_cpy;
    deep_cpy.reserve(m_ts.size());
    for(const auto &elem : m_ts){
        deep_cpy.push_back(elem->clone());
    }
    return deep_cpy;
}

template<typename float_t>
std::unique_ptr<transform<float_t>> transform<float_t>::create(trans_type tt)
{
    switch (tt) {
        case trans_type::TT_null:
            return std::make_unique<null_trans<float_t>>();

        case trans_type::TT_twice_fisher:
            return std::make_unique<twice_fisher_trans<float_t>>();
    
        case trans_type::TT_logit:
            return std::make_unique<logit_trans<float_t>>();
    
        case trans_type::TT_log:
            return std::make_unique<log_trans<float_t>>();
    }    

    throw std::invalid_argument("that transform type was not accounted for");
}

template<typename float_t>
void transform_container<float_t>::add_transform(trans_type tt)
{
    m_ts.push_back(transform<float_t>::create(tt));
}
```