# Calling empty virtual function from a base class pointer fails

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

While writing my first piece of software, I encountered a "strange" behavior when playing with virtual functions, inheritance, and pointers. What I had was a template class State, that had a following function in the public interface

```
void State::saveState() {};
```

When the app was first fired up, in order to set a default state, it was calling a `setState()` function within the manager function, that roughly goes as follows

```
case(some enum):
{
    mActiveState->saveState();
    delete mActiveState; 
    mActiveState = new SomeStateClassDerivedFromState();
    mActiveState->setup(some arguments);
    break;
}
```

Now for the strange thing - the first two lines of this code should cause a run-time error, or something similar. If this function is used to CHANGE the state, then it should be fine. But it was also used for the assignment of some object/memory for `State::mActiveState`, which at that point is `nullptr`. But it didn't crash for some reason, program executed as expected. But then, I wanted to override the `saveState()` function in one of the classes inheriting from State, so I added a virtual tag to the function (body remained empty), and wrote a definition for `saveState()` in the derived class. Suddenly, these two lines started crashing the app at startup (as expected). Removing the virtual tag from `saveState()` made the app run again.

Why didn't calling a member function and deleting a `nullptr` cause a crash until the `saveState()` member function was declared as virtual (with empty body, not pure virtual)?

This code recreates the problem

```
class State
{
public:
void saveState() {};
}

class DState : public State
{
saveState() {};
}

int main()
{
State* state = nullptr;
state->saveState();
delete state;
state = new DState();
}
```

This worked. The moment I added virtual tag to the `saveState()` function in the State class, it crashed on start. My question again, why?

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] demonstrating the problem please.

Comment: Deleting a null pointer should not cause a crash.

Comment: Where did you put the `virtual` keyword. In the base class definition or higher up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does calling method through null pointer "work" in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320822/why-does-calling-method-through-null-pointer-work-in-c)

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès how is the problem of virtual/non-virtual function making a difference between how the app runs a duplicate of the question you have linked again?

Comment: Because with a virtual method, another mechanism is involved that needs to dereference the (here null) pointer to retrieve the right function to call... With non virtual you basically have something like  a call to `saveState(nullptr)` while with a virtual method you would have `m_ptr=find_method_in(nullptr,SAVESTATEID); m_ptr(nullptr);` and the *first* expression need to examine the structure passed as first parameter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class State
{
public:
    void saveState() {};
}
//...
    State* state = nullptr;
    state->saveState();
//...
```

Because saveState is non-virtual here, you are simply calling a function that quietly takes a `this` pointer as the first argument.

The function does nothing, so nothing happens, infact the compiler may even be able to elide the function and the call to it entirely. If your function had tried to reference a member variable, it would have crashed. You've basically invoked Undefined Behavior and gotten lucky - mostly because you did nothing in the function.

When you make the function virtual, the program has to dereference the object to find it's *vtable* (virtual function table) which means it dereferences a nullptr and that's why you get a crash.

You also asked why deleting a null pointer doesn't crash: that's because, unlike free, it is legal to delete a null pointer -- basically delete does the check for you.

Answer (score 1):

Calling an empty method through `nullptr` has undefined behaviour but does not have to crash your program, as no data is accessed. Calling virtual function though requires to look for vtable, which brings behavior you see. But even if your program did not crash it does not make it valid.

On another side deleting `nullptr` is valid and leads to no-op.