# Program should fail/crash while dynamic_cast is working

Tags: c++

In my opinion following program should be crashed but its not only working but showing the right result("derv is called").

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base 
{
 public:
  virtual ~base(){}
};
class derv: public base 
{
 public:
   void f() { cout << "derv is called" <<endl;}
};
int main() {
  base* p = new base();
  derv *d1 = dynamic_cast<derv*>(p);

 // Since p point to base , so d1 should return nullptr 
 //calling any function using d1, should fail/crash 
 //but why the following line is working ?? 

 d1->f();
}
```

Sorry I forgot to add few lines in my  previous post: If I add a single data member and try to access it, gives me segmentation fault, which I think is the correct behavior. My Question is that why  accessing data member changes the behavior ? When variable is not get accessed , calling "f()" function is successful while   the same function "f()" gives segmentation fault when accessing with the data member?  Is it the undefined behavior?

```
class derv: public base 
{
 public:
  int x = 0 ; // Added new member,  c++11
  void f() { cout << "derv is called " << x << endl;} //access it here
};
```

Comment: How do you know `d1` is null? You don't check it, and your function doesn't use the `this` pointer in any way, so it's within the realm of possibility that it won't crash, even if it's null. https://ideone.com/K2dTD7 And here's a crash: https://ideone.com/US5s6r

Comment: It is Undefined behavior.

Comment: Once more, Undefined Behavior means anything can happen - including seeming to "work".

Comment: There is no "should crash" in C++. A "should crash" *can* make sense if you are talking about a specific implementation of a C++ compiler, with specific flags, a specific operating system or a specific memory situation. But there are no mandated crashes in the language specification.

Comment: I  updated my question

Comment: Now I tried to run the above program after adding and  accessing a single variable, it always give me segmentation fault.  It it a undefined behavior?

Comment: Many duplicates - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320822/why-does-calling-method-through-null-pointer-work-in-c), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505328/calling-class-method-through-null-class-pointer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533476/what-will-happen-when-i-call-a-member-function-on-a-null-object-pointer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is undefined behavior in your program you dereferencing `d1` which is a NULL pointer:

```
base* p = new base();
derv *d1 = nullptr;
d1 = dynamic_cast<derv*>(p);

if(nullptr == d1) // condition succeeds which means d1 is nullptr
    cout << "nullptr" << endl;
```

A safe programming is the task of the programmer not the compiler's so a good program checks before uses:

```
// avoiding error prones and UBs
if(nullptr != d1)
    d1->f();
```

Comment: In practice, your second example either postpones the undefined behaviour or trades it for specified but undesired behaviour. An unexpected null pointer is a bug, so `assert(d1 != nullptr);` should be used.

Comment: You mean I should use: `if(nullptr != d1) d1->f();`?

Comment: Well, I'd say that `if (d1)` is already idiomatic in C++.  Trying to `if (d1 != nullptr)` is wordier, but I don't see it as arguably better.  Depends on which way your OCD falls.

Comment: `if (derv* d1 = dynamic_cast<derv*>(p)) ...` is IMHO nicer - limits the scope of `d1` to the `if` test/statements, and if you get in the habit of writing your dynamic casts like this you can't accidentally use a `nullptr` `d1`

Comment: @Raindrop7: First of all, you should use `if(d1 != nullptr)` and not `if(nullptr != d1)`. The latter form of equality comparisons was sometimes recommended 20 or 30 years ago, when compilers didn't warn about accidental assignments, but nowadays it just looks funny. As for whether to compare with `nullptr` at all or just write `if (d1)`... well, I usually prefer the former form because it's more readable.

Answer (score 3):

`f` is not a virtual function. The program does not have to look for the virtual function table when trying to call `f`, so the method is called anyway.

If you try to check the pointer value of `this` inside of `f`, it will be `nullptr`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, null or just trash? Or compiler dependent UB?

Comment: If dynamic_cast fails the result is null.

Comment: `nullptr` to pick a bit on details.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: I think it is undefined behavior.

Comment: The result of checking `this` inside of `f` might depend on exactly how you check it.  A compiler is allowed to optimize `if (this)` to do the same as `if (true)`, since there's no legal way to have `this` be a null pointer value.

Comment: @super There is no `nullptr` involved here.  `nullptr` is a keyword.  Pointer objects can have null pointer values.

Comment: @aschepler You are not wrong. Still it is involved in the sense that you would use `nullptr` to check if a pointer object has a null pointer value.

Comment: @aschepler You are not wrong. Still it is involved in the sense that you would use `nullptr` to check if a pointer object has a null pointer value.