# What happens when you dynamic_cast between derived classes with the same base class?

Tags: c++11, polymorphism, dynamic-cast, static-cast

I am trying to figure out what happens when you `dynamic_cast` from one derived class to another derived class. Why does the below code raise a segmentation fault? Note that I am not trying to use this code for anything. I merely want to understand what is happening.

It's also worth noting that the same code works using `static_cast`. I can't seem to find any documentation that goes into the finer details of what is happening here. Can somebody explain?

```
struct base 
{ 
    virtual void printing(){cout<<"base printing"<<endl;};
};
struct derived_1 :public base 
{ 
    virtual void printing(){cout<<"derived_1 printing"<<endl;};
};
struct derived_2 :public base 
{ 
    virtual void printing(){cout<<"derived_2 printing"<<endl;};
};

int main()
{
    base * b = new derived_2();
    derived_1 *d_1 = dynamic_cast<derived_1*>(b);

    // calling printing raises segmentation fault
    d_1->printing(); 
}
```

Comment: Note: Albeit legal, you should remove the `virtual` specifier from the overriden methods in the subclasses and add `override` instead, as in `void printing() override { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast to `derived_1` will fail, because `derived_2` *is a* `base` object but *not* a `derived_1` object. Therefore, you cannot "side cast" to the desired pointer type.

Not that whenever `dynamic_cast` fails, it will return a `nullptr` ([except for reference types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)). This eventually leads to the segmentation fault in your code (in general, I would suggest you always add a `if (d_1 != nullptr)` before using a dynamically casted object).

**Update:**

By the way, this is actually a good example for the necessity of `dynamic_cast`. Even though you could be tempted to use `static_cast` in your example and it would compile, you will be dealing with *undefined behavior*. Using `static_cast` will compile without hickups, but you would actually be working with a broken type. Assume `derived_1::printing()` accesses some variable `derived_1::a`, which does not exist in `derived_2`. By statically side-casting a `derived_2` object (which doesn't have `a`) to a `derived_1` object `d_1`, you would falsely assume `d_1` to contain some valid `a`, which is not the case.

Example:

```
// ...
struct derived_1 :public base
{
    const int a = 123;
    void printing() override {cout<<"derived_1 printing " << endl;}
    void foo() { cout << "Foo using constant = " << a << endl; }
};

// ...
int main()
{
    base * b = new derived_2();
    derived_1 *d_1 = static_cast<derived_1*>(b);
    d_1->printing(); // Will call derived_2::printing(), which is not what you expect!
    d_1->foo();      // Won't show a = 123 but some nonesense (mostly 0),
                     // because a is not defined in derived_2.
}
```

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense! Thanks for the help.
I was getting confused because the code I was actually testing was calling 2 functions. So it read like

    d_1->non_virtual_member_function_of_derived_1();
    d_1->printing(); 

The first function call was succeeding so I just assumed that d_1 was not a nullptr. However, I see now that nullptr's can actually call member functions. Even though this is undefined behaviour it was succeeding in this case

Comment: _However, I see now that nullptr's can actually call member functions._: No, you can't call anything on a nullptr.

Comment: That's what I thought but apparently you can. It is undefined behaviour, but you can do it and it will not always raise segmentation fault. This is discussed at this SO 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320822/why-does-calling-method-through-null-pointer-work-in-c)

Comment: You can call non-virtual functions on null pointers, though it is classed as undefined behaviour. However calling virtual functions with a null pointer will be fatal, as knowledge of the object is required to look up the implementation of the virtual function - generally via the VFT pointer in the instance itself.