# How is obj1 is referenced and calling show method if it is NULL

Tags: c++, class, singleton

I am trying to create the class that can only allow one object to be created at a time, so i have created private constructor and one public wrapper getInstance() method that will create object for this class, the code goes as follows

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class sample
{
    static int cnt;
    int temp;
    private: sample()
    {
        //temp++;
        cnt++;
        cout<<"Created "<<++temp<<endl;
    }
    public:
    void show()
    {

        cout<<"Showing \n";
    }

    static sample* getInstance()
    {
        cout<<"count is "<<cnt<<endl;
        if(cnt<1)
            return (new sample());
        else
            return NULL;
    }

};
int sample::cnt=0;
int main()
{
   // cout<<"Hello World";
    sample *obj = sample::getInstance();
    obj->show();

    sample *obj1 = sample::getInstance();
    if(obj1 == NULL)
        cout<<"Object is NULL\n";
    obj1->show();

    return 0;
}
```

How is `obj1->show()` is getting called?
**OUTPUT :**

```
count is 0
Created 1
Showing
count is 1
Object is NULL
Showing
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does calling method through null pointer "work" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320822/why-does-calling-method-through-null-pointer-work-in-c)

Comment: Short answer: undefined behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a vacuum, this is just because your function:

```
public:
void show()
{

    cout<<"Showing \n";
}
```

don't actually try to do anything with the object - to get into the correct mindset of why this works just think of a member function as an abstraction over a *free function* taking the object as it's first argument:

```
void show(Object* this)
{

    cout<<"Showing \n";
}
```

Now it is easy to see why this works since you don't use `this` - the null pointer.

If you change to something ala. this:

```
public:
void show()
{

    cout<< this->temp << "Showing \n";
}
```

Your program should almost certainly crash.

Comment: Thnx for the hep, btw my intention was only to crash the code.....

Answer (score 1):

What is almost certainly happening here is that the compiler is optimizing the call to `show` by inlining it. Further, it can also make it a "pseudo-static" function, as the there is no reference inside `show` to any other class member.

To 'break' the optimisation (and cause a crash) you can do one of these:

1. Decare the `show` function `virtual`
2. Reference a **non-static** member (e.g. `temp`) inside the function

Comment: This isn't entirely correct - it would work even if the function wasn't inlined - hasn't anything to do with optimizations really - I could reproduce with all optimizations turned off