# Delete an object, then call it's method via a std::function. It works! But WHY?

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

I run this code snippet to test the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    int i;

public:
    A(): i(0) {}    

    void doSomething()
    {
        cout << "do something " << i << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    A* a = new A();
    function<void()> func = std::bind(&A::doSomething, a);

    delete a;
    a = nullptr;

    func();

    return 0;
}
```

And got the output:

```
do something 0
```

Could anyone help me explain why we can call an object method after deleted the object ?

Comment: The behavior is undefined, which means that one of the allowed behaviors is your function being called.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505328/calling-class-method-through-null-class-pointer

Comment: @quantdev Lazy gcc devs! Make us time travel, dammit!

Comment: When you created `func` it stored the address of `A::doSomething`. After calling `delete` on `a`, the address still remains for `A::doSomething`. `delete` doesn't wipe the memory of `a`. But this is undefined.

Comment: `Could anyone help me explain why we can call an object method after deleted the object `  If you have your drivers license suspended, does that mean you can't physically get into a car and drive it?

Comment: thank you. shooting myself in the foot ... again :))