# Resize a std::vector<AbstractClass*>

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, abstract-class

It is my understanding that we can never instantiate an abstract class in `C++` or equally an interface in `Java`. This makes sense because we have "pure virtual" functions that provide no implementation, therefore we can only instantiate subclasses of this class/interface that adhere to the contract formed by the abstract class. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class AbstractClass {
public:
  AbstractClass() {
    cout << "Instantiating" << endl;
  }

  virtual void pureVirtualFunction() = 0;

  void testMe() {
    cout << "test" << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  vector<AbstractClass*> v;
  v.resize(100);
  cout << v.size() << endl;
  v[0]->testMe();
  v[0]->pureVirtualFunction(); //segfault on my machine
  return 0;
}
```

What baffles me when I run this on my computer is that I can actually resize the vector. I always thought that `std::vector::resize` instantiated some number of elements, thus calling each element's constructor but further research shows that the constructor is not actually called (also evident by my stdout not showing 100x "Instantiating" strings).

So if `std::vector::resize` allocates space for these new objects, and allows me to actually call methods on each of them, how are they not fully instantiated? I figured I couldn't even call `resize()` on a vector of abstract classes but I can, I assume because they are not fully initialized. Could someone explain what is happening here?

### EDIT:

Brain fart..forgot that a vector of pointers, when resized, does not actually allocate `new` elements, as pointers can be created without allocated elements behind them, however...why can I still call a member function on a pointer to a class in which is not instantiated?

Comment: You are referring to a pointer in the vector. There won't be any objects crated of the abstract class.

Comment: The answers below aside, it is kind of interesting that calling testMe may "work". I believe a similar explanation to what is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505328/calling-class-method-through-null-class-pointer) may apply.

Comment: If you want to increase the likelihood that the madness of `v[0]->testMe()` will actually parade its *undefined behavior*, declare a member variable `int foo;` in `AbstractClass`, and use it in some fashion (assign it as `foo = 42;`, for example) in `testMe()`, in addition to your stdout-write.

Comment: And with your edit-update, the link provided by Robert ([repeated here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505328/calling-class-method-through-null-class-pointer)) becomes even more relevant.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers already say what's wrong with your code, I'm here to answer the edit:

> however...why can I still call a member function on a pointer to a
>   class in which is not instantiated?

You mean this part in particular:

```
  v[0]->testMe();
  v[0]->pureVirtualFunction(); //segfault on my machine
```

Basically, because `v[0]` doesn't point to a valid object yet trying to call `testMe()` is already undefined behaviour.

The only reason it doesn't segfault is because you're (un)lucky that the compiler rewrote your code. Your body of the method `testMe()` doesn't require the `*this` object at all and thus the compiler will just replace it with a `cout` call. Because no attempt to access some invalid `this` pointer is made there is no segfault yet. Then, when calling the second method the compiler needs to check the vtable of an invalid `this` pointer, which causes the segfault. Don't *ever* rely on the behaviour of the `testMe()` working out, this is still undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I found out that whenever `testMe()` used `this` to say, set a member variable we'd then segfault (which totally makes sense because there technically is no `this`)

Answer (score 2):

The `value_type` of your `vector` is `AbstractClass*` - that is, the vector contains *pointers* which could be `nullptr`, a pointer to a valid instance of `AbstractClass` deriviation or random locations in memory.

`vector::resize(N)` creates `N` default-initialized elements, and again, the `value_type` of your vector is something`*`, so it will create `N` instances of `nullptr`.

`AbstractClass::testMe` is a non-virtual member function. Thus, under the hood, it is simply a plain function that takes a hidden `this` pointer as its first argument.

The body of `testMe` itself does not access any elements of the abstract class, so it never *dereferences* `this`.

Thus

```
v[0]->testMe();
```

calls `AbstractClass::testMe(nullptr, );` and never dereferences `this`.

```
v[0]->pureVirtualFunction(); //segfault on my machine
```

tries to dereference `nullptr` to find `v[0]`s vtable => crash.

Comment: Your explanation on how we only got lucky because we never dereferenced `this` is great thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You made a vector of `AbstractClass *`, not of `AbstractClass`.

Pointers can be created without objects to point to.

Because of the function being virtual, those pointers could point to derived classes' objects which are no longer abstract, so the call would be legal.
Only when you finally execute it, the system trips over the null in the vptr table and dumps.