# Which of these will create a null pointer?

Tags: c++, dereference, null-pointer

The standard says that dereferencing the null pointer leads to undefined behaviour. But what is "the null pointer"? In the following code, what we call "the null pointer":

```
struct X
{
  static X* get() { return reinterpret_cast<X*>(1); }
  void f() { }
};

int main()
{
  X* x = 0;
  (*x).f(); // the null pointer?  (1)

  x = X::get();
  (*x).f(); // the null pointer?  (2)

  x = reinterpret_cast<X*>( X::get() - X::get() );
  (*x).f(); // the null pointer?  (3)

  (*(X*)0).f(); // I think that this the only null pointer here (4)
}
```

My thought is that dereferencing of the null pointer takes place only in the last case. Am I right? Is there difference between compile time null pointers and runtime according to C++ Standard?

Comment: That's not a homework. The C++ Standard says not much about dereferencing the null pointers. I just want to know.

Comment: The first part of my answer here talks about dereferencing null pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-behav (I love that question.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only the first and the last are null pointers. The others are results of `reinterpret_cast` and thus operate on implementation defined pointer values. Whether the behavior is undefined for them depends on whether there is an object at the address you casted to.

Comment: What is the difference between dereferencing the null pointer and some invalid pointer?

Comment: @Johannes : they are null pointers, but will they cause a core dump? Initially I thought so, but after some thought I'm not so sure. See my answer above.

Comment: @Scott Smith: It's implementation defined. Particularly on platforms which have no concept of a "core" i.e. anything outside of UNIX.

Answer (score 12):

An integer constant expression that evaluates to 0 is valid as a null pointer, so the first case is also dereferencing a null pointer.

A pointer which is set to 0 via some arithmetic calculation is not necessarily a null pointer. In most implementations it will behave in the same way as a null pointer, but this is not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: "Converting an integral constant expression (5.19) with value zero always yields a null pointer (4.10), but converting other expressions that happen to have value zero need not yield a null pointer"  (5.2.10/5 note 64).

Comment: @James Ahh! So 0!=NULL for very large values of 0!

Comment: Notice the difference between 0 and a null pointer. `0` is not valid as a null pointer always, but only when the conversion to a null pointer is possible. `0` is a null pointer constant and only where the conversion to a null pointer is considered, it is valid as a null pointer by that conversion. @Kirill refers to the internal representation of that null pointer, while i believe @Mark is referring to something completely else (to the value of a null pointer constant, which in fact always and necessarily has the value `0`).

Answer (score 7):

C++ Standard (2003) 4.10

**4.10 Pointer conversions**

> 1 A null pointer constant is an
>   integral constant expression (5.19)
>   rvalue of integer type that evaluates
>   to zero.  A null pointer constant can
>   be converted to a pointer type; the
>   result is the null pointer value of
>   that type and is distinguishable from
>   every other value of pointer to object
>   or pointer to function type.  Two null
>   pointer values of the same type shall
>   compare equal.  The conversion of a
>   null pointer constant to a pointer to
>   cv-qualified type is a single
>   conversion, and not the sequence of a
>   pointer conversion followed by a
>   qualification conversion (4.4).

**5.2.10 Reinterpret cast**

> Note 64) Converting an integral constant
>   expression (5.19) with value zero
>   always yields a null pointer (4.10),
>   but converting other expressions
>   that happen to have value zero need
>   not yield a null pointer.

1)  `X* x = 0; (*x).f();` Yes.
0 is integral constant expression and is converted to the null pointer constant.
Then null pointer constant can be converted to the null pointer value.

2) `x = X::get();` no, see note 64 in 5.2.10

3) `x = reinterpret_cast<X*>( X::get() - X::get() );` no, see note 64 in 5.2.10

4) (*(X*)0).f(); Yes.
 0 (integral constant expression) --> the null pointer constant -->
the null pointer value.

Comment: For the footnote in 5.2.10, also notice the defect report in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#463

Answer (score 0):

```
X* x = 0;
(*x).f(); // the null pointer?  (1)
```

I think this qualifies as dereference, even though `f()` never actually uses the `this` pointer, and there are no virtual methods in `X`. My reflex was to say that this is a crash, but now that I think of it, I'm not so sure.

```
x = X::get();
(*x).f(); // the null pointer?  (2)
```

Probably an invalid pointer. not sure whether it will crash (see above for reasoning).

```
x = reinterpret_cast<X*>( X::get() - X::get() );
(*x).f(); // the null pointer?  (3)
```

Does the expression `X::get() - X::get()` compile? I didn't think it was legal to subtract a pointer from another pointer like that.

EDIT: D'oh! Of course it's legal. What was I thinking? Clearly, I am a maroon.

Comment: In concerns to calling a nonstatic function on a null instance: It leads to undefined behavior. So all bets are off, clearly. That said, in practice as long as there is no need for the `this` pointer (no virtual functions, no members, etc.), then it won't crash, since it's never used.

Comment: subtracting pointers is very common - and it will return the difference between the two pointers. However since these are not in the same array then you are right - result undefined. (but it probably compiles)

Comment: @Scott Smith, I just compiled that in GNU C++ and executed without errors. Why do you think that subtracting pointers is illegal? My first thought was that code in OP question will crash in (2).

Comment: @Kirill: Pointer subtraction is explicitly undefined behavior if both pointers do not point to elements in the same array (or one past the end of said array.) It's in 5.7/6. That said, you can cast a pointer to a `uintptr_t` or kin, and compare those, yielding an integer value.

Comment: Adding two pointers is not allowed; subtracting one pointer from another is.  However, the result of the subtraction is not a pointer; it's an integer value with type `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @GMan, I was talking about exact implementation (g++ 4.x.x). Dereferencing null pointer is a common hack in C sources in Linux as I can see, hence same code should work in C++ for back compatibility. But I thought that dereferencing invalid pointer will lead to core dump.

Comment: @pm100 - Ah, silly me, of course. I've done this before - dunno what I was thinking.