# Is it safe to have a reference to an out-of-bounds array element if I never actually use the reference?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working with an API wherein the caller passes in an array of pointers to stuff, as well as the length of the array. To make my code more readable/maintainable, I would like to be able to effectively give names to each argument rather than refer to them as `arg[0]`, `arg[1]`, etc. Is it safe to declare references to all of the possible arguments even if the length of the passed-in array can be different sizes due to optional arguments?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
void myFunc(int out_args[], size_t nargs) {
  int &foo = out_args[0];
  int &bar = out_args[1];    // bar is optional argument. is this safe?
  ...
  foo = 5;
  if(2 >= nargs)
    bar = 10;
  ...
}
```

Note that the arguments are *output* arguments, so I really want to have references to them. **So, is it safe to have a dangling-ish reference to args[1] if I never actually use it?**

My guess is that this is safe because I imagine the way references are implemented is to treat `&` in the variable declaration of references as `* const`, and whenever I use the references, then the compiler automatically dereferences the pointers for me. Ie, under the hood, I imagine that what I wrote is translated to something like

```
void myFunc(int out_args[], size_t nargs) {
  int *const foo = &out_args[0];
  int *const bar = &out_args[1];    // bar is optional argument. is this safe?
  ...
  *foo = 5;
  if(2 >= nargs)
    *bar = 10;
  ...
}
```

In this case, I believe the code never actually accesses memory it shouldn't, so if the version above is equivalent to this, then I should be ok, right?

---

EDIT:
I'm basically writing a plug in, and the API I'm using and can't do anything about can call my code with either something like

```
int ret_vals[1];     // only care about 1 return value
myFunc(ret_vals, 1);
```

or

```
int ret_vals[2];     // care about both return values
myFunc(ret_vals, 2);
```

or even

```
myFunc(NULL, 0);     // ignore all return values; just marvel at the side effects
```

and my code needs to work in all cases.

Comment: The question is: Why are you *replacing* the pointers supplied?  I know you're allowed to modify the content, but I'm not so sure about replacing the pointers.

Comment: @paddy, I think you are referring to my earlier version of the post; refresh to see the edit where I took out the extra pointer stuff.

Comment: Why are you keeping a reference that you are "never actually using"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is it safe to have a dangling-ish reference to args[1] if I never actually use it?

The standard impose that a reference shall be bound to a valid object in § 8.3.2:

> There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references,
>   and no pointers to references. [...] A reference shall be initialized
>   to refer to a valid object or function. [ Note: in particular, a null
>   reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way
>   to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object”
>   obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, which causes undefined
>   behavior. [...] — end note ]

It means that it is **not** safe.

> My guess is that this is safe because I imagine the way references are
>   implemented is to treat & in the variable declaration of references as
>   * const, and whenever I use the references, then the compiler automatically dereferences the pointers for me.

No, don't do that. Again, the standard doesn't specify how references shall be implemented. In fact in § 8.3.2 it states that:

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage.

As for your code: you could name the parameters once you are sure they exists.

```
void myFunc(int out_args[], size_t nargs) {
  int &foo = out_args[0];
  ...
  foo = 5;
  if(nargs >= 2) {
    int &bar = out_args[1];
    bar = 10;
  }
  ...
}
```

I feel obligated to make you notice that the use of C-style arrays in C++ is discouraged. It is generally a good idea to use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: Thank you, some quotes from the standard is what I was hoping for. As for C-style arrays... I don't like them either but I'm stuck with them.

Answer (score 3):

It is undefined behaviour to evaluate the expression `args[1]` if `args` isn't a pointer to the first element of an array of at least two elements. Taking the address immediately, like `&args[1]`, is valid only if `args` points to the first element of an array of at least one element.

Basically, don't do it.

Comment: Isn't `&args[1]` equivalent to `args+1`, in which case, it doesn't really matter if `args` is even a valid pointer?

Comment: @SchighSchagh: `args + 1` is only valid if [same as above]. You can't make up arbitrary pointers. Pointers must point to actual elements, or one-past-the-end.

Comment: The statement about `&args[1]` is true only for C, not C++.  The language to permit this was added in C99 (I quoted the language in [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896689/dereferencing-the-null-pointer/2896975#2896975)).  C++ has no equivalent rule.