# Cancellation of *& in ANSI C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

With some friends we discuss about the corectness of this simple following code in ANSI C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a=2;
    printf("%d", *&a);
    return 0;
}
```

The main discuss is about *&. If * access a memory location (aka pointer) and & gives memory address of some variable... I think * tries to access a int value as memory adress ( that obviously don't work), but my friend says *& it cancels automatically ( or interpret as &*). We tested it with GCC 4.8.1 (MinGW) and the code avobe worked it well... I think was not right.

What do you think about? Think there's a bad workaround here ( or this is just stupidity?). Thanks in advice :)

Comment: Sure... I know one can reduce it, but that's why I'm asking this. In some specific memory cases can cause some bad compiler interpretations.

Comment: You might be thinking of the potential issue with combining the operators in the order `&*` which has been discussed on SO several times, including a detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2896975/12711

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is an lvalue: the variable `a`. 
`&a` is a pointer to this lvalue. 
`*&a` is the lvalue being pointed to by `&a` — that is, it is `a`.

Technically speaking, `*&a` and `a` are not completely equivalent in all cases, in that `*&a` is not permitted in all circumstances where `a` is (for example, if `a` is declared as `register`), but in your example, they are completely the same.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know that *& can cause bad interpretations in specific variable-type cases. ;) Thanks!

Comment: There are no bad interpretations. It's just that `&a` may not be meaningful, may not be allowed. Not a problem with interpretation.

Comment: Conversely, `*&a` may be valid where `a` is not: If that is the only time the address of `a` is taken, it was not initialized, and there are no trap-representations for its type, that's enough to make it valid with arbitrary value, instead of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting excerpt from C standard (as a footnote), namely C11 §6.5.3.2/4 (footnote 102, emphasis mine), which discusses this aspect directly:

> Thus, `&*E` is equivalent to `E` (even if `E` is a null pointer), and
>   `&(E1[E2])` to `((E1)+(E2))`. It is always true that if `E` is a function
>   designator or an lvalue that is a valid operand of the unary `&`
>   operator, **`*&E` is a function designator or an lvalue equal to `E`**. If `*P`
>   is an lvalue and `T` is the name of an object pointer type, `*(T)P` is an
>   lvalue that has a type compatible with that to which `T` points.

In your case `a` is a (modifiable) lvalue, that reflects to `E` symbol from standard and it's valid operand of the `&` operator as standard requires, thus `*&a` (i.e. `*&E`) is an lvalue equal to `a`.

Note that you can't take address of `register` storage class variable (as pointed by @Deduplicator), so it does not qualify into such reduction (that is, even as modifiable lvalue).

Comment: `*&a` and `&*a` are different things.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Right, note that both cases are explained. `*&E` requires that `E` is a) lvalue, b) valid operand of the `&` operator.

Answer (score 1):

So long as `*&a` is meaningful, then `*&a` and `a` are the same thing and are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `*&a` is the same as `a`.

Still, there are corner-cases:

1. `*&` may be invalid because `&a` is not allowed, as it is not an lvalue or it is of `register`-storage-class.
2. Using `a` may be Undefined Behavior, because `a` is an uninitialized memory-less variable (`register` or `auto`-storage-class which might have been declared `register` (address was never taken)).

Applying that to your case, leaving out `*&` does not change anything.