# Printing null pointer gives ""Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to explore the pointers in C, so pretty new to this subject. I came to know that best practice is to assign "NULL" when declaring a pointer. So in the below program I did the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

 unsigned int *ip = NULL;

 printf("Address stored in pointer: %x \n",ip); //gives 0
 printf("Value stored at Address stored in pointer: %d \n",*ip); // gives "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

 return 0;

}
```

I am not able to understand clearly why this is happening. Shouldn't it output a value (NULL or something).

I am using centos 6.5 and gcc version 4.4.7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dereferencing the null pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896689/dereferencing-the-null-pointer)

Comment: Why do you say that "it should output a value" ? Where have you read that ? because what you have read would be false.

Comment: This is why setting pointers to NULL is good practice. So you get an error if you dereference it. Use %p to print a pointer.

Comment: `*ip` dereferences a null pointer and this usually leads to a crash on modern systems (MacOS, Windows, Linux).

Comment: Thanks all for sharing your insights...i also took a look in the link by @2501..

Comment: @NeilKirk..that tip made the warnings disappear "warning: format ‘%x’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int*" :)

Answer (score 3):

People assign `NULL` to pointer to indicate that it points to nothing.

Dereferencing pointer pointing to memory which doesn't belong to your program
(`NULL==0`, and address `0` belongs to your operating system)
is *undefined behaviour*.

People assign `NULL` to pointers to be able to write

```
if(ip) //NULL==0==false, so the condition means "if ip points to something"
    printf("Value stored at Address stored in pointer: %d \n",*ip);
else printf("The pointer points to NULL, it can't be dereferenced\n");
```

Comment: thanks @GingerPlusPlus for a much clearer explanation for a newbie :)