# converting iterator to pointer - especially at end()

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer

I'm wondering if this is defined:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1337);
int * p1 = &*vi.end();
```

(**Update 1** If this is undefined, I'd like to know more about exactly where my error is. For example, perhaps the reference `int &r = &*(v.data()+v.size())` *is* legal in general, but `*end()` isn't required to return that. )

(**Update 2** I'm really just curious about the pedantic language-lawyer question as to what can be defined. I have no difficulty coding uncontroversial workarounds :-) )

Anyway, of course, using an end-iterator like this looks bad. But first, consider this:

```
int array[3];
int * p2 = array + 3;
```

Clearly `p2` is defined.

The, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2896975/146041), p2 is equivalent to p3 in this code: (*if* you're using C99):

```
int array[3];
int * p2 = array + 3;
int * p3 = &array[3]; // looks bad, but OK in C99
```

(I'm more curious about C++ though, and a comment to that answer implies that C++ allows it also. So, the above C99-compatible code is defined in C++.)

Moving closer to C++, I think I can write this:

```
int & r1 = *p3;
```

I agree that `r1` looks really bad. And certainly, it would be UB if we did something like `int x= r1;`. That is UB because it involves an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. But can we say that `r1` is still just an lvalue? And therefore we can take its address?

```
int * p3 = &r1;
```

If all this is valid, then we can argue that a one-past-the-end *reference* is generally valid - for C-arrays at least. So, what can we say about `*v.end()`?

The `operator*()` method returns an `int&` reference. Does the standard require that it return one of these one-past-the-end references that we are allowed to take the address of?

**Bonus**: what if the vector is empty?  In particular, is `(&*v.end())==(&*v.begin())`

Comment: *Dereferencing* the address one past the end of the allotted memory is undefined behavior. Taking the address is fine.

Comment: You should consider dereferencing any interator pointing to non existing elements (even when implemented as pointer)  as undefined behavior.

Comment: @0x499602D2, I'll see if I can remove the word 'dereference' from my question. It doesn't help

Answer (score 4):

No, any `*` on `v.end()` is illegal.

You can do `v.data()+v.size()` instead for a pointer to the end, and `v.data()` for a pointer to the beginning.

This is defined even for an empty `std::vector`.

Comment: `.data()` is only in C++11, any pre-C++11 solution?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Write a free `data` function: `template<class T, class A> T* data( std::vector<T, A>& v ) {if (v.empty()) return 0; return &v[0]; } template<class T, class A> T const* data( std::vector<T, A> const& v ) {if (v.empty()) return 0; return &v[0]; }`  Now you can `data(v)` and `data(v)+v.size()`.  Of course, this runs into `operator&` overloading issues, which you'd fix with `std::addressof`, which is C++11 as well.  ;)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid The first std::vector specification has data as member!

Comment: @Yakk I am pretty sure (I guess even the HP implementation has it)

Comment: @Yakk BTW: I am the opposite of being fat

Comment: A re-C++11 solution might look like this:

v.size()?&v[0]+v.size():0

Answer (score -1):

v.end() points one beyond the last element. Therefore, dereferencing it is illegal.

You could use *(v.end()-1) to get the last element as long as v.size()>=1.

(Or use &*(v.end()-1) to get a pointer to it.)