# circular linked list (insert at beginning)

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

This is my code. A circular linked list has two functions, one to insert at the beginning and the other to insert at end. When I run it, it works, but there is an error that it doesn't
display the last node, i think because  `head=p;` not `head->next=p;` but if I do `head->next=p;` it is a segmentation error
How can I fix this fault?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int info;
    node* next;
};

node* head = NULL;

void insert_b(int data) {
    node* p = new node; //create
    p->info = data; //fill
    if (head == NULL) {
        head=p;
        p->next = head;
        
    }
    else {
        p->next = head->next;
        head->next = p;
    }


void traverse() {
    node* curr = NULL;
    for (curr = head->next; curr != head; curr = curr->next) {
        cout << curr->info << "  ";
    }
}

int main() {
    int data;
    cout << "enter data: ";
    cin >> data;
    insert_b(7);
    insert_b(2);
    insert_b(1);
    traverse();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(head==NULL)` + `head->next=p;` ==> crash. I think correct is `if (head==NULL) head=p;`

Comment: Work it out by drawing boxes and arrows using pen and paper first.

Comment: Dupe1: [Why dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793262/why-dereferencing-a-null-pointer-is-undefined-behaviour) , Dupe2:[dereferencing the null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896689/dereferencing-the-null-pointer)

Comment: Your next step should be to determine the line at which the crash occurs, then find the values of each variable used on that line. A debugger is very helpful for this.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question yesterday. I somehow missed the whole "circular" part (although it's clearly stated in the question more than once). I've now updated my answer to deal with that.

Answer (score 2):

The logic in `insert_b` is flawed. if `head == NULL` you can't dereference it like you do in `head->next = p`.

You have a similar issue in `traverse` where you go directly for `head->next`. First check that `head` is `!= nullptr` then start by printing. Check if `curr` reaches `head`, then `break` out.

Fixing the logic in `insert_b` is a bit tricky since it's a circular list. For both `insert_b` and `insert_t` you want to insert the new node between the last element and the first element, so you need to traverse the linked list until you find that last `node*`. For `insert_b` you also want to move `head` so that it points at the newly inserted `node`.

Since the logic is so similar, I suggest creating a common function that can be used for both. This would be the `insert_t` function:

```cpp
node* insert_t(int data) {
    node* p = new node;  // or:
    p->info = data;      // node* p = new node{data, nullptr};

    if (head) { // there is at least one node
        node* curr = head;
        // find the last node:
        while(curr->next != head) curr = curr->next;
        // link in the new node between the last node and head
        p->next = head;
        curr->next = p;
    } else { // first node - let it point at itself
        p->next = p;
        head = p;
    }
    return p;
}
```

The above links the new node in last in the circular linked list and returns a pointer to the inserted node. In order to implement `insert_b` we only need to call `insert_t` and move `head`:

```cpp
void insert_b(int data) {
    // move head to point at the newly inserted node
    head = insert_t(data);
}
```

The corrected loop needs to check that `head != nullptr` first, then print the value of the current `node`, step to the next - and abort if it's coming back to `head`:

```cpp
void traverse() {
    if (head) {
        node* curr = head;
        do {
            std::cout << curr->info << "  ";
            curr = curr->next;
        } while(curr != head);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```