# Why is NULL/0 an illegal memory location for an object?

Tags: c++, c, null, memory-management

I understand the purpose of the `NULL` constant in C/C++, and I understand that it needs to be represented *some* way internally.

My question is: Is there some fundamental reason why the 0-address would be an invalid memory-location for an object in C/C++? Or are we **in theory** "wasting" one byte of memory due to this reservation?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759845/why-is-address-zero-used-for-null-pointer

Comment: 0 is not necessary an invalid memory location. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511921/which-of-these-will-create-a-null-pointer

Comment: @aioobe: If you understand the purpose of `NULL` and that null-pointer has to be represented *some way* internally, then you must understand that it has absolutely nothing to do with 0-address. Null-pointer can be numerically tied to *any* address, not necessarily to 0-address.

Comment: In all hw architecture I am aware of, the "begin" of the memory (address 0 and beyond) is used to store things like interrupt vectors and more stuffs. So it is a reasonable pick to intend 0 as a not-valid address for user applications, even when indeed because of MMU that address could be something different from the 0-address before MMU were used. the important is that NULL must be an invalid address, i.e. an address that can't be "mapped" to the program; likely it's numerically 0 always, but it's not a need

Comment: I've worked with several microprocessors that had no such limitations on address 0.  The null pointer can, and sometimes is, a perfectly valid address.  What is important is that the compiler not create objects there.  Technically, it is a compiler limitation, *not* an architectural one.

Comment: not talking about the fact that 0 is not accessible:it is of course;but accessing it is not useful from a user point of view on most systems;reading in _some case_ is(e.g. at addr 4 on Amiga was stored the ptr to exec lib),but writing is normally a system thing,and _can_ cause troubles;that physical addr is not mapped at all in common OSs to user app space,and since on those we gain memory through system funcs(through lib func like malloc),the choice of"0"for NULL(failure) is logical.If a system can give mem from 0(mapped to 0)a lot of things can go wrong(despite compilers and cpus)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The null pointer does not actually have to be 0. It's guaranteed in the C spec that when a constant 0 value is given in the context of a pointer it is treated as null by the compiler, however if you do

```
char *foo = (void *)1;
--foo;
// do something with foo
```

You will access the 0-address, not necessarily the null pointer. In most cases this happens to actually be the case, but it's not necessary, so we don't really have to waste that byte. Although, in the larger picture, if it isn't 0, it has to be something, so a byte is being wasted *somewhere*

Edit: Edited out the use of NULL due to the confusion in the comments. Also, the main message here is "null pointer != 0, and here's some C/pseudo code that shows the point I'm trying to make." Please don't actually try to compile this or worry about whether the types are proper; the meaning is clear.

Comment: Theoretically, there doesn't *have* to be a null pointer set aside anywhere.  But then programmers would have to have `isValid` flags associated with all their pointers instead.  So the options are to have a byte wasted somewhere, or lots of bytes wasted everywhere.

Comment: Your code snippet invokes undefined behavior, but I won't downvote because the meaning is clear.

Comment: Alternately, `int z = 0; void *foo = (void *)z;` won't necessarily produce a null pointer (at least in C++; I'm not as up on the C standards).

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: Apparently there are a couple architectures which use a high bit in the pointer as a flag marking it as null or invalid. There are many ways in which ISAs approach it.

Comment: Nitpick: `NULL` (in all caps) means the preprocessor macro (which is, by definition, 0 (or possibly `(void*) 0` for some C implementations).  You mean *the null pointer*. http://c-faq.com/null/varieties.html

Comment: The size of `char` is guaranteed to be 1 *C-byte*, but not guaranteed to be 1 *machine byte*. This means that `(void *) 1` is not necessarily a valid value for a `char *` pointer and that decrement will not necessarily produce a zero address. The implementation might be built around two-machine-bytes `char`s, meaning that the above might easily produce something like `0xFFFF...` instead of zero address.

Answer (score 14):

This has nothing to do with wasting memory and more with memory organization.

When you work with the memory space, you have to assume that anything not directly "Belonging to you" is shared by the entire system or illegal for you to access. An address "belongs to you" if you have taken the address of something on the stack that is still on the stack, or if you have received it from a dynamic memory allocator and have not yet recycled it. Some OS calls will also provide you with legal areas.

In the good old days of real mode (e.g., DOS), all the beginning of the machine's address space was not meant to be written by user programs at all. Some of it even mapped to things like I/O. 
For instance, writing to the address space at 0xB800 (fairly low) would actually let you capture the screen! Nothing was ever placed at address 0, and many memory controller would not let you access it, so it was a great choice for NULL. In fact, the memory controller on some PCs would have gone bonkers if you tried writing there.

Today the operating system protects you with a virtual address space. Nevertheless, no process is allowed to access addresses not allocated to it. Most of the addresses are not even mapped to an actual memory page, so accessing them will trigger a general protection fault or the equivalent in your operating system. This is why 0 is not wasted - even though all the processes on your machine "have an address 0", if they try to access it, it is not mapped anywhere.

Comment: This is only peripherally related to the issue, but wasn't page 0 reserved for the interrupt table?  If so, then 0 would be a valid address.

Comment: @Steven On the x86, only in real mode. In protected mode, the physical location of the interrupt table is specified in the IDTR register. A reasonable kernel would never map a page of an unprivileged process's virtual memory onto the interrupt table.

Comment: @user168715:
Which is one of many good reasons why Windows 9x/Me kernels can't be called reasonable...

Comment: @user: That's what I thought.  For some time now, I've been able to count on the OS to force an exception whenever a NULL (or otherwise invalid) pointer was dereferenced.  I guess I'd forgotten the bad old days when a wild pointer could corrupt the entire machine's state.  I don't miss those days!

Comment: @slacker: In their defense, MS wasn't trying to be reasonable.  Rather it wanted to ensure backward compatibility at any cost, even sanity.

Comment: @Steven Sudit:
Sanity was always a very scarce resource in the Microsoft world (this only recently slowly starts to change). And this all still doesn't change the fact that the Windows 9x design is one huge WTF to anyone versed in OS engineering. Here, have a "protected" OS which goes to great lengths to forbid access to other user-mode processes' memory, while happily allowing everyone write access to kernel memory. **WTF?**

Comment: @slacker: Again, I fully agree that it's unreasonable.  But it fulfilled their goal, which was to continue to be able to run those wacky DOS games.  Good thing modern CPU's are capable of virtualization.

Comment: The color text mode video memory is actually mapped to the real mode *segment* `0xB800`, which is actually quite a *high* address in real mode (it is above the famous "640k limit").

Comment: @Steven Sudit:
DOS games ran in a partially virtualized environment, without any sane way to access the kernel. It is about the **Win32** processes having kernel memory mapped in their address spaces with write permission. WTH does this have to do with compatibility?

Comment: @slacker: You keep bringing up sanity, but I don't think that ever entered the picture; market necessity is all that ever mattered. DOS games and even utilities ran in a variety of quirky environments and often depended upon directly hooking into the interrupt lookup and replacing entries.  This pretty much forces page 0 to be exposed, unless you can fully virtualize it (as we do now).

Answer (score 10):

There is no requirement that a null pointer be equal to the 0-address, it's just that most compilers implement it this way. It is perfectly possible to implement a null pointer by storing some other value and in fact [some systems do this](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html). The [C99 specification](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) §6.3.2.3 (Pointers) specifies only that an integer constant expression with the value 0 is a null pointer constant, but it does not say that a null pointer when converted to an integer has value 0.

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
>   void *, is called a null pointer constant.
>
> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

On some embedded systems the zero memory address is used for something addressable.

Comment: Would there be any means by which an embedded system where the machine representation of the null pointer constant was something other than 0 could allow code to "smoothly" create a pointer to physical address zero?  The only approach I can think of would be to store pointer addresses as something like of the real address and the null pointer constant, but that seems really icky.

Answer (score 6):

The zero address and the NULL pointer are not (necessarily) the same thing. Only a *literal* zero is a null pointer. In other words:

```
char* p = 0; // p is a null pointer

char* q = 1;
q--; // q is NOT necessarily a null pointer
```

Systems are free to represent the null pointer internally in any way they choose, and this representation may or may not "waste" a byte of memory by making the actual 0 address illegal. However, a compiler is required to convert a *literal* zero pointer into whatever the system's internal representation of NULL is. A pointer that comes to point to the zero address by some way other than being assigned a literal zero is not necessarily null.

Now, most systems do use 0 for NULL, but they don't have to.

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessarily an illegal memory location.  I have stored data by dereferencing a pointer to zero... it happens the datum was an interrupt vector being stored at the vector located at address zero.

By convention it is not normally used by application code since historically many systems had important system information starting at zero.  It could be the boot rom or a vector table or even unused address space.

Answer (score 4):

On many processors address zero is the reset vector, wherein lies the bootrom (BIOS on a PC), so you are unlikely to be storing anything at that physical address.  On a processor with an MMU and a supporting OS, the physical and logical address addresses need not be the same, and the address zero may not be a valid logical address in the executing process context.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is typically the zero address, but it is the zero address in your applications *virtual address space*.  The virtual addresses that you use in most modern operating systems have exactly nothing to do with actual physical addresses, the OS maps from the virtual address space to the physical addresses for you.  So, no, having the virtual address 0 representing `NULL` does not waste any memory.

Read up on [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) for a more involved discussion if you're curious.

Comment: This only works on those OS's that support a virtual address range.  On embedded systems, the address 0 is valid (especially if there is something located there, like RAM or a UART).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the answers directly addressing what i *think* you were asking, so here goes:

Yes, at least 1 address value is "wasted" (made unavailable for use) because of the constant used for *null*. Whether it maps to 0 in linear map of process memory is not relevant.

And the reason that address won't be used for data storage is that you need that special status of the null pointer, to be able to distinguish from any other real pointer. Just like in the case of ASCIIZ strings (C-string, NUL-terminated), where the NUL character is designated as end of character string and cannot be used inside strings. Can you still use it inside? Yeah but that will mislead library functions as of where string ends.

I can think of at least one implementation of LISP i was learning, in which NIL (Lisp's null) was not 0, nor was it an invalid address but a real object. The reason was very clever - the standard required that CAR(NIL)=NIL and CDR(NIL)=NIL (Note: CAR(l) returns pointer to the head/first element of a list, where CDR(l) returns ptr to the tail/rest of the list.). So instead of adding if-checks in CAR and CDR whether the pointer is NIL - which will slow every call - they just allocated a CONS (think list) and assigned its head and tail to point to itself. There! - this way CAR and CDR will work and that address in memory won't be reused (because it is taken by the object devised as NIL)

ps. i just remembered that many-many years ago i read about some bug of Lattice-C that was related to NULL - must have been in the dark MS-DOS segmentation times, where you worked with separate code segment and data segment - so i remember there was an issue that it was possible for the first function from a linked library to have address 0, thus pointer to it will be considered invalid since ==NULL

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer. However, `char *foo = (void *)1;
--foo; // do something with foo`   seems to indicate that the addres is not actually wasted after all?

Comment: @aioobe - it is more the case of "you shouldn't", not "you can't".  
It depends on the compiler/environment - in some runtime de-referencing of NULL will be detected and prevented. Not to mention that use of memory not provided by malloc/OS is heresy! :-)

Answer (score 0):

But since modern operating systems can map the physical memory to logical memory addresses (or better: modern CPUs starting with the 386), not even a single byte is wasted.

Comment: If I had three GB of RAM and a 32-bit OS, it would waste a whole 4096 byte page.

Comment: @kmm No.  It's just that the bottom page of the virtual address space of each process is not mapped.  The actual physical page 0 can still be used (assuming it is RAM) and can be mapped anywhere into any of the processes' address space.

Comment: The virtual address space of a 32 bit OS is only 3 GB for each process. If I have 3 GB RAM, and there needs to be at least one NULL pointer, somewhere, you're wasting a page of memory.

Answer (score 0):

As people already have pointed out, the bit representation of the NULL pointer has not to be the same as the bit represention of a 0 value. It is though in nearly all cases (the old dinosaur computers that had special addresses can be neglected) because a NULL pointer can also be used as a boolean and by using an integer (of suffisent size) to hold the pointer value it is easier to represent in the common ISAs of modern CPU. The code to handle it is then much more straight forward, thus less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in noting that the address space at 0 is not usable storate for your program.  For a number of reasons a variety of systems do not consider this a valid address space for your program anyway.

Allowing any valid address to be used would require a null value flag for all pointers.  This would exceed the overhead of the lost memory at address 0.  It would also require additional code to check and see if the address were null or not, wasting memory and processor cycles.

Ideally, the address that NULL pointer is using (usually 0) should return an error on access.  VAX/VMS never mapped a page to address 0 so following the NULL pointer would result in a failure.

Answer (score -1):

The memory at that address is reserved for use by the operating system.  0 - 64k is reserved.  0 is used as a special value to indicate to developers "not a valid address".

Comment: Not necessarily, in embedded systems (which may or may not have an OS) all bytes within the pointer's range are possible.  Valid addresses are defined by the implementation.  The address 0 may be valid and may be in RAM and needs to have code copied there.

Comment: Ah, yes, true.  I was thinking strictly from a Windows POV.