# if (!ptr) VS if (ptr == NULL) in C

Tags: c, pointers

Sometimes I see programmers use:

```
void *ptr = <something>;
if (ptr == NULL)
    <do something>;
```

Instead of:

```
void *ptr = <something>;
if (!ptr)
    <do something>;
```

Is there anything that can go wrong with `if (!ptr)`, or is it just a coding style preference?

Comment: It's just a coding-style preference.

Comment: There seem to be some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6187656/133203), but I'm not sure if this should be classed as a duplicate

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894013/is-null-always-zero-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, it is just a coding style preference.

Some people prefer `if (NULL == ptr)` with the argument that if the programmer made a typo (and mistyped the `==`  as a *single* `=`) the compiler will complain. However, many compilers would emit a warning for `if (ptr=NULL)` (at least recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) do, when invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra` as you should).

---

In C++ (where you would use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`) there could be a difference, because one can redefine `operator !` (e.g. on smart pointers). However, on raw plain pointers (like `void*`, or `sometype*` or `SomeClass*`), you cannot redefine operators like `!` or `!=`.

---

BTW, some weird processors might have `NULL` pointers which are *not* an all zero-bits machine word (but the compiler should deal with this issue). I can't name any such processor in wide use today (however think of 1980s segmented 16 bits x86 as a counter example).

Comment: One could redefine `==`, too, so it's unclear which is better.  Though if you are daft enough to define `a==0` != `!a`, you deserve all that comes to you...

Comment: IIRC, segmented x86 has null pointers that aren't necessarily all-bits-zero (due to use of segment registers), and the compiler must make sure that they compare equal to `0` .  There's probably some x86 around today (notably in devices such as cameras and other embedded controllers).

Comment: I thought of that, but I won't call 16 bits segmented x86 in wide use today.

Comment: I thought that Canon DSLRs are 16-bit x86?  Perhaps I misremember.

Comment: Is `NULL` always a zero? because if it's not then `if (!ptr)` won't be equivalent to `if (ptr == NULL)`, when `ptr` is `NULL`.

Comment: The compiler would compile both equivalently. I don't know what you mean by `NULL` always zero.

Comment: I mean all it's bits are 0

Comment: @Toby Speight: but that is a camera, not a programmable computer

Comment: @PintoDoido: today, a camera *is* a programmable, embedded, computer system.

Comment: @Toby Speight what programming tools do you use for that?