# Pointer vs. reference return types

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

i'm trying to come up with a concrete reasoning why to use a pointer over a reference 
as a return type from a function ,

my reasoning is that if inadvertently a null value is returned to a reference type 
it could not be checked , and could lead to run-time errors

```
  int& something(int j)
  {
      int* p = 0 ;  
      return *p;
  }

  void main()
  {
      int& i = something(5);
      i = 7;   // run-time error 
  }
```

if i had used a pointer i could check it and avoid the error 
the pointer return value would act as a contract to that a value must be returned.

```
 void main()
 {
         int* i = something(5);
         if( i != null )
             *i = 7;
 }
```

any thoughts would be appreciated 
again ,

what would you use and why 
reference or pointer

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should never return a reference to local memory anyway.

Comment: Why would you do either of those things?

Comment: @Chad: There's no *prima facie* indication that the reference would be to local memory. As it stands, the code simply returns a null pointer.

Comment: @Marcelo You don't see anything wrong with `int& i = 0;`? There is a reason why this generates an access violation in it's current state.

Comment: @AJG85 The code is just exemplifying what could go wrong when returning a reference (and it's obviously contrived in order to be simple and to the point). The question is not about fixing the code that is incorrect *for example purposes*.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: My point was merely that assigning a null pointer to a reference is just as bad. A reference is suppose to be an object, an object should not be null. `int* p = 0; int& i = *p;` is illegal and rightly so.

Comment: @R. Martinho is correct , it's just a "dumb" example of miss use of code , you inadvertently place the null to reference type 
which passes at compile time.

Comment: @AJG85: The whole thrust of the question is whether the risk of *inadvertently* returning a "null reference" suggests that a pointer is preferable. It is obvious that the example function is deliberately doing the wrong thing just to illustrate the point. Plus, I have no idea what any of this has to do with my comment about returning a reference to local memory.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use a pointer instead of a reference if:

- Null is a valid return value
- You dynamically constructed something in the function, and the recipient becomes the owner. (In this case, you might consider returning a smart pointer such as std::unique_ptr or boost::shared_ptr.)

Regardless, you would not want to return either a pointer or a reference to a local variable.

Comment: Just for the people reading this (>2016) since 2011 it seems auto_ptr has been deprecated. unique_ptr would be more fitting now.

Comment: @andersfylling - Fixed. Thanks! It had been deprecated for two months when I mentioned it.

Answer (score 21):

References are a different way of thinking. Think of references as "pointers to existing objects". Once you do that, you'll understand why they can't be NULL - the object exists and the reference points to it.

Therefore, if your function returns a reference to something that it creates, it needs to guarantee that it actually does create a valid object. If it does not, or is unable to, then that is grounds to throw an exception.

Contrast that with a pointer. A pointer can be NULL and the caller will have to deal with a NULL return value. Therefore, if your function cannot guarantee that it will return a valid reference and you don't want to throw exceptions, you will need to use pointers.

Answer (score 3):

If you inadvertently return a null value, that's a bug. You can just as easily place the check inside `something()` and throw an exception if it's null.

Having said that, the historical convention is to return heap objects via pointers, even if they are guaranteed to be non-null.

Answer (score 1):

C++ references cannot be null. The bug is dereferencing a null pointer. That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Here's a null C++ reference:
void print_value(int &v) {
  printf("0x%08x\n", &v);
  printf("%d\n", v);
}

int main() {
  int *d = 0;
  print_value(*d);
}

Comment: @moof That program is UB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2727872/505088 *Note: in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior.*

Answer (score 1):

If your function is intended to "always" return a value, then your function should return a reference.

In those cases where, for some exceptional reason, you cannot find the value to return, you should throw an exception.

You should not rely on there being a run-time error generated when you try to return a reference to a null or wild pointer.  The behavior is undefined.  Anything could happen.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually dependent on what you are trying to accomplish, but I generally treat return values this way:

Return pointer - Caller owns memory (and cleanup)

Reference - Callee owns the memory. DO NOT return a dynamically allocated point unless the callee manages it as well.