# Reference to array in memory

Tags: c++

I have this memory layout:

```
0018FBD2 ?? ?? ?? ??    ?? ?? ?? ??
0018FBDA AA AA AA AA    BB BB BB BB  <- stuff I'm interested in
0018FBE2 ?? ?? ?? ??    ?? ?? ?? ??
```

In C, I would do:

```
int* my_array = (int*) 0x18FBDA;
my_array[0]; // access
```

However, I'm using C++, and I'd like to declare a reference:

```
int (&my_array)[2] = (???) 0x18FBDA;
```

In order to use like this:

```
my_array[0]; // access
```

But as you can see, I don't know how to cast it:

```
int (&my_array)[2] = (???) 0x18FBDA;
```

How should I do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Why are you thinking C++ would handle this differently? If it's a C-style array, use C notation. You want a reference. You've got a pointer. You're going to have to deal with pointers. You can [de-reference if you want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172735/how-to-cast-convert-pointer-to-reference-in-c) but that could cause problems.

Comment: Is this embedded? You probably get a segfault if not

Comment: Just use the pointer, everyone knows how that works anyways. If you want that to look more C++, call the pointer an "iterator" and, if you feel like it, use another past-the-end pointer as an end iterator.

Comment: If you are bored enough, you can also implement some `array_view` class with a custom `operator[]` to wrap the original array in.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` seems like the proper tool for the task. Considering what the question is, I assume this is ring-0 code or embedded.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, tell us how you *really* feel about C++ :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, it's better than ANSI C. ;)

Comment: Not sure that this question is really a duplicate of the other one:  this one is very specific about using a reference for an array at a specific physical location.  The other one is very general about legality of array reference casting, and someone looking for having an array at a fixed location might not recognize that it answers his question.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find the notion of using an array reference a bit convoluted, like **tadman** mentioned. But you can do it as you'd do with any type, by dereferencing a pointer.

```
int (&my_array)[2] = *reinterpret_cast<int(*)[2]>(0x18FBDA);
```

Also, if you are going to do such a cast, don't let it appear innocent by doing a c-style cast. Such a thing should stand out IMO.

Comment: @krzaq, I find this more expressive. A `reinterpret_cast` in my code is a sign to myself I'm doing something risky which should be treated with care.

Comment: @krzaq, of course it's also a shorter way to get around [this error](https://ideone.com/9hGcQ7)

Comment: @krzaq, this entire post seems to me about shooting myself in the foot. Might as well do it with less keystrokes (a double `static_cast` is required, or at least a c-style cast to `void*` first) :)

Comment: That's what I get for using literal 0 to check if `static_cast` would allow this :)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, but when compiling (VS2013) I get: `error C2101: '&' on constant`. I'm using your exact same code. Is this compiler-dependent? It seems to compile fine with GCC (ideone)

Comment: @Martin I don't have VS to check, but it seems like a compiler bug.

Comment: @Martin It may be possible for you to get around the error with `typedef int arr_t[2]`

Answer (score 2):

I would go with C-style pointer. But if you really want *the C++ way* (it isn't, not any more than what you presented in the question):

```
template<typename T, size_t S>
using arr = T[S];

auto& my_arr = *reinterpret_cast<arr<int,2>*>(0x18FBDA);
```

which is just a clearer notation for

```
auto& my_arr = *reinterpret_cast<int(*)[2]>(0x18FBDA);
```