# Can you return an integer by dereferencing a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior

```
int f(int *x)
{
    *x = 5;
    return *x;
}

int main()
{
    int * y = 0;
    int z = f(y);
}
```

Why does this code give me a run time error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does this code give me a run time error?

Because `y` is a `NULL` pointer, which is dereferenced in `f()`. Note, it is undefined behaviour to dereference a `NULL` pointer.

> Can you return an integer by dereferencing a pointer?

Yes, assuming the pointer is pointing to a valid `int`. For example:

```
int main()
{
    int y = 0;
    int z = f(&y);
}
```

Comment: Why "Technically"? It's undefined behavior, plain and simple.

Comment: @KeithThompson, he asked specifically why he was getting a runtime error and this would be the cause but it is not guaranteed to cause a runtime error. However, I will remove the "technically" as it is not useful.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I only started learning c++ recently. Still learning the tricks of the trade.

Comment: Worth mentioning that a run time error is one possible consequence of undefined behavior, but is not required.

Answer (score 7):

You can, if a pointer points to some valid memory. In your case, you are [dereferencing a NULL (`0x00`) pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727834/c-standard-dereferencing-null-pointer-to-get-a-reference), which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (aka UB). This, for example, works fine:

```
int f(int *x)
{
    *x = 5;
    return *x;
}

int main()
{
    int value = 1986;
    int *y = &value; // Point to something valid.
    int z = f(y);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because after `int *y = 0;`, `y` is a pointer which points to nothing (points to address `0`).
Your code should be like this:

```
int * y = new int;
*y = 0;
int z = f(y);
// ...
delete y;
```

or

```
int y = 0;
int z = f(&y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the pointer `y` to `0` which makes it an `NULL` pointer:

```
int * y = 0;
```

and then you are trying to perform *indirection* on the *pointer* in `f()` here:

```
*x = 5;
^
```

and in the subsequent line, which is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `8.3.2` *References* paragraph *5* says:

> [...] Note: in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by indirection through a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior. [...]

Answer (score 1):

Check pointers before dereferencing and always specify error behavior:

```
int f(int *x)
{
   if ( x )
   {
     // do something with x
   }
   else
   {
     // do something else in case null pointer
   }
}
```

Dereferencing a null pointer yields a null pointer exception, such as in your case.

Comment: Just because a pointer is not NULL does not mean it points to a valid object.

Comment: that is true. Nonetheless, do your best to validate your arguments.

Comment: there's always such a thing as overdoing it. I've edited my answer to not encourage such behavior.