# Single Linked List seg fault issue

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I tried to implement by myself a single linked list. For now, I only wrote an addition of an element to the end of the list, and a function which prints lists content. But when I want to print out a list my program gives me a segmentation fault. Heres my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Stuff;

class List
{
    private :

        Stuff *first, *last;

    public :
        List();
        void addfront(Stuff *s);
        void print();
        ~List();
};

class Stuff
{
    private :

        string name;
        double price;

    public :

        Stuff();
        Stuff(string, double);
        void print();
        Stuff *next;
};

Stuff::Stuff()
{
    name = "";
    price = 0;
    next = NULL;
}

Stuff::Stuff(string n, double p)
{
    name = n;
    price = p;
}

void Stuff::print()
{
    cout << name << " " << price << "\n";
}

List::~List()
{
}

void List::addfront(Stuff *s)
{
    if(first == NULL )
       first = s;
   last->next = s;
   s->next = NULL;
   last = s;
}

void List::print()
{
    Stuff *p;
    if(last == first == NULL)
        cout << "list is empty!\n";
    else
        for (p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next)
            p->print();
}

List::List()
{
    first = last = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    List l;

    Stuff *s1 = new Stuff("Coffe", 4.50);
    Stuff *s2 = new Stuff("Apple", 2.50);

    l.addfront(s1);
    l.addfront(s2);

    l.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `NULL`-macro in C++... Use `0`, instead.

Comment: Juste one remark, `last == first == NULL` will not work as you expect. Use `last == first && first == NULL` instead.

Comment: @bash.d That's not better, use `nullptr`.

Comment: @Djon if C++11 is available!

Comment: @bash.d Well it's more likely OP is using a compiler that supports C++11 rather than one that doesn't define NULL to 0.

Comment: More likely but not entirely excluded...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to check if `last != NULL` before setting `last->next` to `s`.

Deferencing a `NULL` pointer results to an [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727834/c-standard-dereferencing-null-pointer-to-get-a-reference/2727872#2727872).

Your `addFront` function should look like that:

```
void List::addfront(Stuff *s) {
    if(!first)
        first = s;
    if (last)
        last->next = s;
    s->next = NULL;
    last = s;
}
```

Btw: Use `if(last == first && last == NULL)` instead of  `if(last == first == NULL)`.

Answer (score 3):

One issue is

```
if(last == first == NULL)
```

make it

```
if(last == NULL && first == NULL)
```

also you need to do,

```
void List::addfront(Stuff *s)
{
    if(!first)
       first = s;
    if (last)
        last->next = s;
   s->next = NULL;
   last = s;
}
```

Comment: This is **exactly** my answer.

Comment: @segfolt Yeps I know I am late! I was trying to find some links relevant to the issue. No probs I upvoted yours. Will add some links to mine when i find them

Comment: Thanks. No prob. I just didn't understand because it was looking like a pure copy paste :p

Answer (score 2):

It is because of this line in `addfront` method

`last->next = s;`

Here `last` is a NULL pointer.

```
(gdb) p last
 $1 = (Stuff *) 0x0
```

Deferencing a NULL pointer will cause memory fault/segmentation violation.

Always check whether it is NULL and then deference.

```
if (last)
  last->next = s;
```

If you are in Linux machine, then you can run the program in `gdb`. Once segmentation violation happens put use `backtrace` command to see the call stack to understand which statement is crashed.