# Permuting bottom element with top element in a stack

Tags: c, data-structures

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *top;


int count=0;
void push(int n);
void Print();
void permute();

int main()
{
 int no, ch, e;
 printf("\n1 - Push");
 printf("\n4 - Print");
 printf("\n7 - Permute first and last element");
while (1)
    {
        printf("\n Enter choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter data : ");
            scanf("%d", &no);
            push(no);
            break;
        case 4:
            Print();
            break;

        case 7:
            permute();
            break;
        default :
            printf(" Wrong choice, Please enter correct choice  ");
            break;
        }
    }


}
void push(int no)
{
    struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=no;
    temp->next=top;
    top=temp;
    count++;
}
 void Print()
{
    struct node *temp=top;
    printf("List is:");
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d  ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void permute()
{
    int i;
    struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *temp1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *temp2=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp=top;
    temp1=NULL;
    for(i=0;i<count-1;i++)
    {
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }
    temp1->next=temp2;
    temp2->data=temp1->next->data;
    temp1->next=temp;
    temp->data=top->data;
    temp=NULL;
    temp2->next=top;
    top=temp2;
}
```

So my implementation of a stack works fine as for pushing and printing the elements in the stack, but when I want to permute the bottom element with the top element the program crashes. I think I am messing something up in my permute function. Thank you for any help before hand.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: If I don't cast it then I get an error.

Comment: `temp1=temp1->next;` but `temp1=NULL;`

Comment: `struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));...temp=top;` causes a memory leak. It's not the origin of your problem.

Comment: @Module , Are you compiling in C++ instead of C? BTW, *what* is the error?

Comment: @Module Is it enough simply to swap values of data member data of the two nodes?

Comment: `temp1=NULL;...temp1=temp1->next;` : dereferencing NULL pointer is [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727834/c-standard-dereferencing-null-pointer-to-get-a-reference). The program may crash due to a segmentation fault.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I will try just permuting the data members of the two nodes and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: "*If I don't cast it then I get an error.*" then you aren't using a Standard conforming C compiler, but most probably a C++ compiler.

Comment: @alk I am using Dev cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have correctly understood it is enough simply to swap values of data member `data` of two nodes. The function can be defined the following way

```
void permute()
{
    if ( top && top->next )
    {
        int data = top->data;

        struct node *last = top->next;

        while ( last->next ) last = last->next;

        top->data = last->data;
        last->data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly fine now. I was messing the permutations up .

Comment: The condition in the if statement is the equivalent of just saying that if top is different from NULL and top->next is also different from NULL. If I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Module  You are right. At least two nodes that differ from NULL are required that to make the permutation.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to permute nodes, here is a solution. Since there is no new node in the stack when a permutation is performed, there is no need to allocate memory. It is just pointer handling.

Notice the additional test to treat the case of an empty stack, or a stack with a single element.

A removed the cast of the return of `malloc()` in `push()` and tested the return value of `malloc()`. `malloc()` may fail if there is not enough memory available.

The following code is compiled by `gcc main.c -o main -Wall` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <conio.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *top;


int count=0;
void push(int n);
void Print();
void permute();

int main()
{
    int no, ch;
    printf("\n1 - Push");
    printf("\n4 - Print");
    printf("\n7 - Permute first and last element");
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n Enter choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter data : ");
            scanf("%d", &no);
            push(no);
            break;
        case 4:
            Print();
            break;

        case 7:
            permute();
            break;
        default :
            printf(" Wrong choice, Please enter correct choice  ");
            break;
        }
    }


}
void push(int no)
{
    struct node *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(temp==NULL){printf("malloc failed\n");exit(1);}
    temp->data=no;
    temp->next=top;
    top=temp;
    count++;
}
void Print()
{
    struct node *temp=top;
    printf("List is:");
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d  ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void permute()
{
    if(count<2){return;}
    int i;
    struct node *temp1=top;
    struct node *temp2;
    for(i=0;i<count-2;i++)
    {
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }
    temp2=temp1->next;
    temp1->next=top;
    temp2->next=top->next;
    top->next=NULL;
    top=temp2;

}
```

Comment: I would like to ask you: Is Francis a French man's name and Frances a French woman's name?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow : According to wikipedia, Francis is a French and English surname of Latin origin ( Franciscus). I did not know about the English part... France was the scenic name of woman singer [France Gall](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/France_Gall), the name of my country and the name of a [boat](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/France_%28paquebot_de_1912%29). Yet the feminine of Francis is Francine...It's not very common nowadays...Nice to ask !

Comment: I simply know a woman that names herself Frances. It is her real name. In Italian there are Francesco and Francesca. So i have thought that in French there are Francis and Frances.

Comment: By the way she also uses shortened name Fran.