# Dereferencing a NULL pointer to a reference which is unused; Is this also "Undefined Behaviour"?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, undefined-behavior, nullptr

In a large project compiled using latest g++, following behaviour at "--->" is consistently observed:

```
void somewhere ()
{
  T* pt = find(x); // returns `nullptr` for `x`
  foo(*pt);
}

void foo (T& t)  // many times `t` is created from `pt = nullptr`
{
  if(condition)
    t.set(0);  // ---> But app crashes, only if this is touched
}
```

Means, `find(x)` always returns `nullptr` to `pt`. But the app doesn't crash, unless the `condition` is true. Suppose, if the `condition` is never true when `pt` was `nullptr`, is the app still in the UB state?

In other words as marked in question:
**Is dereferencing a NULL pointer into a reference, which is never accessed for read/write, still an undefined behaviour?**

As null pointer itself is not a UB, but only accessing it. Similarly, the reference derived from such pointer (analogically a "null reference") shouldn't act in the same way!

Comment: *pt is UB already if pt is nullptr.