# using unique_ptr after move

Tags: c++, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I don't understand why this code works:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void doStuff() const{}
    Base(Base & b) = delete;
    Base() {
        cout << "Base" << endl;
    }
    ~Base() {
        cout << "~Base" << endl;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Base& a) {
         return out << "me";
    }
};
int main(){
    unique_ptr<Base> pt = make_unique<Base>();
    auto npt = move(pt);
    auto &a = *pt;

    if (pt == nullptr)
        cout << "yes nullptr" << endl;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

The output in Visual Studio 2015 is:

```
Base
yes nullptr
me
~Base
```

So it doesn't crash and `pt` is even usable after being moved from.
In coliru online compiler, it crashes at line  `cout << a << endl;`. I don't understand how it doesn't crash at line `auto &a = *pt;`, since pt is equal to nullptr at this point and the command `auto &refToNull= nullptr;` is a compilation error.

I will appreciate a clarification about what's going on.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: You forget that your `operator<<` function is *not a member function*. It's a global non-member function. Try calling an actual member function, or accessing a member variable instead.

Comment: _So it doesn't crush and `pt` is even usable after being moved from._ Who says that it should always crash? It is Undefined behavior.

Comment: Your example boils down to `Base& a = *(Base*)nullptr; cout << a;` That exhibits UB in the same way, and I predict would produce the same outcome. `unique_ptr` or `move` have nothing to do with it - they just form a very elaborate way to spell `(Base*)nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the statement

```
auto &a = *pt;
```

is an *Undefined Behaviour*, that is not defined. Dereferencing a `nullptr` in C++ does not make *crash* your program, it may happen everything.

---

What you probably expect from your code is a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), but it does not occur because you actually does not ever access to the the object `a`.

Indeed, your `operator<<` take a `Base` object but it does not use it at all.

Instead, if you try to do something like:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Base& a) {
     a.do_stuff();
}
```

Your program will be killed by the OS because `a` object is referenced on a wrong memory (actually 0x0 memory).

A related question about nullptr derefereing is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727834/c-standard-dereferencing-null-pointer-to-get-a-reference).

Answer (score 0):

`auto npt = move(pt);` transfers ownership of `pt` to `npt` leaving `pt` a `nullptr`. Since `pt` is now a `nullptr` then `if (pt == nullptr) cout << "yes nullptr" << endl;` outputs "yes nullptr" correctly.

`auto &a = *pt;` means you are trying to dereference a `nullptr` this is simply an **undefined behavior**. `cout << a << endl;` can lead to **anything can happen** but not necessarily crashing program.