# Is it legal to create a null rvalue reference in a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I'm trying to get size of a `std::tuple` at compile time using a constexpr function.

I write this, which I thought might be easy to use and could give a clear error hint:

```cpp
template<typename... TArgs>
constexpr int get_tuple_size(const std::tuple<TArgs...>&) { return sizeof...(TArgs); }
```

Soon I realized I don't want to construct a `std::tuple` really, so I tried this:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>
template<typename... TArgs>
constexpr int get_tuple_size(std::tuple<TArgs...>&&) { return sizeof...(TArgs); }
template<typename T>
constexpr T&& make_rvalue() {
    return ((T&&)*(T*)0);
}
int main() {
    printf("%d\n", get_tuple_size(make_rvalue<std::tuple<int, double, float&>>()));
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: this code can work in `Clang 7.0.1` `GCC 9.2.0` `VS2019`

This code meets all my requirements, but is it really legal?

I mean, when I write `((T&&)*(T*)0)` in a non-constexpr function, it gave an error.

> error C4854: binding dereferenced null pointer to reference has undefined behavior

By the way, is there any better solution to solve it?

I have tried this:

```cpp
    template<typename T>
    struct is_tuple {
        static constexpr bool value = false;
    };
    template<typename... TArgs>
    struct is_tuple<std::tuple<TArgs...>> {
        static constexpr bool value = true;
    };
    template<typename T>
    constexpr bool is_tuple_v = is_tuple<T>::value;
    template<typename T>
    struct sizeof_tuple {
        static_assert(is_tuple_v<T>, "==========>sizeof_tuple input type isn't std::tuple");
    };
    template<typename... TArgs>
    struct sizeof_tuple<std::tuple<TArgs...>> {
        static constexpr size_t value = sizeof...(TArgs);
    };
    template<typename T>
    constexpr size_t sizeof_tuple_v = sizeof_tuple<T>::value;
```

But if you input an wrong type, the error hint won't point to where you referenced `sizeof_tuple_v<T>` but the declaration itself.

Comment: why not use [`std::tuple_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size)?

Comment: Thanks! That's really a good idea @AlanBirtles , but that's not my main question.

Comment: If you don't want to construct a tuple, you should pass the type as a template parameter, intead of relying on a function with an argument. `get_tuple_size(make_rvalue<std::tuple<int, double, float&>>()))` is just a worse version of `get_tuple_size<std::tuple<int, double, float&>>()`, no?

Comment: C++ does not have null references. In general, `*(T*)0` gives your program undefined behavior.

Comment: @Pete Becker, but you can have references to pointers (that can be nullptr).The dereferencing itself is UB then, that's right.

Comment: Edit: AFAIK, the standard is not that specific about UB in terms of nullptr dereferencing. It's quite clear about UB when accessing underlying data via dereferencing but that's not the case here.

Comment: For the reference question portion, also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727834/c-standard-dereferencing-null-pointer-to-get-a-reference

Comment: @Secundi -- "[ Note: In particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by indirection through a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior. As described in 12.2.4, a reference cannot be bound directly to a bit-field.
— end note ]" [dcl.ref]/5.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I was not aware of this special note.