# c++ objected oriented programming exception failure

Tags: c++, oop, exception, inheritance, virtual

So I am creating an exception using inheritence of "exception" library, but I get an error which says looser throw for 'virtual'.

```
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>

namespace Vehicle_Renting{

using namespace std;

class Auto_Rent_Exception : public std::exception{


protected:
      string error;

   public:
      Auto_Rent_Exception(){
      }
  virtual const string what() = 0;

  virtual Auto_Rent_Exception* clone() = 0;
};
```

It says : error: looser throw specifier for 'virtual Vehicle_Renting::Auto_Rent_Exception::~Auto_Rent_Exception()'
 Vehicle_Renting is namespace of my project.

Comment: Should we start an over/under on who guesses first the toolchain and language version your using?

Comment: I am using Code Blocks compiler and c99 standard.

Comment: c99 ?  um.. this is **C++** code, right?. CodeBlocks isn't a compiler, its an IDE. What *compiler* are you using? g++? clang++, mingw ? and what version? And on what *specific* line in the above code does this error rear? (mark it with a comment). In fact a reproducible case would be helpful, ([works here](http://ideone.com/6SRxpu)).

Comment: Oh sorry I meant mingw version 4.4.1

Comment: How about the exact error message?

Comment: You may find [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539009/gcc-exception-specification-of-default-destructor) interesting.

Comment: Thank  you, sorry that i'm bad at asking question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the prototype destructor to your derived class from Auto_Rent_Exception.

```
virtual ~Auto_Rent_Exception() throw();
```

On a side note you should be careful about using `std::string` (or anything that allocates memory dynamically) in an exception class. In case some API function fails (e.g. because there is too little memory left), chances are your `std::string` constructor will throw `std::bad_alloc`, hiding the initial exception. Or if you implement an own memory allocator you can possibly create an endless loop of exceptions. It would be better to catch and ignore exceptions from `std::string`, so that the original exception is propagated (without a description, but still better than nothing/a "wrong" exception).