# C++ basic string exception

Tags: c++, exception

If I just want to throw a string, isn't there a built in type somewhere so that I can just do

```
throw standard_exception("This is wrong!");
```

Or do I have to define such a standard exception that derives from exception myself? I know it is very simple to do so, I just thought this would be so common that it would be defined somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::runtime_error` and `std::logic_error` (both derived from `std::exception`) both have constructors that take strings and override the `what()` member function to return the provided string.

Comment: It is interesting that every link I found tells one not to throw strings, but to define your own custom exception. The option to throw a runtime_error or the like never gets mentioned.

Comment: I prefer to define my own exceptions derived from `runtime_error` for individual components; doing so makes correcter exception handling quite a bit easier because you can handle specific errors and let other errors be handled elsewhere.  I do use `logic_error` directly, though, but only for errors that really are logic errors (e.g., the code is wrong), sort of like an assertion.

Comment: True, but if all one wants to do is for the thread to fall over without affecting the rest of the application, anything that gets caught by exception works. I am not doubting that more advanced throwing and catching warrants your own exception, but for a quick "this is impossible, now die" I think this is certainly more suited. I feel that in my situation defining your own exception as recommended on other posts on here or the C++ FAQ is overkill and for newbies not the most lightweight introduction to exceptions.

Comment: @Cookie: During development just to make things are working I use `throw "This is wrong"` or `throw int(4)`. But this is for development only. Once I have worked out how everything should be I put correct exception objects in to the code. PS. I don't recommend doing this unless you have an automated way of detecting and removing them (I have a script on the build server to make sure I can't check these in)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to throw a string, you can do so by just writing

```
throw "I'm throwing a string!";
```

This isn't a particularly good idea, though, since it's not considered good form to throw things like `char*`s as exceptions.  If you want to wrap the string into an exception of some form, you can always just use `runtime_error` or `logic_error`:

```
throw logic_error("This is wrong!");
throw runtime_error("This is wrong!");
```

Answer (score 4):

[Runtime error](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/stdexcept/runtime_error/) should be what you are looking for

```
throw runtime_error("This is wrong");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can throw `std::runtime_error` or create your own class that inherits from `std::exception` as follows

```
#include <exception>
#include <string>


class myexcept : public std::exception
{
private:
  /**
   * Reason for the exception being thrown
   */
  std::string what_;

public:
  /**
   * Class constructor
   *
   * @param[in] what
   *    Reason for the exception being thrown
   */
  myexcept( const std::string& what ) : what_( what ){};


  /**
   * Get the reason for the exception being thrown
   *
   * @return Pointer to a string containing the reason for the exception being thrown
   */
  virtual const char* what() const throw() { return what_.c_str(); }


  /**
   * Destructor 
   */
  virtual ~myexcept() throw() {}
};
```

To throw

```
throw myexcept( "The reason goes here" );
```

Comment: [The destructor must have an exception specification.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233078/how-does-an-exception-specification-affect-virtual-destructor-overriding)