# VC++ 2012 and Boost incompatibility - `throw()` specifications in library headers

Tags: visual-c++, exception, boost, boost-format

I have a new project where I cannot use boost::format. I get a compiler error complaining that boost's override of a virtual function, ~basic_altstringbuf, lacks a "throw()". Even the most trivial attempt to use boost::format does that.

I have other projects where it works fine. I have verified that the new project uses the same include-paths for boost, and for the VC++ includes. All the projects have "Enable C++ Exceptions" set to Yes. The only explanation I can come up with is that the projects that work have some #DEFINE or some setting that disables those vile exception specs in the std:: include-files. But I have no idea what or where it might be. Any ideas?

> Error 1   error C2694: 'boost::io::basic_altstringbuf::~basic_altstringbuf(void)': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits>::~basic_streambuf(void) throw()

EDIT: Corollary question: Is there a Properties-item in VS++ 2012 that will cause the std:: header files to be included without exception-specs? - short of turning off exceptions, that is?

Comment: what version of Boost? Try the latest version? If it is the latest, file a bug at the boost Trac issue tracker, since the compiler detection apparently fails for VC++ 2012

Comment: @sehe  Boost version boost-1.51. It does not fail in another project that uses the same compiler. Both use v110. I am using the same boost include files for both, but just as a test, I tried using first include files from a boost that I compiled locally and second from one that I got pre-built off of the net. Same thing on both. Works for other projects, not for the new one. The new one must be different somehow, but I have no clue what that how might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the request of the original owner of the green check-mark, I am submitting this summary.

1. The bugs are on the Microsoft side, in header-files for C++ standard library interfaces, and in the VC++ compiler when "Disable Language Extensions" is NOT set. The header files contain exception-specifications that the standard does not call for. When "language extensions" are not enabled, the compiler accepts invalid code. I have filed a [bug report.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766514/incorrect-exception-specifier-in-vc-header-file-causes-correct-user-code-not-to-compile#tabs)
2. Boost could work around the problem in this specific case by adding seven characters to a nested include-file, i.e. "throw()" at line 65 in alt_sstream_impl.hpp. I filed [a report](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7477) with boost also, although I made it clear that the bug is not in their code. I am just suggesting a workaround.

All the tedious details are in the two reports linked above.

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to publish the effective answer. I hope you liked my change of the title :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the preprocessor defines.

You might turn on and inspect verbose logging to see the exact flags that are passed to `cl.exe`

You could keep the preprocessed source and compare the version from the old (working) project with the new (failing) project.

My gut says, something else is being #defined/passed using -D in the old project that is not being defined in the new project, of differently (think of `WINVER` type macros)

---

#### See new answer posted: [VC++ 2012 and Boost incompatibility - `throw()` specifications in library headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764151/vc-2012-and-boost-incompatibility-throw-specifications-in-library-header/12773189#12773189)

<strike><sup>EDIT by OP, Jive Dadson - It turned out to be /Za, which enables/disables "Microsoft language extensions." It is the contention of Visual Studio that the C++ standard requires that a program shall not compile if it has a virtual function override that is less restrictive in the "throw()" category than the function it overrides. Boost has a class that derives from basic_streambuf, and has a virtual destructor that lacks "throw()". The original destructor has that evil festoon. My new project will compile boost::format if I turn MS language extensions ON.</sup></strike>

<sup>So the question becomes, who is wrong, and how? Is it standard-complying to put throw() on that destructor or not? Is the desired behavior (desired by me, that is) actually an "extension"? I seem to recall that MS considered some standard C++11 features to be "extensions," but I am not sure I remember correctly. Anyway, I will leave it to the boosters to decide, if they are interested. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7477</sup>

Comment: I went through the command lines already. I googled up a bunch of flags that were not familiar to me, but I did not see anything that looked like it could possibly be the culprit. Oh well. Onward through the fog!

Comment: The exception specification is definitely required to match in the override, [even for destructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233078/how-does-an-exception-specification-affect-virtual-destructor-overriding).

Comment: @James Then either MS or boost has errors in their header files. Does the standard say that ~basic_streambuf() is supposed to be decorated with throw()? That abomination is deprecated, finally.

Comment: @James I tracked it down. The bug is in the VC++ header file. The declaration for ~basic_streambuf() does not have a "throw()" exception-specifier. Section 27.6.3, C++11; Section 27.5.1 C++03.

Comment: @JiveDadson Great information. I'm not entirely sure anymore whether it was the /Za flag, or the headers, or the combination thereof? Perhaps you can post the summary as your own answer for future reference (and accept it). More people might run into this.

Comment: @James See the Answer I just submitted.

Comment: @sehe I did as you requested. Stackoverflow will not allow me to accept my own answer for 24 hours.