# Error in websocketpp library and boost in windows Visual Studio 2015

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2015, boost-asio, websocket++

I'm trying to compile this simple example https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/echo_server/echo_server.cpp from the developer github, but I'm getting strange errors outside the code.

I have also tried turning on the /Za option as shown in this post: [VC++ 2012 and Boost incompatibility - `throw()` specifications in library headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764151/vc-2012-and-boost-incompatibility-throw-specifications-in-library-header) but it throws a different error, saying "Threading support unavaliable: it has been explicitly disabled with BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS"

Does someone know how to fix this?
thanks!

The errors:
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 in Windows10 x64, 
`C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/transport/base/connection.hpp(187): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::transport::error::category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>  C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/transport/base/connection.hpp(187): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::transport::error::category::name'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(167): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/transport/iostream/base.hpp(89): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::transport::iostream::error::category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>  C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/transport/iostream/base.hpp(89): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::transport::iostream::error::category::name'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(167): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/error.hpp(151): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::error::category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>  C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/error.hpp(151): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::error::category::name'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(167): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/frame.hpp(831): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
1>C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/extensions/extension.hpp(65): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::extensions::error::category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>  C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/extensions/extension.hpp(65): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::extensions::error::category::name'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(167): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>C:\local\boost_1_59_0\boost/asio/detail/config.hpp(227): warning C4005: 'BOOST_ASIO_ERROR_CATEGORY_NOEXCEPT': macro redefinition
1>  C:\local\boost_1_59_0\boost/asio/detail/config.hpp(213): note: see previous definition of 'BOOST_ASIO_ERROR_CATEGORY_NOEXCEPT'
1>C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/transport/asio/base.hpp(189): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::transport::asio::error::category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>  C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/transport/asio/base.hpp(189): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::transport::asio::error::category::name'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(167): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/transport/asio/security/base.hpp(109): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::transport::asio::socket::socket_category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>  C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/transport/asio/security/base.hpp(109): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::transport::asio::socket::socket_category::name'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(167): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/processors/base.hpp(165): error C2694: 'const char *websocketpp::processor::error::processor_category::name(void) const': overriding virtual function has less restrictive exception specification than base class virtual member function 'const char *std::error_category::name(void) noexcept const'
1>  C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/processors/base.hpp(165): note: see declaration of 'websocketpp::processor::error::processor_category::name'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(167): note: see declaration of 'std::error_category::name'
1>C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/common/md5.hpp(367): warning C4267: '+=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'websocketpp::md5::md5_word_t', possible loss of data
1>C:\websocketpp\websocketpp/sha1/sha1.hpp(176): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: Just googled this, found your post, it looks like a bug to me, it doesn't account for the fact that VS2015 has constexpr and noexcept. I added the exceptions in cpp11.h, but now I am getting errors with `boost::milliseconds` and chrono's duration. boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::steady_clock,boost::asio::wait_traits<Clock>,boost::asio::waitable_timer_service<Clock,WaitTraits>>::basic_waitable_timer(const boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<Clock,WaitTraits,boost::asio::waitable_timer_service<Clock,WaitTraits>> &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'boost::chrono::milliseconds' to 'c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining `_WEBSOCKETPP_NOEXCEPT_` and `_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_CHRONO_` did the trick for me :)
https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/issues/437

Comment: Thanks! that works for me. Just to help other that might have the same problem, I had to add this: 
` #define _WEBSOCKETPP_NOEXCEPT_ 1
#define _WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_CHRONO_ 1
#include <... `