# How to fix the syntax in this code rife with templates?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code

```
template<typename T, typename U> class Alpha
{
public:
    template<typename V> void foo() {}
};

template<typename T, typename U> class Beta
{
public:
    Alpha<T, U> alpha;
    void arf();
};

template<typename T, typename U> void Beta<T, U>::arf()
{
    alpha.foo<int>();
}

int main()
{
    Beta<int, float> beta;
    beta.arf();
    return 0;
}
```

Fails to compile due to:

> ../src/main.cpp: In member function
>   ‘void Beta::arf()’:
>   ../src/main.cpp:16: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ‘int’
>   ../src/main.cpp:16: error: expected
>   ‘;’ before ‘int’

How the heck do I fix this?  I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alpha::foo` is a [dependent name](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#dependent), use `alpha.template foo<int>()`.

Dependent names are assumed to

- not be types unless prefixed by `typename`
- not be templates unless directly prefixed by `template`

Comment: VC8 is not standard regarding this point. Writing portable code with VC8 is such a mess...

Comment: @ale: Oh yes - and porting template-heavy parts later from VC8 is quite a pain.

Answer (score 4):

Try `alpha.template foo<int>()`. Note that your code compiles fine with VC8. Since alpha is of dependant type, you have to specify that foo is a template.