# May I have a real life example where a non-static member function not accessing the object being called via a null pointer causes observable problems?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, null-pointer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does invoking a member function on a null instance result in undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha)

Anything like this:

```
class Class {
public:
    void Method()
    {
       //empty;
    }
};

Class* object = 0;
object->Method();
```

is undefined behavior in C++ because calling non-static member functions via null pointers is formally illegal. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474021/57428) for a detailed explanation full of quotes from the C++ Standard. I'm well aware of the theoretical part and this question is not about theory and so it's not a duplicate of that question.

In all implementations I'm aware of the code above or some equivalent thereof doesn't cause any observable problems - since the member function doesn't access the object the method will be called just fine.

May I have any real-life example in which the same setup causes practical observable problems?

Comment: What happens if you put some trivial codes that does not access object data members inside? Like a g_Num = rand(); where g_Num is a global variable.

Comment: @KennyTM: Not a dupe. That questions asks "when it is UB" and the answer is "it is UB at all times because the Standard says so". I know what the Standard says and want to know of an example when this leads to *observable problems*.

Comment: @ksming: That code will usually be executed.

Comment: Obviously, if the function is virtual, it *will* fail miserably.

Comment: If I cross the street with my eyes closed, will I always be run over by a bus?

Comment: @Bo Persson: No, but "you might be run over by a bus" would be a real life example of what could go wrong while crossing a street with your eyes closed.

Comment: Here's a very good example that does not include "simply beware of UB" and "crazy optimization" plots: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3257755/57428

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

```
struct Object { void foo(); std::string s; };

void print(Object* o) {
  o->foo();
  if (o) { std::cout << o->x << "\n"; }
}
```

Let us say that `foo` does not access any non-static attribute of `Object` (ie, `x`).

The problem is that because *formally* `o->foo()` is undefined behavior if `o` is null, then it is *obvious* that `o` is not null. Therefore the check is redundant.

The function is thus optimized:

```
void print(Object* o) {
  o->foo();
  std::cout << o->x << "\n";
}
```

Reversing the order does not change anything:

```
void print(Object* o) {
  if (o) { std::cout << o->x << "\n"; }
  o->foo();
}
```

is still optimized:

```
void print(Object* o) {
  std::cout << o->x << "\n";
  o->foo();
}
```

*Sometimes referred to as the Time Travel Clause of Undefined Behavior by some SO members.*

For more information, check out Chris Lattner's serie on Undefined Behavior:

- [What Every C Programmar Should Know About Undefined Behavior 1/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html)
- [What Every C Programmar Should Know About Undefined Behavior 2/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html)
- [What Every C Programmar Should Know About Undefined Behavior 3/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html)

Your specific concern is addressed in `2/3`.

Whether this actually fails depend on the compiler you use, the optimization passes you specify and the order in which they run.

Do you *really* want to depend on all that :x ?

Of course, one would argue that's it is pointless to have a function member that does not access any state of the object... so the question itself is of little value in practice (but interesting for its theoretical aspects).

Comment: Btw what exactly is called "time travel clause"? May I have a reference to any such usage?

Comment: @sharptooth: there is no *reference* AFAIK, I have just seen some members here (GMan or jalf perhaps) using it a few times. If you look at the second example (where the test preceeds the `o->foo()` statement), you can see that the presence of `o->foo()` affects the test (which is removed) even though the test is (in normal circumstances) executed before. Therefore, the UB of `o->foo()` creates a crash *before* the `o->foo()` statement is executed, as if it travelled into the past :)

Comment: Just FYI: I've found a more real life example that does not include hardcore optimizations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3257755/57428 Yours is great too.

Comment: @sharptooth: interesting indeed, though slightly different since `this` is actually accessed. What is amusing is that a compiler is allowed to consider that `this` is never `null` and thus the example could break even without multiple bases :)

Comment: Yes, you're right, but it is possible to craft some other example where `this` is not actually used by the method but the compiler needs to adjust it before passing into the method because it doesn't know what the method does inside. `this` will have insane value anyway, just this will be undetected.

Answer (score 1):

This is UB, so what would constitute a "problem"? To be a problem, the code would have to do something other than what the standards say it should do or what we expect it to do, otherwise it's not a problem. The standards give us no idea what the code should or will do, so whatever it does isn't a problem.

You say it doesn't cause any "observable problems". Well, of course not. Whatever it did would be fine. It could fault, and that wouldn't be a "problem" because that's what the standard tells us can happen.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that this code produces any problems on any platform I'm aware of. It is still undefined behavior, primarily because it is an irrelevant corner case: it could be defined that under certain conditions calling a member function on a null pointer would be OK. However, what is the point? If you don't access any of the members, why make the function a non-static member function? There is no loss in leaving this undefined as there is no conceivable need to define this case and it would thus unnecessarily complicate the language.

Comment: You could have a `dump()` function in the class that checks if `this == 0`, and then either prints "Null" or some diagnostics. If you then have a bunch of pointers, some null and some valid, you can mindlessly call `dump()` on all of them. But then, for the reasons Matthieu M. pointed out, this is still a bad idea...