# Why am I able to cast the this pointer of a base class to a pointer to a child class using the CRTP?

Tags: c++, crtp, dynamic-cast, static-cast

Consider the following classes, which employ the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP):

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

    void typeOfThis()
    {
        cout << "Type of this:  " << typeid(this).name() << '\n';
        cout << "Type of *this: " << typeid(*this).name() << '\n';
    }

    void callFuncOfTemplateParam()
    {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->hello();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    void hello()
    {
        cout << "Hello from Derived!" << '\n';
    }
};
```

When I execute the following:

```cpp
Base<Derived> * basePtrToDerived = new Derived();
basePtrToDerived->typeOfThis();
basePtrToDerived->callFuncOfTemplateParam();
```

I obtain these results, which make sense to me:

```
Type of this:  P4BaseI7DerivedE
Type of *this: 7Derived
Hello from Derived!
```

Clearly, the call to `hello` inside of `callFuncOfTemplateParam` succeeds because the `this` pointer points to an instance of `Derived`, which is why I am able to cast the `this` pointer from the type `Base<Derived>*` to the type `Derived*`.

Now, my confusion arises because when I execute the following:

```cpp
Base<Derived> * basePtrToBase = new Base<Derived>();
basePtrToBase->typeOfThis();
basePtrToBase->callFuncOfTemplateParam();
```

I obtain the following results:

```
Type of this:  P4BaseI7DerivedE
Type of *this: 4BaseI7DerivedE
Hello from Derived!
```

The types of `this` and `*this` make sense, but I don't understand how the call to `hello` succeeds. `this` doesn't point to an instance of `Derived`, so why am I able to cast the type of `this` from `Base<Derived>` to `Derived`?

Note that I also replaced the call to `static_cast<T*>(this)->hello();` with a call to `dynamic_cast<T*>(this)->hello();`, and I still obtain the same results. I expected the `dynamic_cast` to return a `nullptr`, but it doesn't.

I am very surprised by these results. Thank you for any help clarifying my doubts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast used to call `hello()` has **undefined behavior** when `T` does not match the true type of the object that `this` points to.  But `hello()` isn't accessing anything via `this`, so it doesn't really matter what `this` actually points to.  You could just as easily do `reinterpret_cast<T*>(12345)->hello()` and it would still "work".  However you decide to cast `this` wont make any difference since `hello()` simply ignores the result (in the case of `dynamic_cast`, see [Does calling a method on a NULL pointer which doesn't access any data ever fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413892/)).

Change your classes to introduce data members that `hello()` tries to access via `this`, and you will see very different results (ie, the code will likely crash, or report garbage, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer Remy! I had no idea that calling a method on a nullptr could actually work. That's classic me, choosing the one test that fails as a sanity check hahaha.