# Does MSVC allow to call non-virtual non-static functions on a nullptr?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

**Note: This question is about MSVC, not about the C++ Standard!**

According to the C++ standard, calling any member function (virtual or not) on `nullptr` is undefined behaviour (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257393/is-it-legal-well-defined-c-to-call-a-non-static-method-that-doesnt-access-mem) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-behav)). As such I was mildly surprised that when I created a MFC Application with the Visual Studio Wizard to find this code:

```
void CClassView::AdjustLayout()
{
    if (GetSafeHwnd() == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    //...
```

Where `GetSafeHwnd` is defined as:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE HWND CWnd::GetSafeHwnd() const
    { return this == NULL ? NULL : m_hWnd; }
```

This makes me wonder what the rules of MSVC actually are. According to this implementation, calling a function on a `nullptr` seems to be fine, it's just that `this` is then the `nullptr`. Is this assumption correct for MSVC? What if the member function is virtual? What if it's pure virtual?

Comment: It's UB I'd say.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Please keep in mind that this is generated code from Microsoft. I guess they know what's legal with their implementation of C++ and what isn't. This is NOT a question about the C++ Standard, but a direct question about MSVC.

Comment: I've reopened this. This doesn't ask what the standard says, only what MSVC does.

Comment: It doesn't make much difference, they're allowed to change that at any time they'd like to, without any acknowledgement. Thus I'd never rely on that. @Brotcrunsher

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So what would you do in OP's position, where the generated code seems to rely on this assumption?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat blaming the MFC devs. They're not the same people which develop the compiler.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher it's a question about MFC, not MSVC.

Comment: Asking a question of "What extended guarantees does MSVC give when..." is a question about MSVC. Closing this question is unhelpful and doesn't answer an actually practical question.

Comment: Some of the MFC code is way older than the C++ standard.

Comment: @Peter [`GetSafeHwnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getsafehwnd) is a non-static class member of `CWnd` provided by the MFC library. You cannot change that. Plus, it is used internally by MFC literally all over the place. If compiler rules were to ever change, Microsoft would be among the first to find out. Leaving a comment or otherwise documenting the need for future re-assessment doesn't appear to be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's still not allowed.

MFC gets away with it because it's closely tied to MSVC. Microsoft ensures that the MFC code continues to work as intended with new versions of MSVC. This might include non-portable solutions.

As a practical matter, MFC doesn't use virtual inheritance or multiple inheritance in cases where this check exists. So you're on even less solid ground there.