# C++ standard question

Tags: c++

should the following result in undefined behavior?

should value of pointer2 be NULL?

```
double *pointer = 0;
double &value = *pointer;
double *pointer2 = &value;
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-behav

Comment: Which C standard do you think even allows `double &value`??? They are different languages with different standards and different feature sets. Arrggghhhh!!!!!

Comment: Yes, the behavior is undefined. However, if you try it, you may find the code compiles and executes without complaint or crash, since the invalid reference isn't used except to initialize another pointer. "Nothing" is another acceptable response to undefined behavior.

Comment: The Standard's note says 'in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-deﬁned program, because the only
way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer,
which causes undeﬁned behavior'. It would now be interesting to know why the committee in some issue discussion states that merely dereferencing a null pointer is intended to be valid, given that note says the exact opposite. It is not some badly worded normative wording, but a clearly worded note, which indeed exist for the whole purpose of explaining intent.

Comment: @Johannes: Because there's more than one committee member? It's a good thing that the Standard conservatively represents the <s>union</s> intersection of their combined thoughts…

Comment: @Johannes: I'm confused by: "the committee in some issue discussion states that merely dereferencing a null pointer is intended to be valid...". I'm not sure what you're refering to there.

Comment: @Michael http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

```
double *pointer = 0;    // init `pointer` to a NULL pointer value
double &value = *pointer; // dereference it
```

The standard specifically speaks to this situation - from 8.3.2/4 "References":

> A reference shall be initialized to
>   refer to a valid object or function.
>   [Note: in particular, a null reference
>   cannot exist in a well-defined
>   program, because the only way to
>   create such a reference would be to
>   bind it to the “object” obtained by
>   dereferencing a null pointer, which
>   causes undefined behavior. As
>   described in 9.6, a reference cannot
>   be bound directly to a bit-field. ]

Comment: does it matter that I do not read/write to the memory location per se?

Comment: @aaa: Not as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: You might not have a crash at that point because the compiler might not actually try to 'read' memory location 0.  However, that's one of the unfortunate natures of undefined behavior - the compiler doesn't have to act like it's an error.  Even so, setting a reference via a NULL pointer dereference is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're dereferencing a null pointer when you do `*pointer` in line 2.