# Does a C++ method definition in a class have to specify the return type?

Tags: c++, return-type

Just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927936/when-is-the-segfault-thrown) relating to a segmentation fault issue in a C++ class and program.

My question relates to the class definition.  Here it is as it was posted:

```
class A { 
    int x; 
    int y;

    public: 
    getSum1() const { 
        return getx() + y; 
    } 

    getSum2() const { 
        return y + getx(); 
    }

    getx() const { 
        return x; 
    }     
}
```

None of the answers on that question so far made any mention about the return types of the methods.  I'd expect them to be defined like

```
int getSum1() const { ....
int getSum2() const { ....
int getx() const { ....
```

Do the `int`s have to be there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `int`s have to be there. The original code sample is not valid (as someone else mentioned the code may have originally been C instead of C++). Firstly, the class declaration needs a terminating semicolon to stand a chance of compiling. g++ reports:

```
foo.cpp:3: note: (perhaps a semicolon is missing after the definition of ‘A’)
```

Adding the semicolon we get:

```
class A { 
  int x; 
  int y;

public: 
  getSum1() const { 
    return getx() + y; 
  } 

  getSum2() const { 
    return y + getx(); 
  }

  getx() const { 
    return x; 
  }     
};
```

Which still fails. g++ will report the following:

```
foo.cpp:8: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘getSum1’ with no type
foo.cpp:12: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘getSum2’ with no type
foo.cpp:16: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘getx’ with no type
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in C++ return types **must** be specified. For a comparison between C and C++, see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Ffunc_type_specifier.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do have to be there.