# Can you use a class without objects?

Tags: c++, oop

EDIT: No... I dont wanna use :: I want to be able to use . when using static method
EDIT 2: Not a namespace. A class/struct is what I'm trying to use!

I bet this has been asked and answered before but I cant find an answer

Suppose I have a class called "A"

```
struct A {
    void log(const char* x) {
         std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If i want to use this class i need to do something like `A B;`
Then i can do something like `B.log("Hello World!");`

But is there any possible way I dont have to make an object to use a class? I just want to be able to do `A.log("Hello World!");`

Is that possible?

Comment: You are confusing class with struct. Yes, off-course you can call methods directly. Just use the magic word `static` in function definition

Comment: ... and then it would be `A::log("Hello World!");`

Comment: @PaulSanders So using static makes me have to use :: instead of . ?

Comment: @Abhishek I thought the only difference was struct was public by default

Comment: @Abhishek OP is correct in their usage. Aside from the default accessibility, `class` and `struct` are the same.

Comment: Agree, but in the question OP was using struct and calling it as a class :-) I was just pointing it out.

Comment: @Duffka _So using static makes me have to use :: instead of ._ If you have an instance of the object, you can use `instance.log()`.  If not, you can use the class name as I showed above.

Comment: @Abhishek Well, structs are classes, so there appears to be no confusion on OP's part regarding that. P.S. unions are classes too.

Comment: Referencing another question, as it looks relevant for the use case of (dot) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731406/dot-access-to-static-method

Comment: @eerorika strictly speaking it isn't. I mean private and public access identifier makes a difference :-)

Comment: @Abhishek Strictly speaking it is. Struct is a class that is defined with the class-key `struct`. The default access specifier of classes defined with class-key `class` is different from the default access specifier of classes defined with the class-key `struct` or `union`, but that doesn't make the latter non-classes.

Comment: What is a class-key?

Comment: @Abhishek class-key is part of the grammar of the class definition. The simplified grammar is `class-key attribute-specifier-seq class-head-name class-virt-specifier base-clause { member-specification }`. The grammar of class-key is `class | struct | union`. All language rules that apply to classes also apply to structs and unions, because they are also classes - unless those rules explicitly exclude structs or unions. It is always correct to say that a struct is a class.

Comment: Unbelievable!! Thanks for sharing this with me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224387/discussion-between-abhishek-and-eerorika).

Answer (score 4):

> Can you use a class without objects?

Yes, you can. For example, you can access static members of a class.

> I want to be able to use . when using static method

You cannot do what you want. The member access operator `.` can only be used on values of the class type and for that you need an object. The operator to access static member function of a class without an object is the scope resolution operator `::`.

You also cannot call a non-static member function - such as `A::Log` of your example - without an instance regardless of syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code as follows,

```
class A {
    static void log(const char* x) {
         std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}

//Call it as follows,
A::log("hello");
```

Observe the word, `static`. `static` methods are class level methods and should be called via class. You will not be able to call it with objects of the class `A`.

You can use `struct` instead of `class` if you like :-)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using a class could be to use a *namespace* instead:

```
namespace A {
void log(const char* x) {
     std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
}
```

That way, your class doesn't need to exist, it can just be a free-function inside it's own namespace. You even call it the same way:

```
A::log("foo");
```

Comment: The changes are very small but I'm not looking for a namespace. A class(Because i want to use . and not :: small yes I know but thats what I'm looking for here)

Comment: @Duffka If your function is static inside a class, and you don't have an object instance, you still have to use `::` with the class version too :-). But obviously if you want/have to use a class, then that's the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

> But is there any possible way I dont have to make an object to use a class? I just want to be able to do A.log("Hello World!");

To use that syntax, you need an object.

With a small change, you can have your expected syntax:

```
/*inline*/ struct {
    void log(const char* x) {
         std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
} A;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc96418b50c26838)

Anonymous class, with variable `A` of that type.
If put in header included at several place, adding `inline` or `static` would avoid ODR-violation.

Using regular way (static method and `A::log`) is less surprising.