# At what point does dereferencing the null pointer become undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, object, null, undefined-behavior, dereference

If I don't actually access the dereferenced "object", is dereferencing the null pointer still undefined?

```
int* p = 0;
int& r = *p;    // undefined?
int* q = &*p;   // undefined?
```

A slightly more practical example: can I dereference the null pointer to distinguish between overloads?

```
void foo(Bar&);
void foo(Baz&);

foo(*(Bar*)0);  // undefined?
```

---

Okay, the reference examples are definitely undefined behavior according to the standard:

> a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the "object" obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, **which causes undefined behavior**.

Unfortunately, the emphasized part is ambiguous. Is it the *binding* part that causes undefined behavior, or is the *dereferencing* part sufficient?

Comment: [This question covers the information you want.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-behav)

Comment: This must be an exact dupe. I know we have discussed this beore.

Comment: "At what point does dereferencing the null pointer become undefined behavior?" - The instant it happens. And once it happens your *entire* program is undefined and the compiler is free to generate *anything*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is undefined behavior, because the spec says that an "lvalue designates an object or function" (at clause 3.10) and it says for the `*`-operator "the result [of dereferencing] is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points" (at clause 5.3.1).

That means there is no description for what happens when you dereference a null pointer. It's simply undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

```
int& r = *p;    // undefined?
```

I think right here you've undefined behavior even if you don't *actually* use `r` (or `*p`)- the dereferenced object. Because after this step (i.e dereferencing the null pointer), the program  behaviour is not guaranteed by the language, as the program may crash immediately which is one of the possibilities of UB. You seem to think that only reading the value of `r` so as to be *used* in *real* purpose invokes UB. I don't think so.

Also, the language specification clearly says *"the effect of dereferencing the null pointer"* invokes undefined behavior. It does **not** say *"the effect of **actually** using dereferenced object from a null pointer"* invokes UB. The effect of dereferencing the null pointer (or in other words *undefined behavior*) doesn't mean that you will *necessarily and immediately* get problems, or it must crash *immediately* after dereferencing the null pointer. No. It simply means, the entire program behavior is not defined if the program contains any UB at all (like dereferencing a null pointer). That is, the program **may** run normally, as expected, from start to end. Or it may crash immediately, or after after some time -  after few minutes, hours or days. Anything can happen **anytime**, **before** or **after** dereferencing the null pointer.

Comment: I cannot find "the effect of dereferencing the null pointer" in the standard. Where exactly did you find it?

Comment: @FredOverflow : §1.9/4 (C++03) says `Certain other operations are described in this International Standard as undefined (for example, the effect of dereferencing the null pointer). [Note: this International Standard imposes no requirements on the behavior of programs that contain undefined behavior. ]`

Comment: The FDIS replaced the null pointer example with `for example, the effect of attempting to modify a const object`, which might indicate that the rules about dereferencing the null pointer have changed.

Comment: @Fred no. they replaced it because they want to change it to defined behavior in the long run (post-c++0x) and wanted a better example of undefined behavior.

Comment: It's actually worse than "anything can happen anytime after dereferencing the null pointer".  In addition, "also, anything can happen anytime before dereferencing the null pointer."  q.v. Raymond Chen's [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Comment: "No. It simply means, the program behavior is not defined after dereferencing the null pointer" - It's not even defined for what happened *before* the nullptr dereference. Once you invoke undefined behaviour, the *entire* program is undefined and the compiler is allowed to even go back in time and undo what you did earlier - UB doesn't just mean that "code from here on is broken" it means "you can't trust *anything* your program ever did or will ever do".

Comment: @JesperJuhl: That's correct. Completely agree. Feel free to edit the answer, as I'm not in touch with these nuances anymore. You'll frame it better and possibly might add more.

Answer (score 6):

I think the second opus of [What every C programmer should know about Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) might help illustrate this issue.

Taking the example of the blog:

```
void contains_null_check(int *P) {
  int dead = *P;
  if (P == 0)
    return;
  *P = 4;
}
```

Might be optimized to (RNCE: Redundant Null Check Elimintation):

```
void contains_null_check_after_RNCE(int *P) {
  int dead = *P;
  if (false)  // P was dereferenced by this point, so it can't be null 
    return;
  *P = 4;
}
```

Which is turn optimized into (DCE: Dead Code Elimination):

```
void contains_null_check_after_RNCE_and_DCE(int *P) {
  //int dead = *P; -- dead store
  //if (false)     -- unreachable branch
  //  return;
  *P = 4;
}
```

As you can see, even though `dead` is *never* used, the simple `int dead = *P` assignment has caused Undefined Behavior to creep in the program.

To distinguish between overloads, I'd suggest using a pointer (which might be null) rather than artificially creating a null reference and exposing yourself to Undefined Behavior.