# Initializing a reference to member to NULL in C++

Tags: c++, reference, ctor-initializer

Is it possible to initialize a reference member to NULL in c++?
I'm trying to something like this:

```
class BigClass
{
private:
    Object m_inner;
public:
    const Object& ReadOnly;
    BigClass() : ReadOnly(NULL)
    {
      Do stuff.
    }
};
```

I know I can do this if I initialize "ReadOnly" to a real reference of an object, but when I want to put in there "NULL", i get the error:

> "cannot convert from 'int' to 'const Object &'

How can I solve this?

Comment: The point of a reference is to make this impossible.  Use a regular pointer instead.

Comment: You can do this {    
    const Object& ReadOnly = \*(Object\*)NULL;
} But its fugly.
The pre-processor just removes the & and the \*

Comment: @Justin "_The pre-processor just removes the & and the *_" nonsense

Comment: @curiousguy hem... let me elaborate hater. The preprocessor cancels out *& combo. The declaring using ref & is just short hand so you don't need to use the -> it's short hand for (*the).thing. so there ;)

Comment: @Justin The C++ preprocessor does no such thing.

Comment: Sorry pre-compiler

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No, references cannot be `NULL` in C++.<sup>1</sup>

Possible solutions include:

- using a pointer instead of a reference.
- having a dummy `Object` instance that can be used to indicate "no object".

---

<sub>[1] From the [C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf):</sub>

> <sub>**[dcl.ref]** [...] a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior.</sub>

Comment: @Magnus: Yep, don't do, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @wandalen - Which part?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth reference is not magic thing. Reference could point on NULL. For example : Object& object = *( Object* ) NULL.

Comment: @wandalen - That won't compile.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Object& object = * ( Object * ) NULL

Comment: It does, last time asterisks were deleted by stackoverflow, sorry.

Comment: @wandalen: Ok but that's now simply undefined behaviour.  And the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) explicitly calls this out: "*a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only
way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer,
which causes undefined behavior*".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes, it's not the most famous technique, and there are too many customs around this things. few programmers from the previous century made all their best to force the world to think in a way they like. they succeed :) only just. regards.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot "solve" this. Use a pointer if you want to be able to have that member not point to anything.

References must be initialized to a real object, they cannot "point nowhere".

Comment: @EthanSteinberg: depends. Smart pointers usually involve ownership. Sometimes you just want to point to something without claiming ownership. Of course you could use a weak pointer, but this requires allocating the object on the heap: no stack allocated object, no attribute of a bigger object, etc... *Smart Pointers are **NOT** a panacea*.

Answer (score 9):

It can be done but it is almost certainly an **extremely bad idea**. The way to do it is to dereference a suitably typed `NULL` pointer which already shows that it is a bad idea: you arrive at undefined behavior at this point which, however, typically tends to "work".

In C++ references are meant to always refer to an actual object. This is different to other programming languages where "references" are actually the equivalent of *pointers* in C++ (typically without things like pointer arithmetic). What you probably actually want (you unfortunately didn't say what you try to achieve it but asked about a solution to a problem which is probably part of a misguided approach) is to use a pointer instead:

```
Object const* const readOnly;
BigClass(): readOnly(0) {}
```

Comment: My favourite answer. I just had to debug a complex class, and needed to call a single function, with a certain object. 0 referenced all the references as described, constructed obj, ignored references, called function, fixed the problem, undid everything. Obviously not something you want to do permanently though.

Answer (score 6):

It's useful in writing unit-tests. That is the *only* place it should be done, but there, it's quite helpful.

```
 Bar& bar(*static_cast<Bar*>(0));
 MockClass mock; // derives from RealClass
 mock.foo(bar);
```

Here, I am testing code which uses `MockClass`, not `MockClass` itself.

It's not a panacea, but it can help. Also, [GoogleMock](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=googlemock&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fgooglemock%2F&ei=39-JUJrlOaKNigKckYCoAQ&usg=AFQjCNF8vsE9svghL2ubFL0KIDYd71-YtQ) might be your friend if you are mocking "concrete" classes.

```
struct Bar;
struct RealClass {
  int& x_;
  double& y_;
  RealClass(int& x, double& y) :x_(x), y_(y) {}
  virtual void foo(Bar&);
};
struct MockClass: public RealClass {
  MockClass(): RealClass(*(int*)0, *(double*)0) {}
  MOCK_METHOD1(foo, void(Bar&));
};
```

Comment: Down-voters: Try this *without* using a reference to NULL. Very difficult! In case it's not obvious, we aim to test code which uses a `RealClass` and which calls `foo()` on that `RealClass`. We inject both the `RealClass` and the `Bar` instances. `MockClass` needs to call the constructor of `RealClass`, but the underlying data are never needed. This is a valid use-case, so stop down-voting.

Comment: If you need to write this kind of tests, I think you have a serious design problem.

Comment: Legacy code or not, introducing undefined behavior in unit tests is a terrible idea.

Comment: It's not undefined behavior. And it answers the question. Downvote the question, not the answer.

Comment: It is UB. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130878/at-what-point-does-dereferencing-the-null-pointer-become-undefined-behavior).

Comment: In practice, absense of behavior. If you switch to a compiler where it fails, delete the test. But you're right: It's worth advising against using this in production code.

Comment: Thanks @cdunn2001! It was very helpful for mocking unit testing my application with GTKmm.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Can't believe this isnt the accepted answer rather than comments like "this is a bad idea" etc.... sigh

Answer (score 3):

Use a pointer:-
 const Object* pReadOnly;