# Mutually referencing instances

Tags: c++

A similar question got asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719937/initializing-mutually-referencing-objects%20here), but didn't get a proper answer.

Is the following legal?

```
struct B;

struct A
{
    A(B& b) : b(b) 
    {
    }

    B& b;
};

struct B
{
    B(A& a) : a(a)
    {
    }

    A& a;
};

struct C
{
    C() : a(b), b(a)
    {
    }

    A a;
    B b;
};
```

I wonder if it falls under 3.8 (6) (C++ 2003)

> ... before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage
>   which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime
>   of an object has ended and before the storage which the object
>   occupied is reused or released, any lvalue which refers to the
>   original object may be used but only in limited ways. Such an lvalue
>   refers to allocated storage (3.7.3.2), and using the properties of the
>   lvalue which do not depend on its value is well-defined.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant to your question, but it looks to me like that initializer list for `C` will never work right. The order of initialisation is dependent on the order of declaration.

Comment: I think as long as the A and B constructors only memorize references without accessing the referenced objects, they will succeed. I guess this counts as "using the properties which do not depend on its value".

Comment: Seems legal to me, too.

Comment: how do you plan to instantiate either an `A` or a `B` ? Both require the existence of an instance of the other type before they can be instantiated.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker fizzer references the standard in the question.

Comment: Those voting to close as duplicate: Yes, I've read the other question (I link to it).  It's not the same - other poster uses aggregate initialization - and the answers he gets are speculative.

Comment: @PeterWood : I understand that, but presumably having two separate classes `A` and `B` implies that they will be used separately too - otherwise what's the point of having two classes if you always have to use them in combination.

Comment: @Sander They could be implementations of abstract classes.

Comment: @PeterWood : fair point - I can see some value in that.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly legal.  Clearly the storage of A and B are allocated as C is allocated prior to constructing C... thus the references to A and B are well-defined and can be used.  However, you wouldn't be able to dereference the B object in the constructor of the A object.  Oppositely, deferencing A in the constructor of B *should* be OK, although compiler support for any of this might be spotty...

Comment: For grins I tried this in VS2012 and it 1) compiled fine, but unexpectedly 2) allowed me to derefernce B in constructor of A which resulted in accessing uninitialized memory.