# Why is gcc 4.7.0 giving me a segfault on this code while online ideone(gcc 4.5.1) doesnt?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, segmentation-fault

I have the following code (works only on gcc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>

const std::string demangle (const char* name) {

    int status = -4;
    char* res = abi::__cxa_demangle(name, 0, 0, &status);
    const char* const demangled_name = (status == 0) ? res : name;
    std::string ret_val(demangled_name);
    std::free(res);

    return ret_val;
}

template <typename T>
const std::string getname (T x)
{
    return demangle(typeid(x).name());
}

int main()
{
   std::add_const<int>::type *p = static_cast<const int *>(0); 
   std::cout << getname(*p) << std::endl;
}
```

On my local computer (with gcc 4.7.0(experimental) it crashes (run with gdb gives a segfault). However, with ideone.com, it prints "int" as expected. Heres, [a link to the example](http://ideone.com/hnfWh). Also, getting rid of the template and calling `demangle(typeid(x).name())` directly fixes the problem, so what is wrong with the template?

**EDIT**
I forgot to include the `type_traits` header (doh!) which fixed the problem, however I would still like to know what is going on a little better.

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is that you are dereferencing a null pointer, which is UB, and so both results that you observe are "correct".

Comment: @todda.speot.is: As specified by the standard, it's undefined behavior in C++. If you want to talk about specific C++ implementations on specific platforms on specific hardware at a specific time that's fine, but realize you are no longer talking about the C++ *language*.

Comment: @GMan Admittedly there is undefined behaviour for some operations involving NULL pointers in the C++ standard, so I take my comments back. However http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232 seems to consider it defined behaviour in certain scenarios, and after reading around a bit more it seems that in this case it's defined behaviour [Objects of class `std::bad_typeid` are thrown when `typeid` is called on a dereferenced null pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid). Although it's undefined for other operations.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: Note that issue is still active, and AFAIK was not been incorporated into the new standard. ([This was an area of interest to me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha/2474021#2474021).) Anyway, the sentence in that article is actually too lose, the relevant section in the standard is §5.2.8/2. It says very specifically that the expression *in the `typeid` expression* can take the form `*p`, `*(p)`, etc., and `p` can be null. That isn't the case here, where UB has already occurred.

Comment: @GMan You are correct, `*p` is not the expression given to `typeid`.

Comment: @GMan: Thanks, you last comment cleared everything up for me, if it was an answer, I would have set it as the answer.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: (Note that Ive subsequently edited the article to clarify.)

Comment: @Jesse: No problem, I'll just let the comments be comments (if the moderators allow...) and you can give Nawaz the points, I've enough rep. :)

Comment: @GMan: **§5.2.8/2** only applies to glvalue expressions whose types are polymorphic class types. **§5.2.8/3** regulates the non-polymorphic case but is silent on the issue of null pointers, however it says *unevaluated operand* which suggests to me it's fine, but I could not find a citation backing up this claim.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Oops, right you are. Since it doesn't evaluate it, the value of the expression doesn't matter, only the type.

Comment: @GMan: that is my guess too, but I didn't find anything close to it.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: It's defined (rather loosely) in §5/8. §4.1/2 also touches on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::add_const<int>::type *p = static_cast<const int *>(0);
```

`p` is a null pointer, and dereferencing it (i.e `*p`) invokes give undefined behaviour (UB). You are lucky that it gives segfault. And since it is *actually* UB, all compilers (and all versions) may not give segfault, for that is what UB means, i.e anything could happen.

Why don't you try this instead:

```
std::cout << getname(int()) << std::endl;
```

Comment: @todda.speot.is: Did you even read the linked article? "While this works correctly in many compilers, it has undefined behavior according to the C standard, since it involves both a dereference of a null pointer, and a cast that violates the aliasing rules. It also tends to produce confusing compiler diagnostics if one of the arguments is misspelled. Modern compilers often define the macro using a special form instead." It's undefined behavior. Stop trying to define it.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: There is no such thing as "userspace" in C++. Dereferencing a null pointer *in C++* is undefined behaviour, though that is not at variance with having a particular platform provide additional guarantees.

Comment: @GMan I had a hunt around the C99 standard and while I found something *close* to defining that implementation of `addressof` as defined behaviour it's explict enough. So you're right in the regard, I should have read the article.

Comment: @GMan : What cast is violating aliasing rules?

Comment: @ildjarn: todda.speot.is had linked to [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof), I was quoting it.

Comment: @GMan : Ah, I see; I thought you were referring to something in the OP's question or this answer and was wondering what I was missing. :-]

Answer (score 3):

There is a subtle issue here: it's a problem of evaluation.

Normally, dereferencing a null pointer is *Undefined Behavior*; however there is a corner case (at least on gcc), that invoking `typeid(*p)` where `p` is null is a valid expression.

Therefore the issue here resides in your level of indirection:

```
int* p = 0;

getname(*p);       // p is null, *p invokes undefined behavior

typeid(*p).name(); // p is null, but it's probably okay in `typeid`
                   // because it's an unevaluated operand here
```

---

For those interesting in delving deeper, the `typeid` expression is described in detail in **§5.2.8** (C++11).

> **2/** When `typeid` is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a polymorphic class type (10.3), the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type of the most derived object (1.8) (that is, the dynamic type) to which the glvalue refers. If the glvalue expression is obtained by applying the unary `*` operator to a pointer and the pointer is a null pointer value (4.10), the `typeid` expression throws the `std::bad_typeid` exception (18.7.3).

Okay, so `typeid(*p)` is defined if `p` points to a polymorphic class... and in this case it throws.

> **3/** When `typeid` is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a polymorphic class type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the static type of the expression. Lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) conversions are not applied to the expression. If the type of the expression is a class type, the class shall be completely-defined. The expression is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5).

Interestingly, no mention of null pointers for non-polymorphic classes. I suspect the *unevaluated operand* is what allows this, but have yet to find the citation.

> **6/** If the header `<typeinfo>` (18.7.1) is not included prior to a use of `typeid`, the program is ill-formed.

No diagnostic seems required. At least on gcc I think it fires off a warning though.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually wondering why `std::bad_typeid` was not being thrown.