# Why is this happening in C++?

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-behavior

I came across a very strange behaviour using G++ (4.5.2) on different platforms; here's the code :

```
class Class
{
private:
  std::string rString;

public:
  Class()
  {
    this->rString = "random string";
    std::cout << "Constructor of Class" << std::endl;
  }

  virtual ~Class()
  {
    std::cout << "Destructor of Class" << std::endl;
  }

  void          say() const
  {
    std::cout << "Just saying ..." << std::endl;
    if (this == NULL)
      std::cout << "Man that's really bad" << std::endl;
  }

  void          hello() const
  {
    std::cout << "Hello " << this->rString << std::endl;
  }

};


int     main()
{
  Class *c = NULL;

  /* Dereferencing a NULL pointer results
     in a successful call to the non-static method say()
     without constructing Class */
  (*c).say(); // or c->say()

  /* Dereferencing a NULL pointer and accessing a random
     memory area results in a successful call to say()
     as well */
  c[42000].say();

  /* Dereferencing a NULL pointer and accessing a
     method which needs explicit construction of Class
     results in a Segmentation fault */
  c->hello();

  return (0);
}
```

The question is, why the two first statements in the main function don't crash the program?  Is this undefined behaviour, or the compiler is simply calling Class::say() as if it was static since it doesn't dereference "this" pointer inside the method?

Comment: Your edit was completely unnecessary, and pretty misguided: `inline` has no effect here because functions that are defined inside a class are automatically `inline`.

Comment: You're wrong, the compiler may or may not `inline` these methods in the binary file he will generate. Just because these methods are defined and implemented within the class `Class` does not automatically mean they will actually be inlined. Plus, prepending my prototypes with the `inline` keyword does not either mean this code will be inlined by the compiler. I'm just giving a hint to the compiler saying that generating a prolog for each of these methods might be heavy.

Comment: No, *you* are wrong. You picked up some half-information that is largely right, but not completely. [Member functions that are defined (as opposed to just declared) inside a class are automatically `inline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw1hbe6y(v=vs.80).aspx) (§7.1.2/3 of the standard). Note that `inline` has more effects than just advising the compiler to perform call inlining. §7.1.2 has more details.

Comment: I was sure of the opposit. Anyway, marking these methods as inline is not, at the end, totally `unnecessary, and pretty misguided` as they've reminded me of this aspect of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's undefined behavior. [You cannot call a member function with a null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha/2474021#2474021).

In practice, the first two indeed work because `this` is never dereferenced so your undefined behavior doesn't have to manifest like it does in the third, where memory is indeed wrongly accessed.

(In all cases, you die a little inside each time it's called, so don't do that.)

Comment: Technically, `this` *is* used (inside `Class::say`), but it's never dereferenced. So there are no invalid memory accesses.

Comment: @bitmask: True, I spoke too loosely. :)

Comment: That's what we at Nit Pickers Inc. are here for.

Answer (score 6):

Undefined behavior just means what happens is not defined.  It doesn't mean "crash."

**Undefined behavior can do anything at all, including work the way you intend it to.**

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior. Since you're not using functions as "virtual" this will just call the functions statically.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined behavior, though it would appear in the first two instances it's been optimized to call `Class::say()` without using any member variables of the object itself (hence this-> not being dereferenced/used causing a sigserv), but the 3rd attempts to access it's member. Likewise, the following may seg fault on another compiler like VC++'s.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, the compiler implements calls to non-static, non-virtual functions by simply passing the object pointer `this` as additional parameter or rather together with all the proper parameters on the stack.

The standard doesn't mandate what is supposed to happen when a member function is called with something that is not a memory location holding an actual object of the respective class or struct. Requiring this would require non-noop runtime checks (if possible at all) and is therefore not reasonable to ask from a conforming implementation.

The typing system already makes sure you have go out of your way to call a member function with an object of a wrong type, but checking against `NULL` or `nullptr` calls cannot meaningfully be covered by the pointer type.
If you want your binary to crash when a member function is called with the null pointer, making the member function `virtual` should do the job, because the compiler will *have* to dereference the vptr of `this` and the operating system will respond by showing you the finger.