# C++ Call a non-virtual non-static method from a null pointer, without accessing members : is this guaranteed to work?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, null, member

Can I call a non-static, non-virtual method of a class from a null pointer? The member function would then test if this==nullptr, and return immediately if it's true.

I know it will work in most cases, but is this a guaranteed result? That way, I can ensure null pointer exceptions never happen, and avoid testing for null pointers in many places of the caller code. That's for compactness, I'm not going to do that right now, but I'm curious to know if any standard will guarantee this to work...

Thanks!

Comment: no, it's guaranteed undefined behavior.

Comment: Why do we vote someone down who provides a well articulated question? Asker wants to know about undefined behavior and is asking about it, it is even phrased distinctly from the propose possible duplicate.

Comment: Article: Still Comparing "this" Pointer to Null? - http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0226/

Comment: @Sqeaky - Plus, its 2014 and the standards have been revised. So the previous answers may not even apply. Its classic [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users) with a bit of "I know more than you" sprinkled on top.

Answer (score 4):

Dereferencing a `nullptr` is **Undefined behavior**. Period!
Whether it works or not on one particular implementation is irrelevant, the behavior is not guaranteed.

Comment: I like the authority :)

Comment: Although I agree with your answer, and the question was about  "guaranteed" behavior: in real life it works some time, and if you have to deal with some code which relies on such things (or more complicated cases of UB), there are a lot of details after the "Period!"...

Comment: That's stating. Please cite your references! Otherwise trusting the answer is not guaranteed.

Comment: @galinette: That is the most common and basically known Undefined behavior use case. If you don't know this basic fact, then you are in dire need of a good book. And No I am not going to summon the holy standard for such a trivial case.

Comment: @anxieux: Once UB occurs the behaviors are undefined from the perspective of the standard so there is no point trying to find meaningful conclusion to it especially when there is no mention of specific compiler implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The standard expliticly mentions dereferencing NULL pointer as undefined behavior. Using opearator -> dereferences the pointer to left.

So you're okay only in case if your implementation *defined* some behavior for the case, as it is a possibility (though I never encountered it in real life yet).

(I hope you understand that observing something is not the same as being defined.)

Answer (score 0):

always avoid calling a null pointer, 
you would usually end up with a core dump

Comment: I will definitely avoid it... In fact, knowing the mechanisms of member functions ('this' is just passed as a hidden first argument to an otherwise static function), I was just wondering how the behavior is defined in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

There are interesting answers here:
[When does invoking a member function on a null instance result in undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha)

Also, the standard gives no hint about the mechanism for calling member virtual functions. It is usually done by just passing 'this' as a hidden function argument, which will in practice not dereference the pointer and work. However, it seems possible to implement even non-virtual function with a vtable, which in this case would crash.

Interestingly, a Microsoft function relies on this behavior :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d64ehwhz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx