# Does C++ compiler automatically sets my function as static?

Tags: c++, singleton, instance

Here's my question with sample code.
In the case a class function never uses instance related data or never references `this`, could the compiler decide this function is kind of static ?

As an example see this code (with description below) :

```
class Dummy
{
    public:
        Dummy()
        {
            std::cout << "Dummy()" << std::endl;
            mInstance = this;
        }
        ~Dummy()
        {
            std::cout << "~Dummy()" << std::endl;
            mInstance = nullptr;
        }

        static Dummy& instance()
        {
            std::cout << "static Dummy& instance()" << std::endl;
            return *mInstance;
        }

        void foo()
        {
            std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
        }


    private:
        int mData;
        static Dummy* mInstance;


};

Dummy* Dummy::mInstance = nullptr;
```

- At construction, my `Dummy` class references it's instance in a *static* variable called `mInstance` using a pointer.
- `mInstance` is available through the *static* function `instance()`.
- `foo()` is not a *static* function. Hence I need and instance to call it.
- `mInstance` is initialized to `nullptr`.

That case if my `main` only does :

```
Dummy::instance().foo();
```

I should get a *seg fault*. Because instance() would de-reference a `nullptr`.

Instead the program runs and the output will be :

```
bar
```

...And only this line so it does not seem to call neither the constructor nor the destructor.

Yet if my `foo()` function is :

```
        void foo()
        {
            mData = 5;
            std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
        }
```

Here a *seg fault* occurs.

I tend to guess as `foo()` actually did not reference anything proper to the instance, the compiler guessed it was a static and compiled this way.
But it does not seem to be logical as `instance()` function returns a reference to an instance and even if the `foo()` is static, `foo()` should not be callable...

As an other example, without the `mData = 5` instruction, if my main is :

```
        Dummy& vDummy = Dummy::instance();
        std::cout << &vDummy << std::endl;
        vDummy.foo();
```

The output is :

```
        statci Dummy& instance()
        0
        bar
```

I don't really understand the way things are done here.... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of member functions (non static) as functions with a hidden parameter that is a pointer to your object. So your `void foo()` could be considered as `void foo(Dummy* d)`. And since you never use that pointer to Dummy, it does not matter if you pass a NULL pointer to it.

Hope this makes sense :)

For further reading about this type of undefined behaviour:
[When does invoking a member function on a null instance result in undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha)

Comment: Ok thank you. Actually I forgot that undefined behaviour think... What suprised me most was also the dereferencing from nullptr, but that seems logical now :)

Comment: There is no dereferencing from nullptr, because the method isn't virtual.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is that 'foo()' isn't virtual, so the object it's being called on is only used for type information at compile time. At runtime the fact that it's null has no effect, unless you used 'this' inside 'foo()', when you would get a nasty surprise, as you did when you tried to set a member variable, which uses 'this' implicitly.