# How to assign pointer to this in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to implement treap class, so I have this code:

```
void item::insert(item* it) {
     if (!this)
         this = it;
     .....
```

I can't compile this with GCC:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

I know, I can simply assign all members of `it` to `this`, but is there another way?

Comment: You cannot, and that's good so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know, I can simply assign all members of `it` to `this`, but is there another way?

You are looking for `*this = *it`. `this` is not an lvalue.

---

You should probably take an `item const&` rather than an `item*`:

```
void item::insert(item const& it) {
    *this = it;
}
```

As a side note: `this` can never be the null pointer in any well-defined program, since methods can only be called on objects. The null pointer doesn’t point to an object.

Answer (score 5):

As per §9.3.2/1:

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called.

Therefore the `this` pointer can never be `nullptr` within a non-static member function, assuming the object, from which the member function is invoked, has been allocated correctly (in the case the member function is invoked on a null pointer, the [behavior seems to be undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha)).

And second: **don't** try to change the `this` pointer, because [it's not assignable](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbec1b6676343775). For good reasons.

Comment: You are wrong. this can be equal to nullptr within a non-static member function..

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, you make me curious. I assume you can always assign to this after casting away the const and set it null, but apart from that?

Comment: Would you care to elaborate about the reasons?

Comment: @Peter Schneider  this is not const. It is an rvalue. If a member function does not access any data member then you can write ( (YourClass *)NULL )->MemberFunction(); In this case inside the function this will be equal to NULL.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you are wrong, that's just undefined behavior. The only way to reach a situation where `this == NULL` is through undefined behavior, so invalid.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore I pointed out that such a possibility exists that inside a non-static member function this can be equal to nullptr.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you might as well have pointed out that inside a non-static member function `1 == 2` might yield `true` - it can happen if it follows undefined behavior.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore I do not see undefined behaviour. The undefined behaviour corresponds only the case when you use this to access data members. When a member function is called this is simply used as the first implicit argument. So there is defined behaviour.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Interesting.-- const: The IBM docs said that "The type of the this pointer for a member function of a class type X, is X* const." (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr035.htm) but I see that the new standard defines it the way you said.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha I thought you already knew this...

Comment: @Peter Schneider Are you deal with an IBM mainframe?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You may be right that calling a member function on a null pointer is UB, but it is indeed important to understand that it can nevertheless happen, and that `this` may actually be null when the member function is entered. If you forget about this **technical** possibility while you are debugging a program in which it occurs, you will be hard put to understand what is going on.

Comment: @cmaster - it annoys me that many, (most) debuggers do not display 'this' when entering a member function.  I've now got quite good at spotting a null or illegal 'this', but it should be easier!  Usually, the only clue is when the function segfaults/AV when reading a member var that you KNOW has been initialised correctly.

Comment: @cmaster there's a **technical** posiblity for **anything** to happen after UB.

Comment: Well, it would be nice if the debugger told me that something bad is likely to happen before I have to put a net over my nose to catch the demons.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Where is it specified that Vlad's code is UB? (As opposed to e.g. IDB). I'm really not sure where even to look int the standard.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm entirely with you that this would be a *very* nice debugger feature :-)

Comment: @PeterSchneider Calling a member function on a pointer counts as dereferencing the pointer afaik, hence it is UB if that pointer is a null pointer. After all, if the member function is virtual, the pointer *is technically dereferenced and will segfault immediately*. The problem is that this segfault may even be deferred until **after** the call completes in the nonvirtual case (this is the case with accessors that only return a reference to a member which is not dereferenced until the caller accesses the object behind that reference, which may again defer...). This can be a real mess to debug.